# Adding chapter marker to far right edge of page

Tags: chapters, appendices

Is there a way to add a thin, ~1 inch tall, rectangular marker to the extreme right edge of each page in a large document to differentiate chapters (each chapter marked at a decreasing vertical position)? I want to provide a visual cue when either quickly scrolling/flipping through a long document, or to be able to visually see the chapters when looking at the physical edge of the printed thesis.

I am not sure if this typesetting element has a formal name (which has made it hard to search), but I feel like I've seen it in theses typeset in LaTeX before.

Comment: Here is a nice alternative: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57031/17425

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those markers are called (by extension) "Thumb-indexes". You can find an example on how to implement them in **Section 21 Thumb-indexes** of the documentation of the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It looks like there are quite a few other packages that address this as well, including `thumb` and `thumbs`.