# Creating a thumb index with LaTeX in book class

Tags: pdf

I am currently finishing my dissertation which consists of an introduction and three publications labelled A, B and C. The dissertation will be published in a book form and it is customary (in our department) to have before each included paper an empty page consisting only of "side bar" indicating the label of the paper. (This makes it easier to browse.) Part of my problem is that I don't know the proper name of this "side bar", see attached pictures for what I mean.

[Side bar for paper B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQWa1.jpg)

[Side bar for paper C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXNCh.jpg)

To my question: These side bar pages are usually added by the printing company, by hand, but **is it possible to do this with LaTeX?**

The papers themselves are added as pdf files via

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{Papers/Paper-1.pdf}
```

So generating such side bar pages as disjoint pdf pages with hand adjusted labels would be fine.

**Edit:** Apparently the "side bar" thing is called a *thumb index*, and the solution can be found from another question listed in the comments.

Comment: have a look at `Tobi`s answer in [How to set a letter to the margin of the page and position it vertically according to alphabetical order?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/how-to-set-a-letter-to-the-margin-of-the-page-and-position-it-vertically-accordi), or any of the other answers for alternative approaches.

Comment: Yes, thank you @runartrollet! This was exactly what I needed. (And it seems the term I was looking for was "Thumb index".)