# Create phonebook-like registers at the page margin

Tags: pdftex, makeindex, page

I try to create a little booklet with formulas that I need for university. Since we are allowed to use formularies (I'm not shure, if this is the right word for that!) in exams, it's absolutely crucial to find each formula as fast as possible.

Therefore I try to create a register at the page margin like on phonebooks or addressbooks as seen in the picture below. 
(What I would like to generate are those red letters. But preferably not only one letter but a few words)

[image]
Do you know any package that could do this for me automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Frieder

Comment: The thing you are looking for is called "thumb index". Maybe you could start [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/how-to-set-a-letter-to-the-margin-of-the-page-and-position-it-vertically-accordi) and post a new question if you have some code ([minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) to show.

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I want! Sorry for my duplicate question, but I didn't knew the word "thumb index" (I am not a nativ speaker as you might have noticed). I will try this!