# workbook dividers / verical side dividers

Tags: vertical

is there a way to obtain side dividers as it workbook or even in some pdf (sa in the pic). So instead having a table of contents at the staart of the document, beginging of every chapter can be reach immediatly.

[image]

Comment: Some similar questions. You can also look in their "Related" links at the right side. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48641/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57031/1952

Comment: If you do this you will have to print on different page widths; wider for chapter pages and the divider text and narrower for regular pages.