# How can one put a marker to every page in a chapter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I am trying to create some sort of tabbing for a template am designing. I want the title page to have the colors of the chapters and then all of the pages within a chapter to have a marking as shown below. The title page should use the page height and split it with respect to the total number of chapters. The rectangles shown should follow an odd-even page criteria so that the display is proper. Here is a sort of a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[text={4.95in,7.5in},centering,bottom=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                        Chapter Page Header/Footer 
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyhead{
\ifodd\thepage
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=cyan] (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.east)+(-0.5,9)$);}
\else
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=cyan] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.west)+(0.5,9)$);}
\fi
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                       Header/Footer Page Styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage$|$}
\fancyfoot[LE]{$|$\thepage}
\fancyhead{
\ifodd\thepage
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=cyan] (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.east)+(-0.5,9)$);}
\else
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=cyan] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.west)+(0.5,9)$);}
\fi
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\title{Your Paper
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=cyan] (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.east)+(-0.5,9)$);}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=magenta] ($(current page.north east)+(0,-5)$) rectangle ($(current page.east)+(-0.5,4)$);}}
\author{You}

\maketitle
\newpage
\chapter{Test 1}
%\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=cyan] (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.east)+(-0.5,9)$);}
\newpage
%\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[fill=magenta] ($(current page.north east)+(0,-5)$) rectangle ($(current page.east)+(-0.5,4)$);}
\chapter{Test 2}
\lipsum
\chapter{Test 3}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Note that chapter 2 should have the magenta color with the marker shifted down by the right amount. I was thinking with a `foreach` statement but I don't know how to test if you are still in chapter 1 or 2 and so on. I think the tricky part will be then to set the colors depending on the amount of chapters. So probably having a default say 20 colors to be used in order as they appear (and hence allowing the user to decide what colors to use and for which chapter) for the chapter markers would be good.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate of: [Adding chapter marker to far right edge of page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31462/5764)

Comment: @Werner I had read that post already but it was not too specific. I am looking for a workable example which I can then study, edit and work on.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a first version:

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup%
{   contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytop}{-(\thechapter-1)*2.5}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybottom}{-\thechapter*2.5}
            \ifcase\thechapter
                \xdef\mycolor{black}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{red}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{orange}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{yellow}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{green}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \else \xdef\mycolor{black}
            \fi
            \fill[\mycolor] ($(current page.north east)+(0,\mytop)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5,\mybottom)$);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    },
    scale=1,
    angle=0
}

\newcommand{\mycolor}%
{   \foreach \x [count=\c] in {blue,violet,red,orange,yellow,green} {\ifthenelse{\c=\thechapter}{\x}{}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\chapter{First}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum

\chapter{Third}
\lipsum

\chapter{Fourth}
\lipsum

\chapter{Fifth}
\lipsum

\chapter{Sixth}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Now checking the total number of chapters and using left/right markers on odd/even pages:

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\regtotcounter{chapter}

\backgroundsetup%
{   contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytotalchapters}{\totvalue{chapter} > 0 ? \totvalue{chapter} : 20}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mypaperheight}{\paperheight/28.453}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytop}{-(\thechapter-1)/\mytotalchapters*\mypaperheight}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybottom}{-\thechapter/\mytotalchapters*\mypaperheight}
            \ifcase\thechapter
                \xdef\mycolor{white}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{red}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{orange}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{yellow}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{green}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \else \xdef\mycolor{black}
            \fi
            \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
            {\fill[\mycolor] ($(current page.north east)+(0,\mytop)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5,\mybottom)$);}
            {\fill[\mycolor] ($(current page.north west)+(0,\mytop)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.5,\mybottom)$);}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    },
    scale=1,
    angle=0
}

\begin{document}
Total chapters: \total{chapter}

Paper height: \pgfmathsetmacro{\yxc}{\paperheight/28.453}\yxc cm

Paper width: \pgfmathsetmacro{\cxy}{\paperwidth/28.453}\cxy cm

\lipsum

\chapter{First}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum

\chapter{Third}
\lipsum

\chapter{Fourth}
\lipsum

\chapter{Fifth}
\lipsum

\chapter{Sixth}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Really nice. No need to explicitly load `tikz`; `background` loads it internally.

Comment: Thanks, I keep forgetting that, and `TikZ` is always loaded in my standard template ;)

Comment: @TomBombadil Thanks, I will study your code in a few and then will get you if I have any questions.

Comment: For those looking for a different approach [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262953/178206) provides a way to do it, by simply adding `\ChapFrame` after each chapter and adding some new commands on the preamble