# Thumb index in Book class (based on previous question)

Tags: pdftex

I'm hoping to get some help from the experts:

My question is related to this thread, but I was asked to post it as a new question: [How to set a letter to the margin of the page and position it vertically according to alphabetical order?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/how-to-set-a-letter-to-the-margin-of-the-page-and-position-it-vertically-accordi/57317#57317)

I have used the last example (This answer is summary of all answers ...) to add thumb indexes to my document. I'm using the book class and chapters. It worked except that I cannot get the thumb to appear on the chapter page. Page 2 etc of each chapter has the correct thumbs, but the starting page doesn't. Is there a way to add them to the first page as well? 
Many thanks, 
Bjorn

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} %
\usepackage[margin={2.5cm},a4paper]{geometry} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lineno,graphicx,textcomp,booktabs,url,setspace,color,soul,eurosym}
\usepackage{multirow,listings,setspace,microtype,gnuplottex,latexsym,keyval,ifthen,moreverb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,arrows,intersections}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,labelsep=colon,font={sf},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}
\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,font={sf},labelfont={bf,sf}]{subcaption}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
    } 
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase{\small \textsf{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
    }
}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\newcounter{letternum}
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{14}
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{1cm}
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{3cm}
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)/\value{lettersum}}

\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{1.5cm}

\tikzset{
   thumb/.style={
   draw=blue,
%  fill=green,
   text=blue,
   minimum height=\thumbheight, %\thumbheight,
   text width=\thumbwidth,
   outer sep=0pt,
   font=\sffamily\Huge,
}
}
\newcommand{\oddthumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north east,] at ($%
            (current page.north east)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north west,] at ($%
            (current page.north west)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
% create a new command to set a new lettergroup
\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{%
\fancyhead[LO]{\oddthumb{#1}}%
\fancyhead[RE]{\eventhumb{#1}}%
% step the counter of the letters
\stepcounter{letternum}%
}


\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 

\chapter{A title} 
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu vehicula ipsum, a dignissim tellus. Nam ac nisl consectetur, elementum lacus et, viverra erat. Ut eget quam id elit accumsan ullamcorper et et velit. Aliquam bibendum tellus nec libero sagittis, vestibulum blandit odio adipiscing. Morbi arcu massa, commodo in venenatis ut, bibendum non mi. Nam mollis urna eu pharetra porta. Suspendisse a cursus risus. Donec sit amet dignissim ipsum. Fusce egestas, nisi tincidunt vestibulum convallis, mi urna suscipit velit, a placerat dui sapien aliquet nunc. Donec commodo sed turpis viverra interdum. Aenean sed scelerisque orci. Quisque iaculis neque non laoreet facilisis. Donec scelerisque sit amet lacus non laoreet. Integer volutpat nisl quis nisl elementum, vel malesuada dui laoreet. Suspendisse facilisis rutrum fringilla.

Sed quis quam consequat, venenatis felis nec, aliquet justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse posuere neque quam, et eleifend nulla scelerisque nec. Etiam magna est, eleifend et consequat vitae, ornare at augue. Nulla ullamcorper arcu id mauris scelerisque, eget lacinia felis dictum. Curabitur ullamcorper dolor id tellus tempus mattis. In scelerisque ipsum porta leo fermentum, id tristique leo sollicitudin. Donec suscipit vehicula enim, at dictum nulla rutrum sit amet. Ut pretium metus ac orci semper cursus. Nam in dolor sapien. Sed scelerisque felis augue, non mollis libero fringilla id. Curabitur placerat lorem vel libero blandit, non interdum orci consectetur. Sed sagittis eleifend neque sed mollis. Nulla sem sapien, sodales eu bibendum non, laoreet ut enim. Sed non nunc et ligula tristique volutpat. Proin auctor adipiscing ante.

Vivamus bibendum lobortis purus, sit amet sodales nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Sed laoreet sollicitudin nisl at sodales. Nulla at condimentum augue. Donec sed diam commodo metus aliquet rhoncus in ac sapien. Nullam sapien dolor, aliquet vitae sem et, vulputate gravida turpis. Fusce mollis sapien quis gravida ullamcorper. Ut bibendum fermentum mauris quis consequat. Aenean volutpat, erat eu vulputate rutrum, massa neque semper nibh, ut venenatis est arcu vitae purus.

Aliquam vehicula mollis faucibus. Maecenas sed mi massa. Cras consectetur leo malesuada, egestas erat ut, eleifend mauris. Nulla quis sem eget ipsum tristique fermentum. Vivamus non ante quis eros vulputate condimentum. Aenean congue, purus sit amet auctor suscipit, turpis nibh dapibus lectus, eu vehicula felis nisi in felis. Nunc tempus lectus a felis suscipit tristique. Nulla consectetur auctor magna. Proin in nisi quis elit semper elementum. Phasellus lobortis est vitae sem dictum, sit amet consequat diam imperdiet. Curabitur quis lobortis nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque placerat. Maecenas orci enim, sollicitudin ut arcu quis, dapibus facilisis dui.

Nullam quis nibh vel velit tempus vulputate. Nam tincidunt in dui a elementum. Quisque bibendum sapien id felis porttitor, sed aliquet odio ullamcorper. Nulla dapibus sollicitudin nisi in bibendum. Vestibulum ultrices sed ligula et condimentum. Nunc vitae tristique ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ultrices venenatis condimentum. Integer scelerisque aliquam risus. In lacinia nisi in ligula euismod pretium at sit amet enim. Nunc lacinia lorem libero, non tempor quam ultricies quis. Integer magna leo, tincidunt non sapien et, consequat commodo urna. Vivamus vel tortor pulvinar, cursus lacus vel, volutpat diam. Nulla eu enim vitae leo condimentum condimentum.

Etiam gravida purus eget porta bibendum. Vestibulum eget nisi ultricies, consectetur elit ac, varius felis. Vivamus ac enim eget nibh tristique eleifend. Etiam scelerisque justo non erat pellentesque lacinia. Ut sit amet lorem sed metus dapibus imperdiet a vitae purus. Nunc dictum enim nec diam dapibus convallis. Nulla odio lacus, feugiat sed magna et, aliquet porta odio. Phasellus faucibus placerat sagittis. Ut ac pretium justo. Donec a facilisis nibh, ac auctor diam. Praesent congue mi velit, sit amet dapibus felis porta ut. Vestibulum eget est et felis vestibulum convallis et id est. Cras sodales nisi at pellentesque adipiscing. Nulla luctus metus accumsan ipsum consequat ornare. Duis cursus feugiat sollicitudin.

Integer felis sem, imperdiet id dolor et, fermentum fermentum felis. Mauris porttitor lorem vitae nulla varius accumsan sit amet at nibh. Sed nunc risus, ultricies in lacus in, tristique volutpat lorem. Nunc convallis erat nec velit eleifend bibendum. Curabitur a iaculis nunc. Phasellus viverra rutrum sapien ut laoreet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque porta congue sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sodales ullamcorper lacinia. Cras accumsan dapibus feugiat. In laoreet placerat scelerisque. Vivamus vel euismod sapien. Vestibulum dignissim pellentesque est. Vivamus vel congue nisl. Proin vehicula augue ante, in porta libero dapibus sit amet.

Integer quis elit vitae nibh accumsan porta in blandit mi. Suspendisse sapien mi, hendrerit et justo eget, bibendum tristique dui. Aenean in vestibulum sem. Cras ut nibh non est sagittis accumsan a nec diam. Quisque sagittis nisi at auctor porttitor. Morbi suscipit sit amet mi vel auctor. Vivamus ante elit, vestibulum non dui et, congue consectetur dolor. Aliquam laoreet metus eu arcu facilisis, vitae faucibus velit aliquet. In ut nulla sit amet nisl pretium euismod congue sed justo. Vivamus purus sapien, egestas sit amet libero ac, congue auctor metus. Etiam ultrices vel elit in lacinia. Nunc tempor sem ut arcu dignissim, sed tempor lacus condimentum.

Pellentesque blandit mattis ipsum, at hendrerit tortor luctus ac. In ante ligula, commodo sed adipiscing non, accumsan sed ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque pretium nunc quis dui commodo, at congue eros pretium. Quisque at ultricies eros. Morbi sed molestie risus. Morbi molestie aliquet sem, sed convallis ipsum commodo id. Proin ultricies pretium eros et eleifend. Duis sed diam vitae tellus mollis vehicula eu non diam.

Nulla rutrum aliquet ante, sagittis tincidunt arcu. Donec viverra varius porta. Nunc condimentum lorem non molestie commodo. Sed sollicitudin at mauris id cursus. Duis tincidunt, sapien eu laoreet volutpat, urna dui pharetra lacus, at euismod leo sapien a neque. Integer non odio augue. Ut orci eros, faucibus sed pharetra id, consectetur eget sapien. Sed vitae eros mi.


\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\chapter{Another title} 
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu vehicula ipsum, a dignissim tellus. Nam ac nisl consectetur, elementum lacus et, viverra erat. Ut eget quam id elit accumsan ullamcorper et et velit. Aliquam bibendum tellus nec libero sagittis, vestibulum blandit odio adipiscing. Morbi arcu massa, commodo in venenatis ut, bibendum non mi. Nam mollis urna eu pharetra porta. Suspendisse a cursus risus. Donec sit amet dignissim ipsum. Fusce egestas, nisi tincidunt vestibulum convallis, mi urna suscipit velit, a placerat dui sapien aliquet nunc. Donec commodo sed turpis viverra interdum. Aenean sed scelerisque orci. Quisque iaculis neque non laoreet facilisis. Donec scelerisque sit amet lacus non laoreet. Integer volutpat nisl quis nisl elementum, vel malesuada dui laoreet. Suspendisse facilisis rutrum fringilla.

Sed quis quam consequat, venenatis felis nec, aliquet justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse posuere neque quam, et eleifend nulla scelerisque nec. Etiam magna est, eleifend et consequat vitae, ornare at augue. Nulla ullamcorper arcu id mauris scelerisque, eget lacinia felis dictum. Curabitur ullamcorper dolor id tellus tempus mattis. In scelerisque ipsum porta leo fermentum, id tristique leo sollicitudin. Donec suscipit vehicula enim, at dictum nulla rutrum sit amet. Ut pretium metus ac orci semper cursus. Nam in dolor sapien. Sed scelerisque felis augue, non mollis libero fringilla id. Curabitur placerat lorem vel libero blandit, non interdum orci consectetur. Sed sagittis eleifend neque sed mollis. Nulla sem sapien, sodales eu bibendum non, laoreet ut enim. Sed non nunc et ligula tristique volutpat. Proin auctor adipiscing ante.

Vivamus bibendum lobortis purus, sit amet sodales nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Sed laoreet sollicitudin nisl at sodales. Nulla at condimentum augue. Donec sed diam commodo metus aliquet rhoncus in ac sapien. Nullam sapien dolor, aliquet vitae sem et, vulputate gravida turpis. Fusce mollis sapien quis gravida ullamcorper. Ut bibendum fermentum mauris quis consequat. Aenean volutpat, erat eu vulputate rutrum, massa neque semper nibh, ut venenatis est arcu vitae purus.

Aliquam vehicula mollis faucibus. Maecenas sed mi massa. Cras consectetur leo malesuada, egestas erat ut, eleifend mauris. Nulla quis sem eget ipsum tristique fermentum. Vivamus non ante quis eros vulputate condimentum. Aenean congue, purus sit amet auctor suscipit, turpis nibh dapibus lectus, eu vehicula felis nisi in felis. Nunc tempus lectus a felis suscipit tristique. Nulla consectetur auctor magna. Proin in nisi quis elit semper elementum. Phasellus lobortis est vitae sem dictum, sit amet consequat diam imperdiet. Curabitur quis lobortis nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque placerat. Maecenas orci enim, sollicitudin ut arcu quis, dapibus facilisis dui.

Nullam quis nibh vel velit tempus vulputate. Nam tincidunt in dui a elementum. Quisque bibendum sapien id felis porttitor, sed aliquet odio ullamcorper. Nulla dapibus sollicitudin nisi in bibendum. Vestibulum ultrices sed ligula et condimentum. Nunc vitae tristique ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ultrices venenatis condimentum. Integer scelerisque aliquam risus. In lacinia nisi in ligula euismod pretium at sit amet enim. Nunc lacinia lorem libero, non tempor quam ultricies quis. Integer magna leo, tincidunt non sapien et, consequat commodo urna. Vivamus vel tortor pulvinar, cursus lacus vel, volutpat diam. Nulla eu enim vitae leo condimentum condimentum.

Etiam gravida purus eget porta bibendum. Vestibulum eget nisi ultricies, consectetur elit ac, varius felis. Vivamus ac enim eget nibh tristique eleifend. Etiam scelerisque justo non erat pellentesque lacinia. Ut sit amet lorem sed metus dapibus imperdiet a vitae purus. Nunc dictum enim nec diam dapibus convallis. Nulla odio lacus, feugiat sed magna et, aliquet porta odio. Phasellus faucibus placerat sagittis. Ut ac pretium justo. Donec a facilisis nibh, ac auctor diam. Praesent congue mi velit, sit amet dapibus felis porta ut. Vestibulum eget est et felis vestibulum convallis et id est. Cras sodales nisi at pellentesque adipiscing. Nulla luctus metus accumsan ipsum consequat ornare. Duis cursus feugiat sollicitudin.

Integer felis sem, imperdiet id dolor et, fermentum fermentum felis. Mauris porttitor lorem vitae nulla varius accumsan sit amet at nibh. Sed nunc risus, ultricies in lacus in, tristique volutpat lorem. Nunc convallis erat nec velit eleifend bibendum. Curabitur a iaculis nunc. Phasellus viverra rutrum sapien ut laoreet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque porta congue sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sodales ullamcorper lacinia. Cras accumsan dapibus feugiat. In laoreet placerat scelerisque. Vivamus vel euismod sapien. Vestibulum dignissim pellentesque est. Vivamus vel congue nisl. Proin vehicula augue ante, in porta libero dapibus sit amet.

Integer quis elit vitae nibh accumsan porta in blandit mi. Suspendisse sapien mi, hendrerit et justo eget, bibendum tristique dui. Aenean in vestibulum sem. Cras ut nibh non est sagittis accumsan a nec diam. Quisque sagittis nisi at auctor porttitor. Morbi suscipit sit amet mi vel auctor. Vivamus ante elit, vestibulum non dui et, congue consectetur dolor. Aliquam laoreet metus eu arcu facilisis, vitae faucibus velit aliquet. In ut nulla sit amet nisl pretium euismod congue sed justo. Vivamus purus sapien, egestas sit amet libero ac, congue auctor metus. Etiam ultrices vel elit in lacinia. Nunc tempor sem ut arcu dignissim, sed tempor lacus condimentum.

Pellentesque blandit mattis ipsum, at hendrerit tortor luctus ac. In ante ligula, commodo sed adipiscing non, accumsan sed ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque pretium nunc quis dui commodo, at congue eros pretium. Quisque at ultricies eros. Morbi sed molestie risus. Morbi molestie aliquet sem, sed convallis ipsum commodo id. Proin ultricies pretium eros et eleifend. Duis sed diam vitae tellus mollis vehicula eu non diam.

Nulla rutrum aliquet ante, sagittis tincidunt arcu. Donec viverra varius porta. Nunc condimentum lorem non molestie commodo. Sed sollicitudin at mauris id cursus. Duis tincidunt, sapien eu laoreet volutpat, urna dui pharetra lacus, at euismod leo sapien a neque. Integer non odio augue. Ut orci eros, faucibus sed pharetra id, consectetur eget sapien. Sed vitae eros mi.



\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: From the `fancyhdr` documentation (Section 7): "Some LATEX commands, like \chapter, use the \thispagestyle command to automatically switch to the plain page style, thus ignoring the page style currently in effect. To customize even such pages you must redefine the plain page style."

Comment: @Bjorn Thanks for the MWE! Another couple tips: It’s usually advisable to get rid of all packages (in an MWE) that are not necessary to reproduce the problem. And for producing lorem ipsum text, you can use the `lipsum` package. See my answer at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/3225#3225 for more.

Comment: I think you can also look at this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113323/1952

Comment: You may consider using the `lipsum` or the `blindtext` package so you won't need dozens of code lines to add some text … ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why there are no thumb marks on the chapter page is, that `\chapter` calls the page style `plain` and not `fancy`. You have to tell `\chapter` somehow to use `fancy`. One way to do so, would be to call:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy}
```

after `fncychap`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} %
\usepackage[margin={2.5cm},a4paper]{geometry} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lineno,graphicx,textcomp,booktabs,url,setspace,color,soul,eurosym}
\usepackage{multirow,listings,setspace,microtype,gnuplottex,latexsym,keyval,ifthen,moreverb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,arrows,intersections}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,labelsep=colon,font={sf},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}
\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,font={sf},labelfont={bf,sf}]{subcaption}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
    } 
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase{\small \textsf{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
    }
}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\newcounter{letternum}
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{14}
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{1cm}
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{3cm}
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)/\value{lettersum}}

\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{1.5cm}

\tikzset{
   thumb/.style={
   draw=blue,
%  fill=green,
   text=blue,
   minimum height=\thumbheight, %\thumbheight,
   text width=\thumbwidth,
   outer sep=0pt,
   font=\sffamily\Huge,
}
}
\newcommand{\oddthumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north east,] at ($%
            (current page.north east)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north west,] at ($%
            (current page.north west)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
% create a new command to set a new lettergroup
\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{%
\fancyhead[LO]{\oddthumb{#1}}%
\fancyhead[RE]{\eventhumb{#1}}%
% step the counter of the letters
\stepcounter{letternum}%
}

\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 

\chapter{A title} 
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu vehicula ipsum, a dignissim tellus. Nam ac nisl consectetur, elementum lacus et, viverra erat. Ut eget quam id elit accumsan ullamcorper et et velit. Aliquam bibendum tellus nec libero sagittis, vestibulum blandit odio adipiscing. Morbi arcu massa, commodo in venenatis ut, bibendum non mi. Nam mollis urna eu pharetra porta. Suspendisse a cursus risus. Donec sit amet dignissim ipsum. Fusce egestas, nisi tincidunt vestibulum convallis, mi urna suscipit velit, a placerat dui sapien aliquet nunc. Donec commodo sed turpis viverra interdum. Aenean sed scelerisque orci. Quisque iaculis neque non laoreet facilisis. Donec scelerisque sit amet lacus non laoreet. Integer volutpat nisl quis nisl elementum, vel malesuada dui laoreet. Suspendisse facilisis rutrum fringilla.

Sed quis quam consequat, venenatis felis nec, aliquet justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse posuere neque quam, et eleifend nulla scelerisque nec. Etiam magna est, eleifend et consequat vitae, ornare at augue. Nulla ullamcorper arcu id mauris scelerisque, eget lacinia felis dictum. Curabitur ullamcorper dolor id tellus tempus mattis. In scelerisque ipsum porta leo fermentum, id tristique leo sollicitudin. Donec suscipit vehicula enim, at dictum nulla rutrum sit amet. Ut pretium metus ac orci semper cursus. Nam in dolor sapien. Sed scelerisque felis augue, non mollis libero fringilla id. Curabitur placerat lorem vel libero blandit, non interdum orci consectetur. Sed sagittis eleifend neque sed mollis. Nulla sem sapien, sodales eu bibendum non, laoreet ut enim. Sed non nunc et ligula tristique volutpat. Proin auctor adipiscing ante.

Vivamus bibendum lobortis purus, sit amet sodales nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Sed laoreet sollicitudin nisl at sodales. Nulla at condimentum augue. Donec sed diam commodo metus aliquet rhoncus in ac sapien. Nullam sapien dolor, aliquet vitae sem et, vulputate gravida turpis. Fusce mollis sapien quis gravida ullamcorper. Ut bibendum fermentum mauris quis consequat. Aenean volutpat, erat eu vulputate rutrum, massa neque semper nibh, ut venenatis est arcu vitae purus.

Aliquam vehicula mollis faucibus. Maecenas sed mi massa. Cras consectetur leo malesuada, egestas erat ut, eleifend mauris. Nulla quis sem eget ipsum tristique fermentum. Vivamus non ante quis eros vulputate condimentum. Aenean congue, purus sit amet auctor suscipit, turpis nibh dapibus lectus, eu vehicula felis nisi in felis. Nunc tempus lectus a felis suscipit tristique. Nulla consectetur auctor magna. Proin in nisi quis elit semper elementum. Phasellus lobortis est vitae sem dictum, sit amet consequat diam imperdiet. Curabitur quis lobortis nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque placerat. Maecenas orci enim, sollicitudin ut arcu quis, dapibus facilisis dui.

Nullam quis nibh vel velit tempus vulputate. Nam tincidunt in dui a elementum. Quisque bibendum sapien id felis porttitor, sed aliquet odio ullamcorper. Nulla dapibus sollicitudin nisi in bibendum. Vestibulum ultrices sed ligula et condimentum. Nunc vitae tristique ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ultrices venenatis condimentum. Integer scelerisque aliquam risus. In lacinia nisi in ligula euismod pretium at sit amet enim. Nunc lacinia lorem libero, non tempor quam ultricies quis. Integer magna leo, tincidunt non sapien et, consequat commodo urna. Vivamus vel tortor pulvinar, cursus lacus vel, volutpat diam. Nulla eu enim vitae leo condimentum condimentum.

Etiam gravida purus eget porta bibendum. Vestibulum eget nisi ultricies, consectetur elit ac, varius felis. Vivamus ac enim eget nibh tristique eleifend. Etiam scelerisque justo non erat pellentesque lacinia. Ut sit amet lorem sed metus dapibus imperdiet a vitae purus. Nunc dictum enim nec diam dapibus convallis. Nulla odio lacus, feugiat sed magna et, aliquet porta odio. Phasellus faucibus placerat sagittis. Ut ac pretium justo. Donec a facilisis nibh, ac auctor diam. Praesent congue mi velit, sit amet dapibus felis porta ut. Vestibulum eget est et felis vestibulum convallis et id est. Cras sodales nisi at pellentesque adipiscing. Nulla luctus metus accumsan ipsum consequat ornare. Duis cursus feugiat sollicitudin.

Integer felis sem, imperdiet id dolor et, fermentum fermentum felis. Mauris porttitor lorem vitae nulla varius accumsan sit amet at nibh. Sed nunc risus, ultricies in lacus in, tristique volutpat lorem. Nunc convallis erat nec velit eleifend bibendum. Curabitur a iaculis nunc. Phasellus viverra rutrum sapien ut laoreet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque porta congue sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sodales ullamcorper lacinia. Cras accumsan dapibus feugiat. In laoreet placerat scelerisque. Vivamus vel euismod sapien. Vestibulum dignissim pellentesque est. Vivamus vel congue nisl. Proin vehicula augue ante, in porta libero dapibus sit amet.

Integer quis elit vitae nibh accumsan porta in blandit mi. Suspendisse sapien mi, hendrerit et justo eget, bibendum tristique dui. Aenean in vestibulum sem. Cras ut nibh non est sagittis accumsan a nec diam. Quisque sagittis nisi at auctor porttitor. Morbi suscipit sit amet mi vel auctor. Vivamus ante elit, vestibulum non dui et, congue consectetur dolor. Aliquam laoreet metus eu arcu facilisis, vitae faucibus velit aliquet. In ut nulla sit amet nisl pretium euismod congue sed justo. Vivamus purus sapien, egestas sit amet libero ac, congue auctor metus. Etiam ultrices vel elit in lacinia. Nunc tempor sem ut arcu dignissim, sed tempor lacus condimentum.

Pellentesque blandit mattis ipsum, at hendrerit tortor luctus ac. In ante ligula, commodo sed adipiscing non, accumsan sed ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque pretium nunc quis dui commodo, at congue eros pretium. Quisque at ultricies eros. Morbi sed molestie risus. Morbi molestie aliquet sem, sed convallis ipsum commodo id. Proin ultricies pretium eros et eleifend. Duis sed diam vitae tellus mollis vehicula eu non diam.

Nulla rutrum aliquet ante, sagittis tincidunt arcu. Donec viverra varius porta. Nunc condimentum lorem non molestie commodo. Sed sollicitudin at mauris id cursus. Duis tincidunt, sapien eu laoreet volutpat, urna dui pharetra lacus, at euismod leo sapien a neque. Integer non odio augue. Ut orci eros, faucibus sed pharetra id, consectetur eget sapien. Sed vitae eros mi.


\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\chapter{Another title} 
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu vehicula ipsum, a dignissim tellus. Nam ac nisl consectetur, elementum lacus et, viverra erat. Ut eget quam id elit accumsan ullamcorper et et velit. Aliquam bibendum tellus nec libero sagittis, vestibulum blandit odio adipiscing. Morbi arcu massa, commodo in venenatis ut, bibendum non mi. Nam mollis urna eu pharetra porta. Suspendisse a cursus risus. Donec sit amet dignissim ipsum. Fusce egestas, nisi tincidunt vestibulum convallis, mi urna suscipit velit, a placerat dui sapien aliquet nunc. Donec commodo sed turpis viverra interdum. Aenean sed scelerisque orci. Quisque iaculis neque non laoreet facilisis. Donec scelerisque sit amet lacus non laoreet. Integer volutpat nisl quis nisl elementum, vel malesuada dui laoreet. Suspendisse facilisis rutrum fringilla.

Sed quis quam consequat, venenatis felis nec, aliquet justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse posuere neque quam, et eleifend nulla scelerisque nec. Etiam magna est, eleifend et consequat vitae, ornare at augue. Nulla ullamcorper arcu id mauris scelerisque, eget lacinia felis dictum. Curabitur ullamcorper dolor id tellus tempus mattis. In scelerisque ipsum porta leo fermentum, id tristique leo sollicitudin. Donec suscipit vehicula enim, at dictum nulla rutrum sit amet. Ut pretium metus ac orci semper cursus. Nam in dolor sapien. Sed scelerisque felis augue, non mollis libero fringilla id. Curabitur placerat lorem vel libero blandit, non interdum orci consectetur. Sed sagittis eleifend neque sed mollis. Nulla sem sapien, sodales eu bibendum non, laoreet ut enim. Sed non nunc et ligula tristique volutpat. Proin auctor adipiscing ante.

Vivamus bibendum lobortis purus, sit amet sodales nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Sed laoreet sollicitudin nisl at sodales. Nulla at condimentum augue. Donec sed diam commodo metus aliquet rhoncus in ac sapien. Nullam sapien dolor, aliquet vitae sem et, vulputate gravida turpis. Fusce mollis sapien quis gravida ullamcorper. Ut bibendum fermentum mauris quis consequat. Aenean volutpat, erat eu vulputate rutrum, massa neque semper nibh, ut venenatis est arcu vitae purus.

Aliquam vehicula mollis faucibus. Maecenas sed mi massa. Cras consectetur leo malesuada, egestas erat ut, eleifend mauris. Nulla quis sem eget ipsum tristique fermentum. Vivamus non ante quis eros vulputate condimentum. Aenean congue, purus sit amet auctor suscipit, turpis nibh dapibus lectus, eu vehicula felis nisi in felis. Nunc tempus lectus a felis suscipit tristique. Nulla consectetur auctor magna. Proin in nisi quis elit semper elementum. Phasellus lobortis est vitae sem dictum, sit amet consequat diam imperdiet. Curabitur quis lobortis nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque placerat. Maecenas orci enim, sollicitudin ut arcu quis, dapibus facilisis dui.

Nullam quis nibh vel velit tempus vulputate. Nam tincidunt in dui a elementum. Quisque bibendum sapien id felis porttitor, sed aliquet odio ullamcorper. Nulla dapibus sollicitudin nisi in bibendum. Vestibulum ultrices sed ligula et condimentum. Nunc vitae tristique ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ultrices venenatis condimentum. Integer scelerisque aliquam risus. In lacinia nisi in ligula euismod pretium at sit amet enim. Nunc lacinia lorem libero, non tempor quam ultricies quis. Integer magna leo, tincidunt non sapien et, consequat commodo urna. Vivamus vel tortor pulvinar, cursus lacus vel, volutpat diam. Nulla eu enim vitae leo condimentum condimentum.

Etiam gravida purus eget porta bibendum. Vestibulum eget nisi ultricies, consectetur elit ac, varius felis. Vivamus ac enim eget nibh tristique eleifend. Etiam scelerisque justo non erat pellentesque lacinia. Ut sit amet lorem sed metus dapibus imperdiet a vitae purus. Nunc dictum enim nec diam dapibus convallis. Nulla odio lacus, feugiat sed magna et, aliquet porta odio. Phasellus faucibus placerat sagittis. Ut ac pretium justo. Donec a facilisis nibh, ac auctor diam. Praesent congue mi velit, sit amet dapibus felis porta ut. Vestibulum eget est et felis vestibulum convallis et id est. Cras sodales nisi at pellentesque adipiscing. Nulla luctus metus accumsan ipsum consequat ornare. Duis cursus feugiat sollicitudin.

Integer felis sem, imperdiet id dolor et, fermentum fermentum felis. Mauris porttitor lorem vitae nulla varius accumsan sit amet at nibh. Sed nunc risus, ultricies in lacus in, tristique volutpat lorem. Nunc convallis erat nec velit eleifend bibendum. Curabitur a iaculis nunc. Phasellus viverra rutrum sapien ut laoreet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque porta congue sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sodales ullamcorper lacinia. Cras accumsan dapibus feugiat. In laoreet placerat scelerisque. Vivamus vel euismod sapien. Vestibulum dignissim pellentesque est. Vivamus vel congue nisl. Proin vehicula augue ante, in porta libero dapibus sit amet.

Integer quis elit vitae nibh accumsan porta in blandit mi. Suspendisse sapien mi, hendrerit et justo eget, bibendum tristique dui. Aenean in vestibulum sem. Cras ut nibh non est sagittis accumsan a nec diam. Quisque sagittis nisi at auctor porttitor. Morbi suscipit sit amet mi vel auctor. Vivamus ante elit, vestibulum non dui et, congue consectetur dolor. Aliquam laoreet metus eu arcu facilisis, vitae faucibus velit aliquet. In ut nulla sit amet nisl pretium euismod congue sed justo. Vivamus purus sapien, egestas sit amet libero ac, congue auctor metus. Etiam ultrices vel elit in lacinia. Nunc tempor sem ut arcu dignissim, sed tempor lacus condimentum.

Pellentesque blandit mattis ipsum, at hendrerit tortor luctus ac. In ante ligula, commodo sed adipiscing non, accumsan sed ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque pretium nunc quis dui commodo, at congue eros pretium. Quisque at ultricies eros. Morbi sed molestie risus. Morbi molestie aliquet sem, sed convallis ipsum commodo id. Proin ultricies pretium eros et eleifend. Duis sed diam vitae tellus mollis vehicula eu non diam.

Nulla rutrum aliquet ante, sagittis tincidunt arcu. Donec viverra varius porta. Nunc condimentum lorem non molestie commodo. Sed sollicitudin at mauris id cursus. Duis tincidunt, sapien eu laoreet volutpat, urna dui pharetra lacus, at euismod leo sapien a neque. Integer non odio augue. Ut orci eros, faucibus sed pharetra id, consectetur eget sapien. Sed vitae eros mi.



\end{document}
```

This gives you thumb marks on the chapter pages:

[image]

## Update

I took a look at the [original code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/how-to-set-a-letter-to-the-margin-of-the-page-and-position-it-vertically-accordi/57317) by @Speravir, and found, that the solution is already there. I reinserted the relevant piece of code into `\lettergroup`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} %
\usepackage[margin={2.5cm},a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,arrows,intersections}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,labelsep=colon,font={sf},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}
\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,font={sf},labelfont={bf,sf}]{subcaption}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
    } 
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase{\small \textsf{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
    }
}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\newcounter{letternum}
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{14}
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{1cm}
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{3cm}
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)/\value{lettersum}}

\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{1.5cm}

\tikzset{
   thumb/.style={
   draw=blue,
%  fill=green,
   text=blue,
   minimum height=\thumbheight, %\thumbheight,
   text width=\thumbwidth,
   outer sep=0pt,
   font=\sffamily\Huge,
}
}
\newcommand{\oddthumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north east,] at ($%
            (current page.north east)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north west,] at ($%
            (current page.north west)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
% create a new command to set a new lettergroup
\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{%
\fancyhead[LO]{\oddthumb{#1}}%
\fancyhead[RE]{\eventhumb{#1}}%
\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \chead{\oddthumb{#1}}% chapters start only on odd pages
    \cfoot{\thepage}
  }
    \thispagestyle{chapterstart}
\stepcounter{letternum}%
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 

\chapter{A title} 
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
\Blindtext\Blindtext




\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\chapter{Another title} 
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
\Blindtext



\end{document}
```

Comment: You may like to add the cause of the problem, i.e. that `\chapter` has another style …

Comment: Thanks for answering. The issue was apparently with me redefining the chapter style for that page. This was done on purpose to (i) modify the way the page numbers are set (not centered anymore) and (ii) to avoid the black line at the top of that page. When including the fix, the line reappears, which I think is not visually attractive... Is there any way to get just the thumb index, without the unwanted line reappearing?

Comment: @Bjorn, you could define a page style for the chapter page, that meets your requirements and assign it instead.

Comment: You may consider using the `lipsum` or the `blindtext` package so you won't need dozens of code lines to add some text … ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@DG' 
Hi,
The update did the trick! I needed to make a few more modifications, but now it is ok (I have frontmatter and mainmatter in my file, with different fancy styles...). 
I did run into one more problem: the bibliography. 
Currently that chapter is defined as follows:

```
%\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}

\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\lettergroup{\thechapter}
\bibliographystyle{phdbib}
\bibliography{myreferences}
```

The thumb marks seem to miss this chapterpage. The second page has one, but the first page does not. How can I force the page to be recognized as a chapter? 
(I'm working on my PhD thesis, so my file is a lot more complex than my MWE, hence the many additional questions... Sorry about that.)

Thanks for your time and help so far!!

Bjorn

Comment: The same problem here: You are using page style `empty`, which has to be modified as well. Anyway, I was wondering, why you are using the rather sophisticated code from @Tobi and @Speravir, and then remove the crucial bit, i.e. the code responsible for the vertical placement of the thumb marks?

Comment: Well, I don't think it is the same problem... I use that to get a blank page with no formatting before a new chapter. It works for all other chapters, but not for the bibliography chapter. I think the problem lies with the fact that you do not really define a chapter (like \chapter{bibliography}) and this is causing the issue. Changing "plain" to "fancy" or similar, just puts formatting on the blank page. It does not add the thumb mark... Unless I missed something? And I still have the vertical spread of my thumbs over my entire page, so can you clarify your last question please? Cheers, Bjorn

Comment: You are right, the thumb marks move down. What I meant was, that you removed the code, that resets the vertical position. So after fifteen iterations your thumb mark vanishes below the page.

Comment: The reason I removed the code is the same as why I am here seeking help: I'm not an expert. The example I based my question on was rather specific. I tried to remove code I thought was unnecessary for my purpose. May I ask what code you refer to? Any help is much appreciated! Bjorn