# Can we make a love heart with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, animations, fun

I understand that this post may cause some down votes because it seems a bit off-topic, but having seen [the discussions on Christmas Tree with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz) I am still willing to try.

How do you draw a red cute love heart using LaTeX?

Comment: “Both of us have just started our PhD.” I am sure that you will leave the graphic representation up to her, then. Equations are good enough: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

Comment: @HaroldCavendish Could be a PhD in the humanities...

Comment: Better still, make her a love-heart acrostic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121440/tex-assistance-in-writing-hidden-acrostics/121942#121942

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  Awesome suggestion!

Comment: You also have a [Valentine's heart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113323/1952) in TeXample.net

Comment: You could of course try [3D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tE7MextdB1E) as well (disclaimer: I did it, but there's no LaTeX involved; though you might include an animation in PDFs...)

Comment: @Jubobs Then at least she has enough time for math. :-P

Comment: Here’s some inspiration: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b525044884/f10.image

Comment: @Thérèse: what an amazing fantastic document!!!!

Answer (score 172):

Use `shapepar` to write your note:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype,shapepar,xcolor}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{Crimson}{\heartpar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
    laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis
    nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure
    dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel
    illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan
    et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril
    delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
    nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
    volutpat.}}
\end{document}
```

The longer your note, and the shorter or more “hyphenatable” your words toward the end of the note, the more likely it is that `shapepar` will produce a pleasing shape, without rivers or the underfull lines seen in my image; I recommend `microtype` for the same reason.

[image]

Comment: Why I end up with this error? I am using TexMaker XeLaTeX. ! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tlfontspec/Ligatures/Historic ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}  **and** ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"!! The font "TeX Gyre Chorus" cannot be found.!! See the fontspec documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}

Comment: +1: Combine it with a love poem and you have a truely romantic love heart!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng TeX Gyre Chorus does not have the hlig feature, only the dlig (use `Ligatures=Rare` or `Ligatures=Discretionary`). But that wouldn’t account for the “font-not-found.” Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng shapepar doesn't require any particular fonts, or xetex, so you can experiment with any fonts you normally use.

Comment: I am using Windows OS

Comment: @perfectionm1ng -- What David means is you can simply not load `fontspec` and (therefore) skip the `\setmainfont` command.  If you are using regular `pdflatex`, simply add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (recommended) and choose a font from the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Can you compile the example with luatex?  I’ve sometimes found that xetex can’t find a font luatex does find, or that luatex chokes on a font xetex handles with no trouble.  Also try removing the call to `fontspec`, adding `\usepackage{tgchorus}`, and compiling with pdftex.  If even that doesn’t work, probably you need to re-install tex-gyre.

Comment: I think you should submit this for the 2014 calendar, it would make a great February! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134638/showcase-tex-typography-for-tugs-2014-calendar-and-win-a-book

Comment: @jon do you know how to insert a picture in the center of the heart with the text wrapped around it(multiple narrow lines)? wrapfig didn't work

Comment: @TobiasWille -- Take a look at `cutwin.sty`.

Comment: @jon lead to a bunch of errors, too:  \opencutcenter  \renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example.jpg}} \begin{document} \shapepar{\heartshape}  \begin{cutout}{a}{b}{c}{d} texttextext  \end{cutout} do you know what is whrong with it?

Comment: @Tobias Wille -- Well, that's not how you use `cutwin`.  You should ask a new question: the comments section is not a good venue for solving problems unrelated to the question/answer.

Answer (score 100):

I know this is a bit late, but for reference, OP didn't say what sort of PhD...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\draw[fill=red!30!white](.456,3.236)
    .. controls (.422,4.168) and (.408,5.095) .. (.461,6.046)
    .. controls (.475,6.228) and (.365,6.400) .. (.379,6.601)
    -- (.819,11.816)
    .. controls (.843,12.194) and (.838,13.389) .. (.900,13.972)
    .. controls (.943,14.340) and (2.870,14.340) .. (2.903,13.972)
    .. controls (2.927,13.699) and (2.932,13.436) .. (2.903,13.169)
    -- (1.847,5.401)
    .. controls (1.914,4.627) and (2.033,3.924) .. (2.129,3.193)
    .. controls (2.177,2.906) and (.441,2.863) .. (.456,3.236) ;
\draw[fill=red!30!white] (.456,3.236)
    .. controls (.422,4.168) and (.408,5.095) .. (.461,6.046)
    .. controls (.475,6.228) and (.365,6.400) .. (.379,6.601)
    -- (.819,11.816)
    .. controls (.843,12.194) and (.838,13.389) .. (.900,13.972)
    .. controls (.943,14.340) and (2.870,14.340) .. (2.903,13.972)
    .. controls (2.927,13.699) and (2.932,13.436) .. (2.903,13.169)
    -- (1.847,5.401)
    .. controls (1.914,4.627) and (2.033,3.924) .. (2.129,3.193)
    .. controls (2.177,2.906) and (.441,2.863) .. (.456,3.236) ;
\draw[fill=red!60!white] (.303,6.697)
    .. controls (-.161,7.442) and (-.022,9.641) .. (.484,11.118)
    .. controls (.795,12.022) and (1.297,12.414) .. (2.062,12.801)
    .. controls (3.429,13.513) and (5.112,13.714) .. (6.598,13.795)
    .. controls (9.495,13.957) and (9.738,11.735) .. (8.974,8.967)
    .. controls (8.744,8.126) and (8.123,7.815) .. (7.917,7.222)
    .. controls (7.683,6.606) and (7.310,5.999) .. (6.598,5.420)
    .. controls (5.570,4.579) and (1.230,5.210) .. (.303,6.697) ;
\fill[fill=red!25!white] (2.540,6.405)
    .. controls (2.296,6.257) and (1.890,6.300) .. (1.608,6.424)
    .. controls (1.274,6.577) and (1.101,6.802) .. (1.001,7.151)
    .. controls (.858,7.652) and (1.025,8.293) .. (1.106,8.795)
    .. controls (1.149,9.072) and (1.149,9.402) .. (1.254,9.684)
    .. controls (1.278,9.746) and (1.278,9.823) .. (1.360,9.870)
    .. controls (1.426,9.909) and (1.412,9.732) .. (1.460,9.651)
    .. controls (1.747,9.144) and (2.210,8.346) .. (2.502,7.834)
    .. controls (2.602,7.657) and (2.631,7.437) .. (2.531,7.303)
    .. controls (2.411,7.146) and (2.206,6.883) .. (2.306,6.768)
    .. controls (2.382,6.682) and (2.621,6.453) .. (2.540,6.405) ;
\fill[fill=red!25!white] (4.204,6.606)
    .. controls (5.413,6.434) and (5.327,7.543) .. (5.466,7.796)
    .. controls (5.599,8.054) and (6.350,8.785) .. (6.498,9.029)
    .. controls (6.646,9.273) and (7.282,9.947) .. (7.067,10.616)
    .. controls (6.847,11.290) and (5.776,11.582) .. (5.212,11.429)
    .. controls (4.643,11.271) and (3.773,10.941) .. (3.166,11.113)
    .. controls (2.559,11.280) and (1.350,10.793) .. (1.790,10.052)
    .. controls (2.225,9.311) and (3.640,6.692) .. (4.204,6.606) ;
\draw[fill=yellow] (1.307,3.107)
    .. controls (1.675,3.107) and (1.976,3.169) .. (1.976,3.250)
    .. controls (1.976,3.327) and (1.675,3.394) .. (1.307,3.394)
    .. controls (.934,3.394) and (.633,3.327) .. (.633,3.250)
    .. controls (.633,3.169) and (.934,3.107) .. (1.307,3.107) ;
\draw[fill=blue!20!red!80!white] (1.307,3.107)
    .. controls (1.675,3.107) and (1.976,3.169) .. (1.976,3.250)
    .. controls (1.976,3.327) and (1.675,3.394) .. (1.307,3.394)
    .. controls (.934,3.394) and (.633,3.327) .. (.633,3.250)
    .. controls (.633,3.169) and (.934,3.107) .. (1.307,3.107) ;
\fill[fill=red!10!white] (1.024,14.000)
    .. controls (.991,13.929) and (.924,12.146) .. (1.039,12.323)
    .. controls (1.120,12.452) and (1.498,12.753) .. (1.870,12.767)
    .. controls (2.004,12.777) and (1.918,14.129) .. (1.875,14.163)
    .. controls (1.789,14.230) and (1.110,14.173) .. (1.024,14.000) ;
\fill[fill=red!10!white] (.618,3.432)
    -- (.618,6.247)
    .. controls (.852,5.941) and (1.086,5.745) .. (1.345,5.578)
    .. controls (1.364,5.033) and (1.368,4.125) .. (1.345,3.556)
    .. controls (1.096,3.556) and (.862,3.518) .. (.618,3.432) ;
\draw[fill=white] (4.872,5.215)
    .. controls (4.944,5.607) and (4.891,5.884) .. (4.595,6.061)
    .. controls (4.389,6.185) and (3.749,6.013) .. (3.864,5.664)
    .. controls (3.974,5.339) and (4.088,5.081) .. (4.346,4.923)
    .. controls (4.533,4.813) and (4.858,5.119) .. (4.872,5.215) ;

\draw[fill=red!80!blue] (5.662,5.665)
    .. controls (5.643,5.732) and (5.624,5.803) .. (5.604,5.880)
    .. controls (5.944,6.076) and (6.355,6.640) .. (6.522,7.314)
    .. controls (6.699,8.031) and (6.336,8.284) .. (5.853,8.796)
    .. controls (5.523,9.154) and (5.313,9.541) .. (5.303,10.014)
    .. controls (5.485,9.106) and (5.844,8.958) .. (6.030,8.877)
    .. controls (6.278,8.767) and (6.221,9.221) .. (6.159,10.029)
    .. controls (6.341,9.412) and (6.298,8.944) .. (6.274,8.752)
    .. controls (6.245,8.561) and (6.589,8.370) .. (6.685,8.093)
    .. controls (6.799,7.777) and (6.924,8.069) .. (6.991,8.208)
    .. controls (7.153,8.547) and (7.311,8.681) .. (7.263,8.987)
    .. controls (7.096,10.033) and (6.780,10.387) .. (6.250,10.650)
    .. controls (6.728,10.492) and (6.833,10.373) .. (6.976,10.230)
    .. controls (6.991,10.440) and (6.900,10.870) .. (6.962,11.209)
    .. controls (6.957,10.669) and (7.277,9.197) .. (7.469,9.044)
    .. controls (7.579,8.953) and (8.296,9.632) .. (8.372,10.139)
    .. controls (8.458,10.698) and (8.936,11.535) .. (8.716,12.213)
    .. controls (8.970,11.458) and (8.535,10.636) .. (8.635,10.445)
    .. controls (8.778,10.641) and (9.060,11.037) .. (9.027,11.257)
    .. controls (8.994,11.477) and (9.170,11.874) .. (9.094,12.333)
    .. controls (9.228,11.883) and (9.065,11.702) .. (9.118,11.377)
    .. controls (9.166,11.052) and (8.979,10.626) .. (8.836,10.359)
    .. controls (8.549,9.828) and (7.889,9.187) .. (7.373,8.595)
    .. controls (7.708,8.796) and (8.535,9.077) .. (8.487,9.369)
    .. controls (8.434,9.661) and (8.860,9.900) .. (9.027,10.306)
    .. controls (8.903,9.928) and (8.587,9.656) .. (8.568,9.321)
    .. controls (8.554,8.982) and (8.023,8.815) .. (7.889,8.762)
    .. controls (7.995,8.752) and (8.253,8.748) .. (8.348,8.834)
    .. controls (8.444,8.920) and (8.702,9.097) .. (8.912,9.044)
    .. controls (8.539,9.044) and (8.463,8.671) .. (8.286,8.657)
    .. controls (8.109,8.647) and (7.641,8.566) .. (7.531,8.470)
    .. controls (7.015,8.016) and (6.599,7.223) .. (6.819,7.271)
    .. controls (7.344,7.381) and (7.899,7.471) .. (8.377,7.988)
    .. controls (8.023,7.567) and (7.999,7.562) .. (7.478,7.314)
    .. controls (7.091,7.137) and (6.537,6.979) .. (6.355,6.511)
    .. controls (6.250,6.229) and (5.887,5.789) .. (5.662,5.665) ;
\draw[fill=red!80!blue] (3.387,5.951)
    .. controls (3.779,7.003) and (2.665,8.600) .. (1.857,9.866)
    .. controls (1.384,10.607) and (1.704,11.157) .. (2.364,11.305)
    .. controls (2.842,11.410) and (4.515,11.004) .. (4.993,11.023)
    .. controls (5.480,11.037) and (5.604,10.856) .. (5.882,10.559)
    .. controls (5.815,10.894) and (5.256,11.305) .. (4.997,11.209)
    .. controls (4.735,11.114) and (4.199,11.229) .. (3.975,11.338)
    .. controls (4.280,11.425) and (4.787,11.401) .. (5.179,11.601)
    .. controls (5.571,11.802) and (5.920,11.750) .. (6.159,11.300)
    .. controls (6.140,11.730) and (5.538,11.955) .. (5.126,11.783)
    .. controls (4.715,11.616) and (3.736,11.434) .. (3.401,11.434)
    .. controls (3.176,11.429) and (3.009,11.468) .. (2.617,11.563)
    .. controls (3.324,11.635) and (4.252,12.084) .. (5.165,12.304)
    .. controls (5.863,12.471) and (6.680,12.452) .. (6.790,12.189)
    .. controls (6.895,11.946) and (7.072,11.840) .. (7.473,11.793)
    .. controls (7.000,12.008) and (6.866,12.156) .. (6.814,12.438)
    .. controls (7.015,12.490) and (7.411,12.256) .. (7.626,12.457)
    .. controls (7.846,12.658) and (8.439,12.653) .. (8.864,12.381)
    .. controls (8.386,12.730) and (7.770,12.710) .. (7.607,12.557)
    .. controls (7.445,12.405) and (7.077,12.553) .. (6.862,12.591)
    .. controls (6.647,12.634) and (6.446,12.644) .. (5.891,12.548)
    .. controls (5.714,12.620) and (5.657,12.715) .. (5.867,12.792)
    .. controls (6.082,12.835) and (6.537,12.806) .. (7.014,12.806)
    .. controls (7.258,12.806) and (7.430,12.935) .. (7.631,12.811)
    .. controls (7.832,12.682) and (8.033,12.873) .. (8.324,13.016)
    .. controls (7.999,12.906) and (7.746,12.768) .. (7.660,12.897)
    .. controls (7.574,13.031) and (7.263,12.916) .. (7.163,12.940)
    .. controls (7.292,12.992) and (7.493,12.935) .. (7.507,13.136)
    .. controls (7.526,13.337) and (8.057,13.284) .. (7.999,13.652)
    .. controls (7.923,13.294) and (7.540,13.423) .. (7.406,13.179)
    .. controls (7.277,12.940) and (6.885,13.055) .. (6.680,13.031)
    .. controls (6.250,12.973) and (5.557,13.074) .. (5.461,12.639)
    .. controls (5.217,12.600) and (4.921,12.514) .. (4.682,12.419)
    .. controls (4.687,12.538) and (5.103,13.026) .. (5.461,13.102)
    .. controls (5.815,13.174) and (6.532,13.155) .. (6.699,13.681)
    .. controls (6.345,13.174) and (5.614,13.356) .. (5.294,13.260)
    .. controls (4.978,13.160) and (4.213,12.285) .. (3.898,12.189)
    .. controls (3.583,12.099) and (3.272,11.922) .. (3.157,11.989)
    .. controls (3.062,12.084) and (3.119,12.600) .. (3.583,12.581)
    .. controls (4.046,12.562) and (4.362,12.882) .. (4.620,13.356)
    .. controls (4.271,12.897) and (3.721,12.615) .. (3.358,12.744)
    .. controls (2.990,12.868) and (2.823,11.936) .. (2.598,11.812)
    .. controls (2.373,11.683) and (1.594,11.377) .. (1.503,11.042)
    .. controls (1.465,11.377) and (2.106,11.903) .. (2.043,12.677)
    .. controls (1.953,11.922) and (1.522,11.783) .. (1.317,11.377)
    .. controls (1.111,10.966) and (1.212,10.555) .. (1.417,9.991)
    .. controls (1.422,9.971) and (3.836,6.267) .. (2.588,5.985)
    .. controls (2.235,5.904) and (1.981,5.813) .. (1.757,5.660)
    .. controls (1.871,4.489) and (2.187,2.481) .. (2.650,2.405)
    .. controls (3.176,2.314) and (4.185,2.878) .. (4.175,3.289)
    .. controls (4.166,3.724) and (3.817,4.766) .. (3.994,5.201)
    .. controls (3.759,5.397) and (3.277,5.617) .. (3.387,5.951) ;
\fill[fill=red!90!blue!70!white] (2.942,5.378)
    .. controls (2.875,5.339) and (2.736,5.378) .. (2.722,5.459)
    .. controls (2.712,5.535) and (2.741,5.583) .. (2.779,5.674)
    .. controls (3.013,6.066) and (3.200,6.716) .. (2.980,7.266)
    .. controls (2.803,7.720) and (2.564,8.226) .. (2.296,8.661)
    .. controls (2.048,9.068) and (1.627,9.670) .. (1.565,10.363)
    .. controls (1.579,10.105) and (1.837,9.737) .. (1.952,9.512)
    .. controls (2.263,8.905) and (3.071,7.815) .. (3.214,7.180)
    .. controls (3.362,6.534) and (3.243,5.875) .. (3.071,5.597)
    .. controls (3.066,5.540) and (3.028,5.425) .. (2.942,5.378) ;
\fill[fill=red!90!blue!70!white] (2.793,2.424)
    .. controls (2.253,3.542) and (2.115,3.948) .. (2.014,5.712)
    .. controls (2.019,5.784) and (2.349,5.903) .. (2.339,5.841)
    .. controls (2.301,4.665) and (2.650,3.289) .. (3.138,2.486)
    .. controls (3.032,2.447) and (2.870,2.419) .. (2.793,2.424) ;
\draw (2.526,6.104)
    .. controls (2.990,5.937) and (2.541,6.688) .. (2.545,6.673)
    .. controls (2.454,6.831) and (2.521,6.869) .. (2.564,6.922)
    .. controls (2.717,7.123) and (2.932,7.165) .. (2.660,7.471) ;
\draw (.461,3.241)
    .. controls (.576,3.657) and (2.187,3.657) .. (2.129,3.198) ;
\draw[fill=red!30!white] (3.687,5.731)
    .. controls (3.520,6.229) and (5.541,6.616) .. (5.556,6.214)
    .. controls (5.570,5.827) and (5.790,5.325) .. (5.800,4.919)
    .. controls (5.809,4.584) and (4.480,4.250) .. (4.308,4.517)
    .. controls (4.084,4.866) and (3.854,5.249) .. (3.687,5.731) ;
\draw (4.299,4.531)
    .. controls (4.189,4.885) and (5.752,5.315) .. (5.800,4.961) ;
\draw[fill=blue!20!red!80!white] (5.097,4.594)
    .. controls (5.436,4.694) and (5.699,4.823) .. (5.680,4.919)
    .. controls (5.656,5.009) and (5.360,5.000) .. (5.020,4.899)
    .. controls (4.681,4.799) and (4.428,4.675) .. (4.452,4.584)
    .. controls (4.475,4.493) and (4.757,4.493) .. (5.097,4.594) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful answer! I wish I had a similar control using `controls`. You should try to answer: [Holiday contest! Drawing a picture of Krampus for Yule](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149604/holiday-contest-drawing-a-picture-of-krampus-for-yule/149629#149629). :)

Comment: They're not my paths - they're from clip art, with some filters to convert .eps paths to tikz paths.  For Krampus, I'd have to find the vector artwork to do the conversion.

Comment: Nice work! I'm really impressed. How did you get all of those points?

Comment: @jvriesem - They're not my points - they're from clip art, with some filters to convert .eps points to tikz points.

Comment: Similarly, percusse and Paul Gaborit explain:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172336/drawing-roman-laurel-leaves-spqr-in-tikz  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/how-to-export-svg-to-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 84):

### Still version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Animated version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPeval\Delta{round(2*pi/30:2)}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.00+\Delta}{31}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
    \psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15},linecolor=red]{0}{\n}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

### Photo Clipper

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{pretty}}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=100,
    xunit=.5\wd\IBox,
    yunit=.5\ht\IBox,
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1.5)
\begin{psclip}{\psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\rput(0,1.25){%
    \color{red}\large
    $\displaystyle\!
    \begin{aligned}
        x(t)&=\sin^3 t\\
        y(t)&=(13\cos t -5\cos 2t -2\cos 3t -\cos 4t)/16
    \end{aligned}$}
\rput(0,1){HAPPY BIRTHDAY}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### PDF animated version

Compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename` as there are some `\immediate\write18{}` in my code below.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{heart.tex}
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=3]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=1000,
    xunit=.5\wd\IBox,
    yunit=.5\ht\IBox,
    linewidth=10pt,
}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPeval\Delta{round(2*pi/30:2)}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\multido{\n=0.00+\Delta}{31}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1.5)
\begin{psclip}{\psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\rput(0,1.25){%
    \color{red}\large
    $\displaystyle\!
    \begin{aligned}
        x(t)&=\sin^3 t\\
        y(t)&=(13\cos t -5\cos 2t -2\cos 3t -\cos 4t)/16
    \end{aligned}$}
\rput(0,1){HAPPY BIRTHDAY}
\psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15},linecolor=red]{0}{\n}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
 \end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{animate}
\immediate\write18{latex heart}
\immediate\write18{dvips heart}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf heart.ps}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{7}{heart}{}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mein Gott! Danke shoen! I like the animated one!

Comment: As usual, please focus on the code rather than on the dummy picture.

Comment: Sorry I can't do that. I don't even see the browser window :)

Comment: Yes I will marry her. Wait, what question... `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: The question is "when was Visual Studio 2013 released?".

Comment: Completely awesome.

Comment: Hopefully they up-voted for my code and not for the dummy picture.

Comment: @Marienplatz no, they didn't (but I did:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: :-(

Answer (score 59):

A three-dimensional version- nice to have an application of volumes of revolution

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/colormap={pink}{color(0cm)=(purple); color(1cm)=(pink!80!purple); color(2cm)=(pink!90); color(3cm)=(pink) }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{10},
            axis equal,
            axis lines=none,
            colormap name =pink, 
        ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=faceted,
            samples=50,
            domain=0:2*pi,y domain=0:2*pi,
            z buffer=sort,
        opacity=0.15]
        (
        {(sin(deg(x)))^3*cos(deg(y))},
        {(sin(deg(x)))^3*sin(deg(y))},
        {(13*cos(deg(x))-5*cos(2*deg(x))-2*cos(3*deg(x))-cos(4*deg(x)))/16}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For my wife :) Maybe this will convince her to learn `LaTeX` and join the site?

Comment: Beautiful! She will definitely learn and join *Anyway, she will need it to write thesis LOL*

Comment: Ah Ah AAAAhhh! No words!

Comment: Love is best expressed in three dimensions. Be careful, the bottom cusp is rather sharp (infinitely sharp, actually - don't touch it).

Comment: Beautiful plot! I added it to the [PGFplots example gallery](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/heart-3d/).

Answer (score 58):

This may be cheesy and slightly off-topic, but here goes... Because my girlfriend's present still hadn't arrived on her birthday, I had to improvise; I made a coupon similar to the following, which she really liked. Perhaps that could give you ideas...

Of course, don't forget to buy her a real present. Most women don't like cheapskates :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\newcommand\mycoupon{%
    ￼\begin{tikzpicture}[color=Maroon,
                        every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
     %\draw[help lines] (-6,-3) grid (6,3);
     \node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=6cm](vecbox){};
     \draw[thin, gray!20]
          (vecbox.north west)
       -- (vecbox.north east)
       -- (vecbox.south east)
       -- (vecbox.south west)
       -- cycle;
     \node[anchor=north west] at (vecbox.north west)
          {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
     \node[anchor=north east] at (vecbox.north east)
          {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
     \node[anchor=south west] at (vecbox.south west)
          {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
     \node[anchor=south east] at (vecbox.south east)
          {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
        \node at (0,0)
        {
            \LARGE
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            Coupon for one snuggle time\\
            with \textbf{Farticle Pilter}
            \end{tabular}
        };
        \node at (0,-2.7)
        {
            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            Coupon redeemable by \textbf{insert name} only, whenever she wants.\\
            Issued on \textbf{insert date}. Does not expire\ldots{} ever!
            \end{tabular}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\mycoupon\\[1em]
\mycoupon\\[1em]
\mycoupon


\end{document}
```

Comment: dude it's sweet! Thanks! BTW, your advice on real present helps. haha!

Comment: How fo I handle this error? ! LaTeX Error: File `pgfornament.sty' not found. Thanks!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng You must install Alain Matthes's `pgfornament` package. I don't think it's part of any distribution yet. You can download it from [there](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html).

Comment: Excellent and very simple to do apparently :-)

Answer (score 44):

a beating heart ...

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,multido}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=1000,unit=5,linewidth=10pt}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=20+20}{4}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.1)(1,0.8)
  \psparametricplot[linecolor=red!50,fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=red!\iA,linejoin=1]{0}{\psPiTwo}%
    {sin(t)^3 | (13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t))/16}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

for the animation:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 300 -alpha remove heart.pdf heart.gif
```

And the same as a 3D cardioid:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=20+20,\iB=10+20,\iC=150+10}{4}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)% the main 2D area
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=50 -20 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=\iC}
\defFunction[algebraic]{heart}(u,v)
   { sin(u)^3*cos(v) }%                               x=f(u,v)
   { sin(u)^3*sin(v) }%                               y=f(u,v)
   { (13*cos(u)-5*cos(2*u)-2*cos(3*u)-cos(4*u))/16 }% z=f(u)
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,linecolor=red!\iB,
 base=0 pi pi 4 div neg 5 pi mul 2 div,
 fillcolor=red!\iA,function=heart,linewidth=0.1\pslinewidth,ngrid=40]
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I hope she does not suffer from epilepsy. By the way, `pst-plot` automatically loads `multido`.

Comment: Cool! I like it a lot!

Comment: no, I am so nervous that you may like it .... ;-)

Comment: I am compiling it with XeLaTeX, texmaker. The heart is seperated into 4 pages, each page showing a static  heart with one color. Any idea?

Comment: see my edit, there is the command for creating the animated gif

Comment: Thanks, but where should I put that line? I am a newbie. Thanks

Comment: @Marienplatz  Oh, I thought I could directly render it into a gif in texmaker... What I wish is to send my GF the code and let her run.. This extra line of command that requires an installtion will definitely ruined the fun...

Comment: Extremely beautiful 3D beating heart.

Answer (score 39):

Here's a TikZing heart!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) .. controls (0,0.75) and (-1.5,1.00) .. (-1.5,2)  arc (180:0:0.75)  -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) .. controls (0,0.75) and ( 1.5,1.00) .. ( 1.5,2)  arc (0:180:0.75) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Simple and classic! Thanks! Where should I touch if I wanna make it bigger w.r.t. the A4 paper?

Comment: You can pass `x=2cm,y=2cm` as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng have a look at the `standalone` documentclass- it was made for images :)

Answer (score 33):

Unicode has many to choose from: `xetex '\font\tenrm="Symbola:color=DD0000" at 3cm \rm ♥ ❤ ♡ \char"1F497\ \char"1F493\ \char"1F498 \bye'`

[image]

Comment: I'm new. Any reason you're using XeTex rather than the standard LaTeX?

Comment: @jvriesem: I rarely use LaTeX; when I need something so complicated that I think it's not worth the effort to do in plain XeTeX/LuaTeX, I go for ConTeXt. But note that you can do the same thing as in this example with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX: the only requirements are a Unicode-aware engine and a font which includes the glyphs. Though, you'd want to use an abstraction layer for the font-loading (ie. package `fontspec`) so you can use the features of LaTeX New Font Selection Scheme (NFSS). Oh, and warm welcome to tex.se! :-)

Answer (score 27):

And then there's Knuth's METAFONT heart, adapted here for Metapost.  See p.134 of the METAFONT book.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "heart.eps";
beginfig(1);
path heart, p;
heart = (100,162) .. (140,178){right} .. (195,125){down}
     .. (100,0){curl 0} .. (100,0){curl 0} .. {up}(5,125) .. {right}(60,178) .. (100,162);
p = (100,200) -- (200,200) -- (200,100) -- (200,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,100) -- (0,200) -- (100,200);
for n=0 upto 10: draw interpath(n/10,p,heart) withcolor .987red; endfor
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Joining late the party!!!

A very simple heart beat proposal with [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) and some shading:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,shadows}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{heart}{\pgfpoint{-0.275cm}{0.4cm}}{%
  color(0cm)=(tikz@ball!60!white);
  color(0.4cm)=(tikz@ball!85!white); 
  color(0.7cm)=(tikz@ball); 
  color(0.9925cm)=(tikz@ball!75!black); 
  rgb(1cm)=(1,1,1)
}
\tikzoption{heart on color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{heart on}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}

\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{heart}{\pgfpoint{-0.275cm}{0.4cm}}{%
  color(0cm)=(tikz@ball!80!white);
  color(0.4cm)=(tikz@ball!90!white); 
  color(0.7cm)=(tikz@ball); 
  color(0.9925cm)=(tikz@ball!75!black); 
  rgb(1cm)=(1,1,1)
}
\tikzoption{heart color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{heart}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\makeatother

% original code by Daniel:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer#55849
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    },
}

% original code in
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes#84608
\tikzset{
  background shade/.style={#1},
  shade on/.style={alt=#1{}{background shade}},
  background shade/.default={shading=heart,heart color=red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\path[drop shadow,heart on color=red,shade on=<{2,4,6,8,9,12,13}>] 
(0,0) to[curve through={(0.25,0.4) .. (0.5,0.6) .. (0.5,1.2) .. (0.4,1.25)}]  (0,1) 
(0,1) to[curve through={(-0.4,1.25)..(-0.5,1.2) .. (-0.5,0.6).. (-0.25,0.4)}](0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `\draw[use Hobby shortcut] ([out angle=85,in angle=85]0,0) .. (1,0) .. ([Hobby finish]0,-2) .. ([out angle=95,in angle=95]-1,0) .. (0,0);`

Comment: @AndrewStacey: definitely more elegant :) But my twisted mind prefers coordinates...

Answer (score 18):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\rule[-2pt]{0pt}{10pt}
\textcolor{red}{$\varheart$}
\rule{0pt}{10pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: heart]

Comment: Red color with arrow missing otherwise perfect

Comment: What's with the struts?

Comment: The struts prevent standalone from chopping off the top of the heart; I tried without them and it looked even worse.

Comment: `\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{10}{\textcolor{red}{$\varheart$}}
\end{document}` is my suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

From [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/valentine-heart/), the author is Alain Matthes:

```
% Valentine heart
% Author: Alain Matthes
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ball color=BrickRed,shading=ball] (4,1) ..controls +(120:2cm)
        and +(90:2cm) .. (0,0) .. controls  +(-90:2cm) and +(90:3cm) ..
        (4,-8) .. controls +(90:3cm) and +(-90:2cm) ..(8,0)  .. controls
        +(90:2cm) and  +(60:2cm) .. (4,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### A very simple heart made with `PGFPlots` (compile twice):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\definecolor{left}{HTML}{f00000}    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215917/152550

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
        \addplot[shading=axis,rectangle,left color=left,right color=left!30!white,shading angle=135,very thick,variable=t,domain=0:360,samples=150] ({16*sin(t)*sin(t)*sin(t)},{13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Heart]

Answer (score 3):

With a parametric curve in TikZ (rather than pgfplots) and without using `controls`

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\fill [red, thick,  domain=-200:200, samples=50] 
        plot ({ .67*sin(\x) * sin(\x) * sin(\x) + .5 }, 
              { .65 * cos(\x) - .2 * cos(2*\x) - .1 * cos(3*\x) - .05 * cos(4*\x) - .4 } );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By means of a pgfplots code, I drew a plot using the formula of a heart. I have the formula from what is presented in [this webpage](https://pavpanchekha.com/blog/heart-polar-coordinates.html), but I have changed some variables to make a nicer heart plot. Also, higher amounts of samples gives better

[image]

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(deg(#1))*sqrt(abs(cos(deg(#1)))))/(sin(deg(#1))+8/5)-1.5*sin(deg(#1))+1.5}}
\begin{axis}
        [
        hide x axis,
        hide y axis,
        domain=-pi:pi,
        samples=1000,
        data cs=polarrad,
        ]
        \addplot [solid, thick,red,fill=red] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And if you are a heartbroken, you can draw this instead :D

[image]

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(deg(#1))*sqrt(abs(cos(deg(#1)))))/(sin(deg(#1))+8/5)-1.5*sin(deg(#1))+1.5}}
\begin{axis}
        [
        hide axis,
        ]
        \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
        \addplot [domain=-0.5:1,samples=10,solid,very thick,black,fill=red,smooth] ({x-1},{1.25*x-2});
        \addplot [->,domain=1.968:2.5,samples=10,solid,very thick,black,fill=red,smooth] ({x-1},{1.25*x-2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A minimalist π heart:

```
\documentclass[border=20,tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\tikz\draw[rotate=90,very thick,domain=0:3.1416,smooth]
plot(\x r:\x*2) plot(-\x r:\x*2); 
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]