# non rectangular body geometry with xintools failed when verse used

Tags: margins, shapes, shapepar, xint, irregular-shape

I use the solution suggested in “[Non-rectangular body geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148883/non-rectangular-body-geometry/164287#164287)” by the (deleted) user @user4686 but the render failed when it reached a `verse` environment in the body:

#### The MWE

As I need the non-rectangle shape for a document part only and not the wide document I remove the `\cnta` repetition commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\def\LINESPERPAGE{45}
\usepackage[textheight=\LINESPERPAGE\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xinttools}% requires version 1.09m or later
\usepackage{poemscol}


% let's divide by two the sizes of the undulation.
\edef\MOCKSINE {%
{1.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5em}%
{2em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}%
{2.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.5em}%
{2.875em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.875em}%
{3em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-3em}%
{2.875em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.875em}%
{2.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.5em}%
{2em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}%
{1.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5em}%
{1em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}%
{.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-.5em}%
{0.125em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-0.125em}%
{0em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-0em}%
{0.125em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-0.125em}%
{.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-.5em}%
{1em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}%
}


\makeatletter

\edef\MCK@LINESPERPAGE {\the\numexpr \LINESPERPAGE\relax }

\def\MCK@LINECOUNT {0}

\def\SETUPPARSHAPE {%
  \xdef\MCK@tmpB {\the\numexpr \pagetotal/\baselineskip}%
  \ifnum\MCK@tmpA>\MCK@tmpB
  % assume we are on a new page. !!!Something more robust should be done here!!!
  \xdef\MCK@LINECOUNT
   {\the\numexpr\MCK@LINECOUNT+\MCK@tmpB-\MCK@tmpA+\MCK@LINESPERPAGE}%
  \else
  \xdef\MCK@LINECOUNT {\the\numexpr\MCK@LINECOUNT+\MCK@tmpB-\MCK@tmpA}%
  \fi
  \global\let\MCK@tmpA\MCK@tmpB   
  \edef\STARTINDEX {\the\numexpr\MCK@LINECOUNT+16-16*((\MCK@LINECOUNT+8)/16)}%
  \parshape 16 \xintListWithSep { }{\xintTrim \STARTINDEX\MOCKSINE}
               \xintListWithSep { }{\xintKeep \STARTINDEX\MOCKSINE} \relax
}

\def\STARTUNDULATIONS {\def\MCK@LINECOUNT {0}\def\MCK@tmpA {0}%
    \def\par {\oldpar \SETUPPARSHAPE }\SETUPPARSHAPE }
\def\STOPUNDULATIONS {\let\par\oldpar }
\makeatother

\let\oldpar\par
\AtBeginDocument {\STARTUNDULATIONS }

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\lipsum %[\cnta-\numexpr\cnta+3\relax]


\begin{verse}
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
\end{verse}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

#### The rendering

[image: rendering with a verse]

As I said the shape is correctly aplied in the whool document exepted when it reach the `verse` environement.

#### The goal

The goal is to force the shape to be applied in the full body included the `verse` environment and to keep going unless I use `\STOPUNDULATIONS` command.

So how can I patch the code to force `verse` environment to follow the shape?

Comment: verse is a list and all latex lists work by using the same parshape mechanism so merging would be hard, simpler to just define a new verse environment that uses  your specified parshape but with shape modiffied to increase teh left indent and decrease the text width in each line

Comment: True, I was feeling the list environement it’s hard to merge with parshape.

Comment: Are you preparing a new edition of Apollinaire's *Calligrammes*, per chance?

Comment: Haha, I was waiting someone ask this quesiton ^^ So, not realy, I make my own poems editions (including some calligrammes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to define a verse enviornment that does not internally rely on the paragraph shape so you do not need to merge. Here I simply define it to add some vertical space and to locally define `\\`  to be end of paragraph. I force the extra indent here filled with dots to make the undulating margin clearer, you could not indent or indent with space just by omitting `\dotfill`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\def\LINESPERPAGE{45}
\usepackage[textheight=\LINESPERPAGE\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xinttools}% requires version 1.09m or later
\renewenvironment{verse}
{\par\parindent=0pt\smallskip\everypar{\makebox[25pt]{\dotfill}}\let\\\par}
{\par\smallskip}


% let's divide by two the sizes of the undulation.
\edef\MOCKSINE {%
{1.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5em}%
{2em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}%
{2.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.5em}%
{2.875em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.875em}%
{3em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-3em}%
{2.875em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.875em}%
{2.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2.5em}%
{2em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}%
{1.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5em}%
{1em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}%
{.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-.5em}%
{0.125em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-0.125em}%
{0em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-0em}%
{0.125em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-0.125em}%
{.5em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-.5em}%
{1em \the\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}%
}


\makeatletter

\edef\MCK@LINESPERPAGE {\the\numexpr \LINESPERPAGE\relax }

\def\MCK@LINECOUNT {0}

\def\SETUPPARSHAPE {%
  \xdef\MCK@tmpB {\the\numexpr \pagetotal/\baselineskip}%
  \ifnum\MCK@tmpA>\MCK@tmpB
  % assume we are on a new page. !!!Something more robust should be done here!!!
  \xdef\MCK@LINECOUNT
   {\the\numexpr\MCK@LINECOUNT+\MCK@tmpB-\MCK@tmpA+\MCK@LINESPERPAGE}%
  \else
  \xdef\MCK@LINECOUNT {\the\numexpr\MCK@LINECOUNT+\MCK@tmpB-\MCK@tmpA}%
  \fi
  \global\let\MCK@tmpA\MCK@tmpB   
  \edef\STARTINDEX {\the\numexpr\MCK@LINECOUNT+16-16*((\MCK@LINECOUNT+8)/16)}%
  \parshape 16 \xintListWithSep { }{\xintTrim \STARTINDEX\MOCKSINE}
               \xintListWithSep { }{\xintKeep \STARTINDEX\MOCKSINE} \relax
}

\def\STARTUNDULATIONS {\def\MCK@LINECOUNT {0}\def\MCK@tmpA {0}%
    \def\par {\oldpar \SETUPPARSHAPE }\SETUPPARSHAPE }
\def\STOPUNDULATIONS {\let\par\oldpar }
\makeatother

\let\oldpar\par
\AtBeginDocument {\STARTUNDULATIONS }

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\lipsum %[\cnta-\numexpr\cnta+3\relax]


\begin{verse}
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
This is a verse \\
\end{verse}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```