# ornaments in pgfornament to be at the corners at every page

Tags: tikz-pgf

Now, I have the following code producing the output as shown:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node[text width=8cm,align=center](Text){%
In visions of the dark night
I have dreamed of joy departed-
But a waking dream of life and
light Hath left me broken-hearted.
Ah! what is not a dream by day
To him whose eyes are cast
On things around him with a ray
Turned back upon the past?
That holy dream- that holy dream,
While all the world were chiding,
Hath cheered me as a lovely beam
A lonely spirit guiding.
What though that light, thro’ storm and night,
So trembled from afar-
What could there be more purely bright
In Truth’s day-star?
A Dream (1827) by Edgar Allan Poe} ;
\node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)
at (Text.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}};
\node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)
at (Text.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
\node[shift={(-1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south west](CSW)
at (Text.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
\node[shift={(1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south east](CSE)
at (Text.south east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
\pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{87}
\pgfornamenthline{CSW}{CSE}{south}{87}
\pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{87}
\pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{87}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to make the ornaments come at the corners for every page and the leaves to be removed. How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139736/21891

Comment: You deleted a recent post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159642/writing-text-in-the-tikz-rectangle-and-attaching-it-to-the-background-for-every.  If you undelete it, I have something of an answer for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another option with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}}}
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-50,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-50,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}}}
   }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node[anchor=north west](CNW)
at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}};
\node[anchor=north east](CNE)
at (current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
\node[anchor=south west](CSW)
at (current page.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
\node[anchor=south east](CSE)
at (current page.south east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to do the same thing, but with keeping the leaves.