# Writing Text In the TikZ Rectangle and attaching it to the background for every page

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=orange,orange, rounded corners] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (2,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

How I make the rectangle more curved something like this:
[image]

The code above generates me the following output:

[image]

Now How do I write text inside the rectangle (vertically letter by letter) and I want to move it to right middle margin for right end pages of the book and left middle margin for the left pages. The text in `lipsum` must be at the beginning as every other page and I want the rectangle on every page of the article. For writing text in the rectangle I would like to use this font:

[image]

Comment: You are asking for tons of different things at the same time. Break your question into different parts so that someone even considers answering it.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking multiple questions at the same time. I'm answering your first one. I strongly recommend you reading section 16 of the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=orange,rounded corners=1cm,text width=0.2\textwidth,inner sep=0.4cm] {\lipsum[2]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]