# eso-pic code for page ornament changing geometry custom page settings to US-Letter

Tags: positioning, geometry, eso-pic

I am trying to use this page decorating code given in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159614/22840). But using this is ignoring my geometry page setting and changing page dimensions to US-Letter. How to debug this? How to correct this?

**Edit1:** I think `memoir` class is creating problem. When I ran same code with `book` class it works well. But I need `memoir` for other purposes. What is the solution to the problem?

This is MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[text={4.3in,6.95in},
%layoutsize={5.25in,8in},
papersize={5.25in,8in},
ignorefoot,
ignoremp,
headsep=11pt,
centering
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159614/22840  --user11232
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}}}
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-50,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-50,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}}}
   }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need to use [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir)?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: `memoir` has its own way of setting the page layout and geometry, and it doesn't work with the [`geometry` package](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry). So either drop `geometry` and use `memoir` stock/layout settings, or drop `memoir` and use `geometry`. It seems like you're after the former, correct?