# Drawing Roman laurel leaves (SPQR) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to get the symbol of the old [Roman emblem (SPQR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPQR).  I'm actually interested in the laurel leaves, and not so much in the banner *per se*.

What I would like to have is something like this (in `Tikz`, as oppose to simply `\includegraphics`).  With the possibility to change the stylish `A` to any other simple roman letter.

[image]

I'm a complete newbie with TikZ, and even though I know this question sounds like *do this for me*, I would really appreciate if someone could at least throw in an sketch where to start.

Comment: This isn’t quite what you want, but it might give you some ideas: http://texblog.org/tag/laurel-leaves/

Comment: @alexwlchan This is a great starting point! :)

Comment: You can always draw it with Inkscape or throw this to potrace and get the TikZ code back.

Comment: @percusse Could you write an answer with an example?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First you clean up the bitmap in even Paint and remove the unnecessary bits and save your file as a `.bmp`. Such as

[image]

### Tracing with POTrace

Then download [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) and in the command window simply type

```
potrace <filename>.bmp
```

And that would give you a vector file format `.eps`, (I optionally convert it to PDF for ease). The quality of the trace is inverse proportional with the complexity of the figure. Sometimes it's amazing sometimes it gets confused.

### Converting to TikZ code

Download and install Inkscape. Add Inkscape to TikZ exporter extension from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). Download `tikz_export.py, tikz_export_effect.inx`, and `tikz_export_output.inx` from the External links on the bottom of the left panel. Put them in the `share-->extension` directory inside the Inkscape installation directory.

Export from the menu: `Extension -> Export -> Export to TikZ path`.  An option window shows up.  Choose your option and export from there (either into a file by specification, or in the clipboard).

So we get

[image]

Here is the resulting file I got.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[cm={{1.25,0.0,0.0,-1.25,(0.0,838.75)}}]% g2993
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.100]% g2995
    % path2997
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (1189.0000,5151.6900) .. controls
      (1023.0300,5080.8400) and (878.5270,4938.0000) .. (799.8440,4767.0000) ..
      controls (767.6330,4697.0000) and (737.5200,4600.2400) .. (748.0000,4600.4100)
      .. controls (781.3520,4600.9500) and (948.2810,4728.0000) ..
      (1001.0500,4793.0000) .. controls (1061.1200,4867.0000) and
      (1260.0000,5155.0100) .. (1260.0000,5168.0000) .. controls
      (1260.0000,5183.1800) and (1266.0000,5184.5600) .. (1189.0000,5151.6900);

    % path2999
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (4700.0000,5167.0000) .. controls
      (4700.0000,5153.4500) and (4847.3600,4938.0000) .. (4932.5600,4827.0000) ..
      controls (5001.6400,4737.0000) and (5189.3400,4585.8500) ..
      (5208.2400,4605.0000) .. controls (5217.2900,4614.1700) and
      (5192.5700,4698.0000) .. (5160.4600,4767.0000) .. controls
      (5078.5800,4943.0000) and (4918.4700,5096.9000) .. (4751.0000,5160.6000) ..
      controls (4713.0000,5175.0500) and (4700.0000,5176.6900) ..
      (4700.0000,5167.0000);

    % path3001
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (734.7660,4967.0000) .. controls
      (629.0630,4857.9200) and (554.9570,4720.0000) .. (525.7460,4578.0000) ..
      controls (501.2660,4459.0000) and (506.9690,4192.0200) .. (535.9140,4102.0000)
      .. controls (545.8910,4070.9700) and (896.6720,4416.0000) ..
      (992.3980,4551.0000) .. controls (1085.2900,4682.0000) and
      (1160.5200,4822.9900) .. (1127.0000,4803.2600) .. controls
      (1068.0000,4768.5300) and (724.4410,4501.3300) .. (703.6410,4474.0000) ..
      controls (689.1800,4455.0000) and (675.2300,4440.8300) .. (673.1290,4443.0000)
      .. controls (668.5080,4447.7700) and (715.5080,4726.0000) ..
      (730.2270,4781.0000) .. controls (736.6480,4805.0000) and (755.6370,4867.5000)
      .. (772.0000,4918.5000) .. controls (788.3630,4969.5000) and
      (799.2730,5014.7300) .. (796.0000,5018.0000) .. controls (792.7380,5021.2600)
      and (764.8050,4998.0000) .. (734.7660,4967.0000);

    % path3003
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (5162.5900,5004.0000) .. controls
      (5165.5500,4993.6100) and (5184.2300,4932.0000) .. (5203.8400,4868.0000) ..
      controls (5236.0000,4763.0000) and (5295.9900,4452.6400) ..
      (5286.0000,4442.9000) .. controls (5283.7800,4440.7300) and
      (5269.7700,4455.0000) .. (5254.4700,4475.0000) .. controls
      (5233.2700,4502.7200) and (4899.0000,4762.9700) .. (4833.0000,4803.1400) ..
      controls (4799.2700,4823.6700) and (4875.0500,4682.0000) ..
      (4967.8800,4551.0000) .. controls (5063.5400,4416.0000) and
      (5414.2000,4070.9700) .. (5424.2100,4102.0000) .. controls
      (5438.9800,4147.8300) and (5450.0000,4264.0000) .. (5450.0000,4374.0000) ..
      controls (5450.0000,4568.0000) and (5416.7000,4697.2800) ..
      (5332.8100,4829.0000) .. controls (5264.0300,4937.0000) and
      (5147.5600,5056.7400) .. (5162.5900,5004.0000);

    % path3005
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (430.8980,4615.0000) .. controls
      (384.6910,4550.2300) and (332.9340,4433.0000) .. (308.1600,4337.0000) ..
      controls (291.5470,4272.6100) and (287.0000,4226.0000) .. (287.0000,4120.0000)
      .. controls (287.0000,3969.0600) and (298.3240,3904.0000) ..
      (359.2190,3705.0000) .. controls (381.2500,3633.0000) and (404.8010,3549.1300)
      .. (412.0000,3517.0000) .. controls (419.1720,3485.0000) and
      (429.0350,3459.0000) .. (434.0000,3459.0000) .. controls (438.9260,3459.0000)
      and (450.6450,3483.0000) .. (459.8830,3512.0000) .. controls
      (482.4840,3582.9600) and (500.0000,3615.0000) .. (590.0000,3750.0000) ..
      controls (699.3320,3914.0000) and (782.2230,4054.2700) .. (817.5120,4135.0000)
      .. controls (852.0390,4214.0000) and (884.6760,4319.3200) ..
      (877.0000,4327.0000) .. controls (874.2770,4329.7200) and (836.0000,4300.1200)
      .. (793.0000,4262.0400) .. controls (665.0000,4148.6800) and
      (573.9610,4043.6700) .. (519.8870,3947.0000) .. controls (502.5430,3916.0000)
      and (484.5780,3890.0000) .. (480.5000,3890.0000) .. controls
      (476.3910,3890.0000) and (470.0590,3963.5000) .. (466.5000,4052.5000) ..
      controls (462.9410,4141.5000) and (455.6680,4235.3600) .. (450.4260,4260.0000)
      .. controls (434.7770,4333.5400) and (438.8520,4488.0000) ..
      (458.8130,4578.0000) .. controls (468.7930,4623.0000) and (473.8400,4660.0000)
      .. (470.0000,4660.0000) .. controls (466.1090,4660.0000) and
      (448.7340,4640.0000) .. (430.8980,4615.0000);

    % path3007
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (5502.0000,4572.5000) .. controls
      (5518.5000,4500.3100) and (5520.9500,4464.0000) .. (5516.0000,4365.0000) ..
      controls (5512.7000,4299.0000) and (5505.9500,4218.0000) ..
      (5501.0000,4185.0000) .. controls (5496.0200,4151.8100) and
      (5491.5500,4072.5000) .. (5491.0000,4007.5000) .. controls
      (5490.4100,3938.5000) and (5486.0800,3890.0000) .. (5480.5000,3890.0000) ..
      controls (5475.3200,3890.0000) and (5463.2700,3905.0000) ..
      (5453.9900,3923.0000) .. controls (5423.4600,3982.2300) and
      (5363.5300,4064.0000) .. (5300.0500,4133.0000) .. controls
      (5217.2700,4223.0000) and (5086.9100,4336.0600) .. (5082.1400,4322.0000) ..
      controls (5076.9400,4306.6400) and (5104.1800,4223.0000) ..
      (5145.3100,4128.0000) .. controls (5179.9700,4047.9600) and
      (5262.7200,3909.0000) .. (5378.7600,3736.0000) .. controls
      (5459.9100,3615.0000) and (5477.8600,3581.8800) .. (5500.1200,3512.0000) ..
      controls (5509.3600,3483.0000) and (5521.0700,3459.0000) ..
      (5526.0000,3459.0000) .. controls (5530.9600,3459.0000) and
      (5540.8300,3485.0000) .. (5548.0000,3517.0000) .. controls
      (5555.2000,3549.1300) and (5578.6400,3633.0000) .. (5600.5400,3705.0000) ..
      controls (5660.7500,3903.0000) and (5672.0700,3968.3400) ..
      (5672.4600,4120.0000) .. controls (5672.8600,4274.0000) and
      (5652.7800,4371.8800) .. (5595.1200,4497.0000) .. controls
      (5561.4800,4570.0000) and (5502.8800,4660.0000) .. (5489.0000,4660.0000) ..
      controls (5485.1600,4660.0000) and (5491.0300,4620.5000) ..
      (5502.0000,4572.5000);

    % path3009
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (135.8750,3978.0000) .. controls
      (121.0230,3926.6700) and (117.1840,3728.0000) .. (129.3160,3639.0000) ..
      controls (143.7730,3533.0000) and (186.0630,3401.2300) .. (231.3750,3321.0000)
      .. controls (248.7700,3290.2000) and (316.7730,3193.0000) ..
      (382.5000,3105.0000) .. controls (448.2270,3017.0000) and (504.3590,2939.1500)
      .. (507.2460,2932.0000) .. controls (518.7420,2903.5000) and
      (527.7190,2925.0000) .. (532.7110,2993.0000) .. controls (536.7850,3048.4600)
      and (550.5900,3096.0000) .. (592.8160,3200.0000) .. controls
      (663.8790,3375.0000) and (675.3950,3411.4100) .. (705.1020,3555.0000) ..
      controls (729.9300,3675.0000) and (738.8910,3830.0000) .. (721.0000,3830.0000)
      .. controls (704.6450,3830.0000) and (547.9220,3569.0000) ..
      (512.6410,3483.0000) .. controls (493.9100,3437.3400) and (473.2380,3362.0000)
      .. (466.0000,3313.0000) .. controls (458.9100,3265.0000) and
      (450.5000,3231.8200) .. (447.5000,3240.0000) .. controls (444.4770,3248.2500)
      and (425.3520,3309.0000) .. (405.0000,3375.0000) .. controls
      (384.7110,3440.8000) and (335.0310,3565.0000) .. (295.0000,3650.0000) ..
      controls (254.9690,3735.0000) and (207.1480,3845.6400) .. (189.1170,3895.0000)
      .. controls (150.7500,4000.0000) and (144.8830,4009.1400) ..
      (135.8750,3978.0000);

    % path3011
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (5804.5000,3985.0000) .. controls
      (5800.3800,3974.0000) and (5783.5000,3929.0000) .. (5767.0000,3885.0000) ..
      controls (5750.5500,3841.1300) and (5704.2600,3735.0000) ..
      (5664.5000,3650.0000) .. controls (5624.7400,3565.0000) and
      (5575.2900,3440.8000) .. (5555.0000,3375.0000) .. controls
      (5534.6500,3309.0000) and (5515.5300,3248.2500) .. (5512.5000,3240.0000) ..
      controls (5509.4800,3231.7500) and (5501.6000,3261.0000) ..
      (5495.0000,3305.0000) .. controls (5480.0000,3405.0000) and
      (5467.4500,3444.3300) .. (5419.7100,3541.0000) .. controls
      (5372.8000,3636.0000) and (5251.4900,3830.0000) .. (5239.0000,3830.0000) ..
      controls (5221.2600,3830.0000) and (5230.4000,3674.0000) ..
      (5255.1100,3555.0000) .. controls (5284.1000,3415.4200) and
      (5303.8300,3353.0000) .. (5371.7700,3186.0000) .. controls
      (5409.2000,3094.0000) and (5422.4400,3047.6300) .. (5427.0000,2992.5000) ..
      controls (5430.3100,2952.5000) and (5435.6900,2920.2200) ..
      (5439.0000,2920.5000) .. controls (5442.2900,2920.7700) and
      (5470.7200,2958.0000) .. (5502.0000,3003.0000) .. controls
      (5533.5200,3048.3400) and (5588.5100,3123.0000) .. (5625.0000,3170.0000) ..
      controls (5661.5000,3217.0000) and (5706.1600,3281.8200) ..
      (5724.9000,3315.0000) .. controls (5769.6100,3394.1300) and
      (5815.5700,3535.0000) .. (5830.6000,3639.0000) .. controls
      (5843.7600,3730.0000) and (5838.3200,3936.6700) .. (5821.6300,3980.0000) ..
      controls (5812.3900,4004.0000) and (5811.7000,4004.2000) ..
      (5804.5000,3985.0000);

    % path3013
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (711.5780,3358.0000) .. controls
      (696.2230,3318.2200) and (662.1990,3144.0000) .. (648.8870,3037.0000) ..
      controls (634.3280,2920.0000) and (642.8670,2759.8100) .. (669.4650,2651.0000)
      .. controls (680.7110,2605.0000) and (688.6450,2565.6400) ..
      (687.0000,2564.0000) .. controls (685.3360,2562.3400) and (660.8240,2602.0000)
      .. (632.0000,2653.0000) .. controls (594.3090,2719.6800) and
      (542.7150,2786.0000) .. (444.5000,2894.0000) .. controls (349.9220,2998.0000)
      and (292.0860,3071.9900) .. (253.0000,3139.0000) .. controls
      (222.0820,3192.0000) and (188.2660,3248.4400) .. (177.5000,3265.0000) --
      (158.0000,3295.0000) -- (163.9730,3213.0000) .. controls (175.7700,3051.0000)
      and (239.0390,2860.7500) .. (317.9410,2750.0000) .. controls
      (387.7620,2652.0000) and (432.4880,2607.7100) .. (525.0000,2544.9700) ..
      controls (571.0000,2513.7700) and (640.2150,2459.8200) .. (678.0000,2425.7000)
      .. controls (767.0000,2345.3400) and (818.8550,2305.8600) ..
      (826.0000,2313.0000) .. controls (829.2730,2316.2700) and (824.6760,2359.0000)
      .. (815.8870,2407.0000) .. controls (796.7460,2511.5500) and
      (796.0230,2568.0000) .. (811.4800,2752.0000) .. controls (831.3910,2989.0000)
      and (800.6090,3235.4500) .. (735.6680,3359.0000) -- (722.0000,3385.0000) --
      (711.5780,3358.0000);

    % path3015
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (5209.7900,3325.0000) .. controls
      (5152.3900,3190.5500) and (5129.4900,2974.0000) .. (5148.6700,2747.0000) ..
      controls (5164.3800,2561.0000) and (5163.7500,2512.4300) ..
      (5144.2700,2407.0000) .. controls (5135.3900,2359.0000) and
      (5130.7300,2316.2700) .. (5134.0000,2313.0000) .. controls
      (5141.1400,2305.8600) and (5193.0000,2345.3400) .. (5282.0000,2425.7000) ..
      controls (5319.7900,2459.8200) and (5389.0000,2513.7600) ..
      (5435.0000,2544.9400) .. controls (5608.8200,2662.7500) and
      (5704.7800,2806.0000) .. (5765.2800,3038.0000) .. controls
      (5787.7100,3124.0000) and (5809.2600,3290.0000) .. (5798.0000,3290.0000) ..
      controls (5795.2700,3290.0000) and (5762.3700,3236.0000) ..
      (5725.5000,3171.0000) .. controls (5670.0900,3073.3200) and
      (5633.1900,3024.5000) .. (5519.5000,2898.5000) .. controls
      (5418.4500,2786.5000) and (5366.8000,2720.1300) .. (5328.5000,2653.0000) ..
      controls (5299.4000,2602.0000) and (5274.6600,2562.3400) ..
      (5273.0000,2564.0000) .. controls (5271.3500,2565.6500) and
      (5280.0700,2607.0000) .. (5292.3900,2656.0000) .. controls
      (5321.2300,2770.6300) and (5323.4000,3006.0000) .. (5296.9000,3145.0000) ..
      controls (5271.7300,3277.0000) and (5246.9700,3370.0000) ..
      (5237.0000,3370.0000) .. controls (5232.5500,3370.0000) and
      (5220.4600,3350.0000) .. (5209.7900,3325.0000);

    % path3017
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (874.5000,2745.0000) .. controls
      (878.0660,2712.0800) and (887.0270,2597.0000) .. (894.3550,2490.0000) ..
      controls (909.2890,2272.0000) and (920.7300,2229.0000) ..
      (1005.5900,2072.0000) .. controls (1030.4600,2026.0000) and
      (1045.1200,1991.6200) .. (1038.0000,1996.0000) .. controls
      (1030.7800,2000.4500) and (985.0000,2037.7800) .. (935.0000,2080.0000) ..
      controls (885.1520,2122.0900) and (787.0000,2199.9800) .. (715.0000,2254.5800)
      .. controls (537.0000,2389.5700) and (464.6680,2455.0000) ..
      (395.0630,2544.0000) .. controls (313.1410,2648.7500) and (306.6880,2646.0000)
      .. (341.1410,2521.0000) .. controls (367.0510,2427.0000) and
      (433.9450,2283.0500) .. (490.7730,2199.0000) .. controls (580.0630,2066.9400)
      and (697.0000,1967.9500) .. (835.0000,1907.5900) .. controls
      (897.0000,1880.4800) and (1204.4100,1800.0000) .. (1246.0000,1800.0000) ..
      controls (1275.0000,1800.0000) and (1275.0000,1800.0000) ..
      (1244.2400,1878.0000) .. controls (1230.3000,1913.3500) and
      (1203.7900,2019.0000) .. (1185.0300,2114.0000) .. controls
      (1146.7100,2308.0000) and (1129.1100,2363.7700) .. (1067.0000,2488.0000) ..
      controls (1013.0000,2596.0000) and (915.2270,2758.3600) ..
      (888.0000,2785.2500) -- (868.0000,2805.0000) -- (874.5000,2745.0000);

    % path3019
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (5056.5800,2767.0000) .. controls
      (4981.1800,2665.1100) and (4856.7100,2428.0000) .. (4821.9300,2320.0000) ..
      controls (4810.4700,2284.4200) and (4789.3800,2193.0000) ..
      (4775.3100,2118.0000) .. controls (4745.5000,1959.0000) and
      (4725.9600,1887.3700) .. (4700.2900,1843.0000) .. controls
      (4668.0500,1787.2800) and (4685.0000,1786.9600) .. (4896.0000,1839.2500) ..
      controls (5077.0000,1884.1100) and (5156.2300,1914.7500) ..
      (5251.0000,1976.5500) .. controls (5409.4500,2079.8700) and
      (5558.2600,2300.0000) .. (5619.0400,2521.0000) .. controls
      (5653.9700,2648.0000) and (5648.9300,2648.9600) .. (5555.7000,2533.0000) ..
      controls (5491.6300,2453.3200) and (5367.0000,2343.6800) ..
      (5207.0000,2226.2500) .. controls (5164.3800,2194.9700) and
      (5085.0000,2131.5800) .. (5032.0000,2086.5000) .. controls
      (4979.0000,2041.4200) and (4928.8800,2000.3700) .. (4921.5000,1996.0000) ..
      controls (4914.0200,1991.5700) and (4926.1800,2021.0000) ..
      (4948.7600,2062.0000) .. controls (5037.7700,2223.6200) and
      (5050.9300,2272.0000) .. (5066.1800,2494.0000) .. controls
      (5073.8100,2605.0000) and (5082.6900,2718.5100) .. (5086.0000,2747.5000) ..
      controls (5089.3200,2776.5000) and (5089.5400,2800.0000) ..
      (5086.5000,2800.0000) .. controls (5083.5000,2800.0000) and
      (5069.9000,2785.0000) .. (5056.5800,2767.0000);

    % path3021
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (1056.2700,2695.0000) .. controls
      (1330.4600,2344.3200) and (1825.0000,1991.1600) .. (2217.0000,1866.0900) ..
      controls (2339.8800,1826.8800) and (2522.0000,1788.0500) ..
      (2675.0000,1768.4500) .. controls (2822.1300,1749.5900) and
      (3207.0000,1752.1100) .. (3355.0000,1772.9000) .. controls
      (3867.0000,1844.8200) and (4378.1500,2126.2000) .. (4781.2300,2558.0000) ..
      controls (4906.3100,2692.0000) and (4912.0900,2713.4100) ..
      (4792.0000,2597.9300) .. controls (4596.7300,2410.1400) and
      (4395.0000,2264.9300) .. (4170.0000,2150.1900) .. controls
      (3807.0000,1965.0800) and (3520.9800,1907.5200) .. (3231.0000,1961.2200) ..
      controls (3131.0000,1979.7400) and (3057.4800,2030.3300) ..
      (3010.4500,2113.0000) -- (2982.0000,2163.0000) -- (2956.2100,2112.0000) ..
      controls (2910.5400,2021.6900) and (2830.0000,1976.4200) ..
      (2666.0000,1948.8800) .. controls (2423.5200,1908.1600) and
      (1997.0000,2021.9500) .. (1682.0000,2211.4000) .. controls
      (1505.0000,2317.8600) and (1305.7200,2471.2700) .. (1130.0000,2636.3600) ..
      controls (1072.0000,2690.8400) and (1039.0000,2717.0900) ..
      (1056.2700,2695.0000);

    % path3023
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (1203.9800,2305.0000) .. controls
      (1214.1400,2278.6300) and (1275.2700,2055.0000) .. (1284.6100,2010.0000) ..
      controls (1301.6200,1928.0000) and (1360.5400,1828.7600) ..
      (1440.1400,1748.0000) .. controls (1495.3400,1692.0000) and
      (1512.4000,1669.5000) .. (1497.0000,1673.0000) .. controls
      (1485.0700,1675.7100) and (1448.0000,1685.3200) .. (1416.0000,1694.0000) ..
      controls (1383.4500,1702.8300) and (1305.0000,1716.9300) ..
      (1241.0000,1725.4600) .. controls (1050.0000,1750.9300) and
      (856.7110,1810.4700) .. (721.0000,1885.6300) .. controls (697.0000,1898.9200)
      and (675.1840,1910.0000) .. (673.0000,1910.0000) .. controls
      (670.7700,1910.0000) and (681.3670,1887.0000) .. (696.9610,1858.0000) ..
      controls (737.3050,1782.9700) and (870.0000,1654.7400) .. (968.0000,1596.0800)
      .. controls (1013.2100,1569.0200) and (1091.5000,1531.3000) ..
      (1142.5000,1512.0000) -- (1235.0000,1477.0000) -- (1410.0000,1483.0000) ..
      controls (1564.0000,1488.2800) and (1599.4000,1492.7700) ..
      (1705.0000,1520.4000) .. controls (1855.0000,1559.6400) and
      (1861.7300,1563.1800) .. (1824.0000,1582.8900) .. controls
      (1781.3700,1605.1500) and (1760.0600,1632.0000) .. (1679.4400,1765.0000) ..
      controls (1581.8500,1926.0000) and (1523.2800,2002.5200) ..
      (1390.8600,2142.0000) .. controls (1268.3900,2271.0000) and
      (1191.0900,2338.4200) .. (1203.9800,2305.0000);

    % path3025
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (4604.6300,2177.0000) .. controls
      (4445.7500,2013.0000) and (4384.0200,1935.1600) .. (4289.8200,1780.0000) ..
      controls (4209.0700,1647.0000) and (4175.1100,1603.3100) ..
      (4137.0000,1583.4100) .. controls (4098.0600,1563.0800) and
      (4104.0000,1559.9100) .. (4255.0000,1520.4000) .. controls
      (4360.6000,1492.7700) and (4396.0000,1488.3400) .. (4550.0000,1483.5000) ..
      controls (4722.0000,1478.0900) and (4726.2900,1478.4700) ..
      (4800.0000,1505.3400) .. controls (4958.0000,1562.9200) and
      (5112.1800,1665.2600) .. (5200.2400,1771.0000) .. controls
      (5244.3800,1824.0000) and (5298.0600,1910.0000) .. (5287.0000,1910.0000) ..
      controls (5284.8200,1910.0000) and (5263.0000,1898.9200) ..
      (5239.0000,1885.6300) .. controls (5103.2900,1810.4700) and
      (4910.0000,1750.9300) .. (4719.0000,1725.4600) .. controls
      (4655.0000,1716.9300) and (4576.5500,1702.8300) .. (4544.0000,1694.0000) ..
      controls (4512.0000,1685.3200) and (4474.9300,1675.7100) ..
      (4463.0000,1673.0000) .. controls (4447.6800,1669.5200) and
      (4464.6400,1692.0000) .. (4518.8100,1747.0000) .. controls
      (4616.6400,1846.3300) and (4647.7800,1908.0000) .. (4699.5700,2105.0000) ..
      controls (4721.3900,2188.0000) and (4743.9100,2267.9500) ..
      (4750.0000,2284.0000) .. controls (4756.0700,2300.0000) and
      (4758.0900,2315.6900) .. (4754.5000,2319.0000) .. controls
      (4750.9400,2322.2900) and (4683.0900,2258.0000) .. (4604.6300,2177.0000);

    % path3027
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (2040.0000,1523.5000) .. controls
      (2020.6800,1521.0200) and (1932.0000,1496.8700) .. (1842.0000,1469.5800) ..
      controls (1596.0000,1394.9800) and (1450.6800,1367.5100) ..
      (1295.0000,1366.1400) .. controls (1223.0000,1365.5100) and
      (1147.1500,1368.3500) .. (1125.0000,1372.5000) -- (1085.0000,1380.0000) --
      (1110.0000,1358.4200) .. controls (1152.3900,1321.8200) and
      (1312.0000,1251.5900) .. (1406.0000,1228.1800) .. controls
      (1477.8100,1210.2800) and (1523.0000,1206.0700) .. (1640.0000,1206.3800) ..
      controls (1814.0000,1206.8200) and (1932.5800,1226.4500) ..
      (2062.0000,1276.2300) .. controls (2357.0000,1389.6900) and
      (2455.5500,1415.0600) .. (2570.0000,1406.9900) .. controls
      (2617.0000,1403.6800) and (2681.8200,1392.6500) .. (2715.0000,1382.3200) ..
      controls (2778.0000,1362.7100) and (2910.3000,1300.5900) ..
      (2909.5000,1291.0000) .. controls (2909.2200,1287.6800) and
      (2877.5000,1262.6600) .. (2838.5000,1235.0000) .. controls
      (2799.5700,1207.3900) and (2731.5000,1150.7400) .. (2686.5000,1108.5000) --
      (2605.0000,1032.0000) -- (2654.5000,1009.5000) -- (2704.0000,987.0000) --
      (2733.5000,1021.0000) .. controls (2749.4500,1039.3800) and
      (2778.1600,1072.0000) .. (2796.0000,1092.0000) .. controls
      (2840.5900,1142.0000) and (2961.1100,1240.0000) .. (2978.0000,1240.0000) ..
      controls (3008.1900,1240.0000) and (3127.3000,1135.0000) ..
      (3226.4300,1021.0000) -- (3256.0000,987.0000) -- (3305.5000,1009.5000) --
      (3355.0000,1032.0000) -- (3273.5000,1108.5000) .. controls
      (3228.5000,1150.7400) and (3160.4300,1207.3900) .. (3121.5000,1235.0000) ..
      controls (3082.5000,1262.6600) and (3050.7900,1287.6800) ..
      (3050.5300,1291.0000) .. controls (3049.7600,1300.7400) and
      (3192.0000,1366.6800) .. (3255.0000,1385.8000) .. controls
      (3296.1400,1398.2800) and (3348.0000,1404.1400) .. (3420.0000,1404.4300) ..
      controls (3536.9800,1404.9100) and (3607.0000,1386.6900) ..
      (3862.0000,1289.4100) .. controls (4027.1300,1226.4100) and
      (4135.0000,1206.8500) .. (4320.0000,1206.3800) .. controls
      (4437.0000,1206.0700) and (4482.1900,1210.2800) .. (4554.0000,1228.1800) ..
      controls (4648.0000,1251.5900) and (4807.6100,1321.8200) ..
      (4850.0000,1358.4200) -- (4875.0000,1380.0000) -- (4835.0000,1372.5000) ..
      controls (4812.8500,1368.3500) and (4737.0000,1365.5000) ..
      (4665.0000,1366.1300) .. controls (4506.3000,1367.5000) and
      (4358.0000,1396.0900) .. (4113.0000,1472.5600) -- (3945.0000,1525.0000) --
      (3765.0000,1524.0400) .. controls (3490.0000,1522.5700) and
      (3294.5900,1480.4700) .. (3072.0000,1374.7100) -- (2980.0000,1331.0000) --
      (2887.0000,1375.0900) .. controls (2681.0200,1472.7400) and
      (2485.0000,1516.9400) .. (2227.0000,1523.9000) .. controls
      (2143.0000,1526.1600) and (2059.3400,1525.9900) .. (2040.0000,1523.5000);

  \end{scope}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to rephrase;

**TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm** ;)

Comment: +1 for acronym! Made me smile :) couldn't this be made a little smaller though by saving one leaf and re-using it?

Comment: @SeanAllred It's the official recursion, you can seee it in the manual. I wish I was that smart :)

Comment: Nice answer! Now for the cherry on top: How would you write a letter in the middle to replace the `A` you just erased?

Comment: @percusse A litle side question: where does the file gets exported when `export to tikz path` is used?  What is the difference between exporting it to tikz path or simply saving it as .tex?

Answer (score 9):

Here I want to describe another (not better, but different from this of @percusse) workflow, that is only adaptd to logo/glyph type drawings. This workflow use exclusively online tools.

1. I search the web for existing SVG version of the drawing. Here I was googling "Assassin's Creed Ancient Rome Insignia" without success.
2. If I can't find one, I convert the bitmap image to svg online, by googling for example "convert png svg". There are plenty of tools and some (most) of them use [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/), like InkScape.
   For this example I used [online-convert.com](https://www.online-convert.com) to obtain [this SVG](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kpym/2889cd47e1855664f8adaa007d17fb3a/raw/1154de9b1142ea6fa5c5e38eb7f88468b02797b3/SPQR_Original.svg).
3. I optimize the svg using the [online version](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) of [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo).
   [image]
   For this particular example are used "precision:0" and "Prefer viewBox to width/height" to obtain this half sized [svg](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kpym/2889cd47e1855664f8adaa007d17fb3a/raw/1154de9b1142ea6fa5c5e38eb7f88468b02797b3/SPQR_Optimized.svg).
4. To convert from SVG to TikZ I use [SVGPathy playground](https://kpym.github.io/SVGPathy/).

[image]

- copy/paste the entire svg in the upper textarea;
- select `Remove Arcs`, `Transformation : scale(1,-1)` and `Output type : One TikZ path per line`
  *(New : You can select `Full TikZ in standalone` and go faster to the final result)*;
- copy the result from the bottom textarea;
- wrap the resulting code in

  ```
      \documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
      \usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
      \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}

        % the code generated with SVGPathy goes here

        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
  ```

Here is the final result (see the notes at the end for the additional options).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    % the code generated with SVGPathy goes here
    \fill svg{M50.1-.5l-1.5-3.8-2.7-6.4-2.2-5.2-1-2.4-1.1-2.8-4.8-11.8-1.3-3.3c-1.4-3.5-2-4.6-3.3-5.8s-3.1-2.5-4.3-2.9c-1.9-.6-4.9-.2-6.9 1l-1.2 .5 .3-.8 1.1-3.8c.2-1.6 .3-4.9 0-6.5l-.8-2.5-.2-.9h.8c2.2 .5 3.9-.3 7.1-3.2 4.7-3.8 10.2-6.5 16-7.7 3.5-.8 4.4-.6 1.8 .2-4.6 1.4-8 3.3-9.8 5.5-1.8 1.9-2.7 4.5-2.5 7.1 .2 1.6 .3 2.2 1.6 5.5 1.3 3.4 2.5 6.8 3.8 10.2l2 5.8c1.8 5.2 3.7 10.3 5.8 15.5 .7 2.1 1.5 4.2 2.4 6.2l3.8-9.1 .7-1.7c1-2.3 1.9-4.7 2.9-7.1l2.2-5 2-5.2 3.2-7.6 2-4.7c.6-1.7 .8-2.5 .8-4.1 0-2.5-.6-4.2-2.5-6.1-3.2-2.7-7-4.5-11-5.4l-.8-.5c7.6 .8 14.7 3.9 20.4 8.9 .6 .6 1.9 1.7 2.9 2 1.1 .6 2.4 .8 3.3 .5l1.1-.2-.3 1c-.6 1.9-.8 3.3-.8 5.6 0 2.5 .2 3.9 1.1 6.3l.5 1.6-1-.2-2.3-.4c-2.5-.3-5.4 .3-7.4 1.7-1.4 .9-2.8 2.5-3.8 3.9-2.3 4.8-4.3 9.6-6 14.7l-1.4 3.3-3.3 8.5-3.3 8c-.5 1.3-1 2.6-1.6 3.9 0 .3-.3 .2-.5-.3zm-28.9-21.2c-3-1.4-4.7-3.5-6.2-6.9-.5-.9-.5-2-.3-2.1 .5 0 2.4 1.3 3.5 2.2 1.3 1.4 5 6.6 5 7.1s-.8 .3-2-.3zm55.5 .3c0-.3 .3-.6 1.1-1.7l.8-1.3c2.4-3.3 3.1-4.1 4.9-5.3 1.1-.8 1.7-1.1 1.9-1 .2 .3-.3 1.9-1 3.2-.5 1.1-1.3 2.2-2 3.3-.6 .8-2.4 1.9-3.6 2.5-1.4 .6-2 .8-2.1 .3z};
    \fill svg{M14.4-24.6c-1.5-1.5-2.6-3.3-3.1-5.3l-.4-1.7c-.2-1.1-.2-4.1 .2-5.7 .2-.9 .3-1.3 .5-1.3l1.4 1.1 2.5 2.4c2.7 2.5 5.2 6 5.8 8 .2 .6-.5 .3-2.2-.9-1.6-1.3-3.3-2.6-5-3.8l.1 1.4c.2 1.4 .5 2.7 1.1 4.6s.8 2.5 .5 2.5l-1.4-1.3zm69.6 1.1 .3-1.2c.8-2.3 1.3-4.8 1.6-7.3l-1.5 1.1c-1.3 .9-2.6 1.9-3.7 3-1.6 1.1-2 1.3-2.1 1 .7-1.8 1.6-3.4 2.8-4.9 1.3-1.7 6.5-6.8 7-6.8 .2 0 .3 .2 .3 .5l.3 1.6c.3 2.2 .2 5.7-.5 7.4-.8 1.9-1.6 3.1-3 4.7-1.1 1.1-1.4 1.3-1.5 .9z};
    \fill svg{M10-29.4c-.8-1.1-1.4-2.2-2-4.1l-.7-3.5c-.2-3 .2-4.4 1.4-8.3l.5-1.4c.2-1.3 .3-1.9 .6-1.9 .3-.2 .6 .3 .7 .8s.9 2.2 1.9 3.6c1.4 2.2 2.7 4.4 3.9 6.6l.9 2.7c0 .6 0 .6-.3 .6-.6 0-4.9-4.4-5.8-6l-.2-.6-.1 1.7-.3 2.8c-.3 2.7-.3 3.8 0 5.5 .6 2 .5 2.4-.5 1.5zm79.2 .3 .4-2.4c.2-1.3 .2-2.7-.1-4.9l-.3-2.8v-1.6l-.7 1c-.8 1.3-5 5.5-5.5 5.5s-.5-.3 .2-1.9c.5-1.7 1.4-3.3 3.3-6.5 2.4-3.6 2.7-3.9 2.8-4.7 .5-1.3 .5-1.4 .8-1.2 .3 0 .6 .8 .6 1.5l.7 2.4c.9 2.7 1.1 3.6 1.2 6 .2 3.1-.5 6-2 8.2-.8 1.3-1.3 1.7-1.4 1.5z};
    \fill svg{M5-40c-.4-3.2-.1-6.5 .9-9.6 .5-1.1 1.6-2.8 2.2-3.4l1.3-1.6 2-2.7 .2 .6c.1 1.3 .4 2.6 .9 3.8l.3 1c.8 1.7 1.1 2.7 1.6 5.3 .6 2.5 .6 4.6 .2 4.6-.3 0-.9-.8-1-1.1l-.5-.8c-1.4-2-3-5.2-2.9-6.5-.9 2.7-2 5.4-3.5 7.9l-.3 .8-.3 .8c0 .5-.6 1.6-.8 1.6l-.3-.7zm89.2 .2-.2-.5-.3-.9-1.1-2.7-1.1-2.4c-.6-1.4-1.2-2.8-1.6-4.2l-.3 .9c-.3 1.3-1.6 3.9-3 6-1.3 2-1.6 2-1.5 0s1.1-6.3 2.2-9c.8-1.7 1.1-3.1 .9-4.1-.2-1.1 .5-.8 2.2 1.8 3.3 4.4 3.8 5.4 4.4 7.8 .6 2.4 .5 7.7-.3 7.8l-.3-.5z};
    \fill svg{M13.9-50.1c-.5-1.9-.8-3.9-.9-5.8-.2-1.6-.1-3.3 .1-4.9-.3 .8-1.7 2.5-4.2 5.1l-3 4.9-.3 .1c-.3 0-.3-2.2 0-3.3 .8-3 1.4-4.6 2.5-6.1 .9-1.3 1.7-1.9 2.5-2.5 1.1-.6 2.7-1.9 3.5-2.7 .9-.9 1.9-1.4 2.2-1.4v1.1l-.3 6.6c0 6.8 .2 6.3-1 8.9-.5 1.1-.8 1.1-1.1 0zm70.8-.4c-.8-2.2-.8-2.5-.7-6.3-.1-2.7-.1-5.5-.2-8.2-.3-1.6-.3-1.9 .5-1.6l.6 .5c1.4 1.4 3 2.5 3.9 3.1 1.3 .9 1.9 1.6 2.7 2.6l.6 .7 .2 .4 .2 .3c.8 .9 2 4.9 2 6.9 .2 1.9-.2 1.9-.9 .5-.7-1.4-1.5-2.7-2.6-4-1.6-1.5-3-3.2-4.2-5 .4 3 .3 6-.5 9 0 .8-.5 2.2-.8 2.3-.2 0-.5-.3-.8-1.2z};
    \fill svg{M16.4-58.5l.2-1.5 .3-3.7c.2-2.8 .3-3.5 1.1-5.4l.7-1.3-.5 .4-1 .7c-.5 .4-1.1 .8-1.5 1.3l-.5 .3-1.9 1.6c-2.2 1.6-2.7 2-3.9 3.6-.5 .8-1.1 1.3-1.3 1.3-.5 0 0-2.4 1.1-4.7 1.5-3.4 4.3-6 7.7-7.4l1.3-.4 1.9-.4 2-.5c1.4 0 1.4 0 1 1.1-.5 .8-.8 2-1.1 4.2-.3 2.3-1.1 4.5-2.2 6.5l-.4 .6c-.6 1.1-1.3 2.1-2 3.2-.5 .6-.8 .8-1 .5zm66.3-.2c-.8-.9-2.8-4.4-3.5-6.1-.6-1.3-.9-2.5-1.1-3.5-.2-2.1-.7-4.1-1.5-6 0-.3 0-.3 1.2-.3l2.1 .5 1.9 .4 1.2 .4 .6 .1 1 .6c3 1.4 5.7 4.6 6.8 8.5l.7 2.6c-.2 .6-.5 .5-1.4-.7-2.2-2.7-4.8-5-7.7-6.9l-1.7-1.3 .6 1.3c.3 .6 .6 1.2 .8 1.9l.3 2.5 .3 3.9c.3 2.4 .2 2.8-.6 2.1zm-64-.5c0-.6 4.4-5.4 7.2-7.5 6.8-5.8 15.5-8.8 24.4-8.5 5.7-.2 8.7 .5 13.2 2.2 7 2.9 13.1 7.6 17.6 13.7 0 .3-.5 .2-1.2-.8-4.2-4.6-9.3-8-14.8-10.3-3.9-1.7-8.2-2.1-12.3-1.1-.9 .3-2 1.6-2.4 2.4s-.6 .8-.7 .2l-.8-1.3c-.8-.9-1.3-1.1-3.8-1.7-1.6-.3-3.8-.2-6.9 .6-5.7 1.3-11.8 4.9-17.5 10.4-.7 .6-1.4 1.2-2 1.7z};
    \fill svg{M21.6-66.1l.4-1.1 .9-3.2c.3-1.9 1.1-3.3 2.4-4.7l.4-.8-1.2 .2-2.2 .3c-2.7 .3-5.3 1.2-7.7 2.5-.6 .5-1.3 .6-1.3 .3 0-.5 .9-1.9 2-2.9 .8-.9 2-1.9 3.2-2.6l.9-.4 2.2-1c.3-.2 1.3-.3 3.2-.1 3 0 4.1 .2 6.3 .7l1.1 .4c.5 .2 .6 .6 .3 .6-.5 0-1.4 .9-1.9 1.7l-1.2 1.8c-1.7 2.8-2.2 3.5-4.6 5.9l-3 2.7-.2-.3zm53.9-2c-2.7-2.8-3.5-3.8-5.4-6.8-.9-1.6-1.4-2.4-1.9-2.5l-.8-.5c-.3 0-.2-.5 .4-.6l1.1-.4c1.9-.6 3-.8 5.6-.9l3.3 .2c2 .6 3.8 1.5 5.4 2.8 .3 0 1.9 1.6 2.5 2.4l.9 1.8c0 .3-.3 .2-1.9-.6-2.8-1.4-4.4-1.9-7.7-2.2l-2.2-.5c-.9-.2-.9-.2-.6 .2 .6 .5 1.7 2 2.1 2.8l.9 2.5c.3 1.5 .6 3 .9 4.6l-2.6-2.3z};
    \fill svg{M34.1-78.7c-3.4-1.3-6.9-2.1-10.6-2.5-.9 0-1.4 0-2.3 .3-2 .5-2 0 0-1.3l2.8-1.2c1.4-.5 1.9-.5 3.8-.6 3.8-.2 6.1 .3 9.3 1.7l3.6 1.1 2.2 .3c1.3 0 1.7 0 2.7-.3 1.1-.3 2.8-1.1 2.8-1.3l-1.3-.9c-1.9-1.4-3.1-2.7-3.1-3.2l.8-.6c.9-.3 1.3-.2 2 .8 .5 .8 1.1 1.4 2.9 2.7 .2 .3 .3 .2 1.1-.3 .9-.8 2.4-2 2.6-2.7 .5-.6 .9-.8 1.8-.5l.8 .6c0 .5-1.4 1.7-3.2 3.2l-1.3 .9c0 .2 1.7 .9 2.9 1.3 .9 .3 1.4 .3 2.7 .3l2.2-.3c1.7-.4 3.4-1 5-1.7 2-.8 4.4-1.3 7.7-1.1 2 .2 2.5 .2 3.8 .6 .9 .3 2.2 .8 2.8 1.2 2 1.1 2 1.6 .2 1.3-1.6-.3-1.9-.3-4.4 0-2.4 .3-4.7 .8-7 1.6l-1.5 .6c-2.9 .3-5.9 .2-8.8-.3-1.7-.3-3.6-.9-6-2.1l-1.1-.4-1.3 .6c-4.5 2.2-9.6 3-14.6 2.2zm-6.3-9.1c-.9-.6-1.3-1.1-1.3-2.2s.3-1.7 1.8-2.9c1.7-1.3 2.2-1.7 2.2-2.3 0-1.3-.9-1.9-2.2-1.7-.8 .2-1.3 .5-1.5 1.2-.3 1.1-.6 .8-.6-.5 0-1.1 0-1.1 .5-1.2l1.7-.2c1.1-.2 1.4 0 2.1 .3 .9 .5 1.4 1.6 1.4 2.6-.2 1.1-.6 1.7-2.1 2.8-1.7 1.3-2 1.6-2.2 2.2-.2 .9 1.3 1.7 2.5 1.2l.8-.7c0-.3 .2-.5 .3-.5l.2 .9c0 .9 0 .9-.5 1.1-1.1 .3-2.5 .2-3.1-.1zm28 .1c-2.5-.8-3.9-2.8-3.8-5.3 .3-3.1 3-5.2 6.3-4.6l1.1 .2 1.9-1c2.8-1.4 3.5-1.6 5.8-1.5 1.7-.2 2.2 0 3 .3 .8 .2 1.1 .5 1.1 .6l-.5 .2c-2.2-.5-2.4-.5-3.6-.4-1.4 .2-2.7 .6-4.9 1.8l-1.7 .8 .6 .4 1 1.5c.5 .9 .5 1.1 .5 2.3s0 1.6-.4 2.2c-.5 .8-1.4 1.7-2 2.1-1.1 .6-3.3 .8-4.4 .4zm2.5-.8c2.2-.6 3.3-3.8 2.4-6.1-.9-2.5-3.8-3-5.7-1.1-.8 .9-1.3 1.9-1.3 3.5 0 1.4 .2 2 1 2.8 .8 .9 2.2 1.3 3.6 .9zm-19.3 .5 .4-.3c.5 0 .5-.2 .5-.9v-6.6c0-.9-.2-1.1-.5-1.1l-.3-.4 1.7-.1c1.6 0 1.9 0 1.9 .3l-.4 .2-.7 .3-.1 4.2v3.9h.6c.8 0 1.6-.3 1.9-.9 .5-.5 .6-1.7 .1-2.4-.2-.3-1.3-.9-1.8-.9l-.5-.2c0-.5 1.6-.3 2.5 0 1.9 1.1 2.2 3.8 .3 4.8-.5 .3-.9 .3-3.1 .3l-2.5-.2z};
    \fill svg{M69.2-88l.6-.3 .5-.2v-3.6c0-4.2 0-4.9-.5-4.8l-.5-.4 1.8-.1 1.8 .1c0 .2-.2 .3-.4 .4-.6 .2-.8 .3-.8 2.2v1.2h.9c.8 0 .8 0 1.3-.8l2.5-2.8c.8-.5 3-.5 3-.2 0 .2-.2 .3-.5 .4-.8 0-1.4 .6-3 2.5l-1.2 1.4 .5 .5c.8 .8 .9 1.4 .9 2.3 0 .8 0 .9-.5 1.4-.6 .8-1.1 .9-3.9 1l-2.5-.2zm4.5-.8c1.1-.6 1.3-3.1 .2-3.7h-1.9c-.3 0-.3 .3-.3 2l.1 1.9c.3 .2 1.6 0 1.9-.2z};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes and disclaimer**

- I'm the author of [SVGPathy](https://github.com/kpym/SVGPathy) that is based on [svgpath](https://github.com/fontello/svgpath).
- SVGPathy is designed to work with svg paths only, not with general svg images, so it is ok only for simple logo/glyph images.
- I have checked in SVGPathy the option `Remove arcs` (that convert arc commands to cubic curves) because else `svg.path` was complaining `! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x`.
- The transformation `Transformation : scale(1,-1)` is here because SVG and TikZ have different conventions about the orientation up/down for the y-axis. Instead of correcting that when converting, you can just put in tikz `[yscale=-1]`.
- For the final image I use `View Box : 0 0 100 100` to reduce the coordinates to be in [0,100]. And I selected `precision:1` and `Zip It` to reduce the code size.
- Even if you use the @percusse workflow I strongly suggest you to optimize your svg before to convert it to tikz. For this you can :

  - Apply all the transforms to the paths by "ungrouping" (the shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+G`) multiple times, if necessary, all the paths (select them with `Ctrl+A`).
  - Save it in InkScape with the option "Save type : Optimized SVG".
  - Use [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to optimize it even more.

Comment: Thank you! `SVGPathy` just saved me when the `svg2tikz` extension for Inkscape let me down.