# Error : Inkscape 0.92 Export to TikZ path

Tags: tikz-pgf, ubuntu, inkscape, export

I am using **INKSCAPE 0.92** on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** and getting the following error. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

> Extensions > Export > Export to TikZ path ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1439, in <module>
    main_inkscape()
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1423, in main_inkscape
    effect.affect()
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex.py", line 216, in affect
    if output: self.output()
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1362, in output
    f = codecs.open(self.options.outputfile, 'w', 'utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 898, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'none'
```

Comment: Just as a test: does it work if you check the `export to clipboard` option?

Comment: Thanks @samcarter for your comment. `Export to clipboard` throws the following error: `ERROR:root:Failed to put output on clipboard`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: sorry, then all my possible ideas are rules out. That is a really strange error! I hope someone with more python knowledge will be able to help.

Comment: seen this: [Export to TikZ path in Inkscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173293/117534)? it seems you left the output filename as 'none'? what happens if you change it to an absolute filepath?

Comment: This does not look like a TeX problem to me. Move to Unix&Linux or ubuntu sx?