# Victory symbol in Salamanca

Tags: tikz-pgf, kerning

In Salamanca, Spain, it was customary when you finished your PhD degree in the city's University ---which is one of the oldest in Europe--- to write in the wall a kind of graffiti, as shown here:

[image]

This symbol says "Victor" which means *victory*  ---According to egreg, *winner* is a more accurate translation into English :)

Do any one of you happen to have one of these symbols in TikZ-pgf?  I have also noticed that it uses all the letters kind of over each other.  Could this be done with some kerning manipulation?

Comment: Could you show us your first attempt, please? Otherwise you leave all the effort to our community.

Comment: More precisely, it means “winner”.

Comment: you don't like my potrace answer? ;)

Comment: @egreg perhaps a more accurate term would be *victorious*?

Comment: @MarioS.E. No: in Latin *victor* is a noun, while the English *victorious* is an adjective. But the OED also lists *victor*, so I guess this is the “best” translation.

Comment: In early modern Spanish, "Victor" was also an exclamation (like "Huzzah!") shouted out at parades and sporting events.

Comment: @AndrewCashner really? I had never heard about it.  Was this in some particular area/region?

Comment: @Mario I've seen it in seventeenth-century villancico texts ranging from Madrid to Bolivia.

Comment: @AndrewCashner wow, the things you learn with TeX... :)

Comment: @percusse did you write an answer?

Comment: To some other question heheh http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172336/3235

Comment: @percusse ahhhhhh, lol, I just didn't know if this could be made by --or was easier, for that matter--- using kerning manipulation.  Or even perhaps someone had taken the time to make some kind of TikZ art for these *vitores*

Comment: @AndrewCashner In Spanish, although we say still "victoria" (=latin), "victorioso" (from "victoriosus") and "invicto" (unbeaten, from "invictus"), today nobody use  "victor" as winner, only as personal name  (eg, "Victor Jara").

Answer (score 21):

Here is a SVG path extracted from your picture by inkscape.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red!30!black] svg[scale=.3pt]
  { m 322.4,45.2 c -0.8,0.8 -1.6,2.3 -1.6,3.3 0,0.9 -0.5,1.7 -1.1,1.7
    -0.6,0 -1.9,1.8 -2.8,4 -0.9,2.2 -2.1,4 -2.6,4 -0.5,0 -1.6,1.6
    -2.4,3.6 -1.5,3.9 -8.2,16.4 -10.3,19.2 -0.7,0.9 -3.3,6.1 -5.7,11.6
    -2.4,5.4 -7.0,14.3 -10.2,19.7 -3.1,5.3 -5.7,10.0 -5.7,10.4 0,0.3
    -1.7,4.5 -3.9,9.2 -5.3,11.5 -9.3,15.3 -15.9,15.3 -6.4,0 -22.5,3.9
    -37.3,9.1 -6.2,2.1 -14.3,4.9 -18,6.2 -12.2,4.0 -26.5,10.5 -37.4,16.7
    -10.7,6.1 -31.2,19.5 -32.5,21.2 -0.3,0.4 -4.8,4.0 -10,8.0 -5.1,3.9
    -12.5,10.4 -16.5,14.5 -6.6,6.8 -22.8,27.2 -22.8,28.8 0,0.3 -1.6,3.1
    -3.6,6.2 -3.9,6.1 -4.4,6.7 -8.3,11.5 -1.4,1.7 -2.6,4.0 -2.6,5.0
    0,1.0 -2.0,5.8 -4.5,10.7 -4.7,9.3 -14.1,33.1 -14.1,35.9 0,0.8
    -0.9,4.3 -2.0,7.7 -2.3,6.9 -2.7,29.4 -0.6,40.1 0.6,3.5 1.9,10.3
    2.8,15.1 1.6,8.5 8.2,30.1 10.8,35.3 10.2,20.2 22.4,34.2 38.4,44.1
    4.3,2.6 7.9,5.1 7.9,5.5 0,0.3 -3.4,7.6 -7.6,16.1 -7.0,14.1 -8.7,16.5
    -20.9,28.5 -11.8,11.6 -14.8,13.8 -27.3,19.8 -19.7,9.4 -20.7,10.0
    -20.7,12.0 0,1.4 7.7,1.7 39.3,1.7 46.8,0 62.6,-0.4 62.6,-1.9 0,-0.5
    -2.8,-1.7 -6.3,-2.6 -10.7,-2.6 -16.8,-6.4 -20.9,-13.0 -3.3,-5.3
    -3.9,-7.7 -4.4,-18.0 -0.3,-6.5 -0.0,-12.3 0.6,-12.7 0.6,-0.4
    4.0,-6.7 7.5,-13.8 5.5,-11.4 6.6,-12.9 9.3,-12.4 4.9,0.9 17.4,7.0
    21.1,10.3 3.1,2.8 8.4,14.1 9.4,20.3 0.7,4.6 3.7,4.0 3.6,-0.7
    -0.2,-17.0 -4.3,-48.4 -6.6,-51.2 -2.3,-2.8 -4.0,0.1 -3.1,5.4 0.5,2.8
    -0.1,5.3 -2.3,8.6 -3.9,5.8 -9.6,6.7 -16.2,2.7 l -4.4,-2.7 2.9,-8.3 c
    5.4,-15.6 6.8,-16.6 20.6,-15.1 6.0,0.6 9.2,0.2 14.9,-1.8 13.5,-5.0
    37.0,-22.7 39.1,-29.4 0.4,-1.4 1.2,-2.6 1.8,-2.6 1.2,0 7.9,-10.3
    11.9,-18.3 4.1,-8.3 11.6,-29.5 12.8,-36.3 0.5,-3.2 1.8,-8.3
    2.9,-11.3 1.2,-3.4 1.9,-11.2 2.0,-22.0 l 0.1,-16.7 -5.3,-11.2 c
    -2.9,-6.2 -6.6,-12.4 -8.1,-13.8 -3.6,-3.2 -3.6,-6.2 0.2,-11.8
    2.7,-4.0 25.3,-48.9 33.6,-66.9 14.5,-31.3 19.4,-40.5 21.4,-39.7
    1.8,0.7 1.9,5.7 1.2,46.9 -0.4,25.3 -1.1,83.6 -1.4,129.4 -1.2,193.4
    -2.7,339.3 -3.8,365.3 -0.2,6.4 -0.6,7.3 -3.3,7.7 -3.7,0.5 -26.2,-3.2
    -33.8,-5.6 -3.0,-0.9 -13.6,-4.3 -23.5,-7.4 -21.3,-6.6 -44.7,-15.1
    -54,-19.4 -6.5,-3.0 -9.3,-4.7 -25.9,-16.1 -4.5,-3.1 -9.1,-5.6
    -10.1,-5.6 -2.4,0 -2.4,3.9 -0.0,7.3 0.9,1.4 4.2,10.1 7.3,19.2
    3.0,9.1 6.0,17.6 6.7,18.8 0.6,1.1 1.9,4.7 2.7,8 0.8,3.2 2.3,7.6
    3.2,9.8 5.0,12.0 10.0,25.5 10.0,27.0 -0.0,2.4 10.5,24.2 11.6,24.2
    0.5,-0.0 1.9,-1.7 3.1,-3.8 5.8,-10.3 45.3,-20.9 100.0,-26.7
    25.4,-2.7 59.0,-0.6 97.2,5.9 16.1,2.7 35.6,8.1 41.4,11.4 1.2,0.7
    2.8,1.2 3.6,1.2 3.6,0 19.9,9.2 25.1,14.2 3.2,3.1 6.3,5.4 6.9,5.0
    0.9,-0.6 2.0,-7.0 5.5,-33.0 0.8,-6.0 1.7,-12.5 2.0,-14.3 0.3,-1.8
    1.1,-6.9 1.8,-11.3 0.6,-4.4 3.1,-16.7 5.4,-27.3 2.3,-10.6 4.6,-22.9
    5.2,-27.3 0.5,-4.4 1.5,-9.9 2.0,-12.3 1.5,-7.0 -2.4,-5.4 -12.4,4.8
    -12.2,12.6 -24.8,20.5 -63.3,39.6 -12.8,6.3 -28.6,11.2 -46.8,14.4
    -10.2,1.8 -18.8,3.2 -19.0,3.2 -0.6,0 1.8,-127.1 3.0,-154.6 0.3,-8.4
    1.0,-51.9 1.4,-96.6 0.4,-44.7 0.9,-92.4 1.1,-106 0.1,-13.5 0.7,-57.9
    1.2,-98.6 0.9,-79.7 1.6,-99.0 3.7,-98.3 1.9,0.6 10.7,18.3 21.7,43.7
    2.3,5.5 7.0,15.7 10.3,22.6 3.3,6.9 6.7,14.7 7.7,17.3 0.9,2.5
    5.1,11.5 9.3,20 10.4,20.7 17.8,36.5 21.2,45.2 1.5,4.0 3.6,8.8
    4.6,10.6 1.7,3.3 5.3,11.2 10.0,22.1 3.4,8.0 8.8,19.6 15.2,33.1
    14.6,30.7 19.3,40.6 22.6,48.6 1.9,4.7 4.0,9.2 4.6,9.9 0.5,0.7
    1.7,3.7 2.7,6.6 0.9,2.9 4.9,12.0 8.8,20.2 8.0,16.8 14.6,37.0
    15.8,49.0 0.7,7.5 0.5,8.4 -3.6,14.6 -4.8,7.2 -12.6,12.2 -24.8,16.1
    -13.2,4.1 -8.0,5.2 23.8,4.7 16.4,-0.2 48.1,-0.6 70.5,-0.8 51.3,-0.5
    47.4,-0.4 55.6,-1.3 8.9,-1.0 9.1,-3.6 0.5,-6.5 -12.6,-4.2
    -33.8,-16.2 -43.5,-24.7 -16.5,-14.4 -30.8,-31.6 -28.4,-34.0 0.3,-0.3
    4.2,-1.3 8.5,-2.0 16.2,-2.9 39.0,-11.5 44.2,-16.7 1.0,-1.0 2.4,-1.8
    3.2,-1.8 0.7,0 5.1,-3.7 9.7,-8.4 8.2,-8.3 18.0,-22.0 24.9,-34.9
    4.9,-9.2 8.7,-29.6 9.6,-52.7 0.7,-17.4 0.4,-21.0 -2.4,-34.6
    -3.9,-18.6 -10.0,-36.8 -17.2,-51.8 -4.4,-9.1 -7.6,-13.5 -16.8,-22.6
    -20.6,-20.5 -36.0,-31.9 -57.3,-42.3 -11.8,-5.7 -21.0,-9.3
    -55.7,-21.7 -4.6,-1.6 -8.6,-3.5 -9.0,-4.1 -0.7,-1.1 4.4,-3.6
    9.8,-4.6 3.9,-0.7 16.5,-5.7 18.4,-7.2 0.8,-0.6 1.7,-0.9 2.1,-0.5
    1.2,1.2 14.0,-13.4 16.9,-19.3 1.5,-3.1 4.3,-12.1 6.3,-19.8 1.9,-7.7
    4.1,-15.3 4.9,-16.7 0.8,-1.4 1.5,-2.9 1.5,-3.3 0.3,-2.2 4.9,-9.2
    8.2,-12.2 2.0,-1.9 8.8,-5.7 15.1,-8.3 6.2,-2.6 12.3,-5.3 13.6,-6.0
    1.2,-0.7 3.2,-1.2 4.4,-1.2 1.1,0 6.4,-1.4 11.6,-3.2 5.2,-1.7
    17.3,-4.5 26.8,-6.1 9.5,-1.5 19.1,-3.1 21.3,-3.6 5.8,-1.0 42.0,-1.0
    46.3,0.0 2.7,0.6 3.6,0.4 3.6,-0.9 0,-1.0 -1.3,-2.2 -3.0,-2.6
    -5.0,-1.2 -30.9,-3.3 -55.6,-4.4 -54.7,-2.4 -84.5,1.1 -104.6,12.5
    -23.1,13.1 -24.2,13.9 -41.3,30.5 -6.5,6.3 -9.1,13.3 -11.0,29.1
    -0.7,6.6 -1.9,13.5 -2.6,15.3 -0.7,1.8 -1.3,3.7 -1.4,4.3 -0.5,4.1
    -4.9,9.1 -10.4,11.7 -11.2,5.4 -24.3,4.5 -53.1,-3.5 -3.7,-1.0
    -7.6,-1.9 -8.6,-1.9 -4.9,-0.0 -11.5,-2.9 -12.8,-5.6 -3.9,-8.1
    -17.1,-38.0 -25.1,-56.9 -2.0,-4.7 -4.3,-9.5 -5.1,-10.6 -0.8,-1.1
    -2.6,-4.7 -4.0,-8 -3.7,-8.9 -15.3,-30.9 -17.6,-33.6 -2.4,-2.7
    -4.4,-2.9 -6.7,-0.7 z m -58.9,112.5 c 0,1.0 -1.5,4.2 -3.3,7.1
    -1.8,2.9 -3.3,5.5 -3.3,5.9 0,0.3 -8.3,17.6 -18.4,38.3 -10.1,20.7
    -21.0,43.0 -24.0,49.5 -5.3,11.2 -5.7,11.7 -9.1,11.0 -19.7,-4.3
    -25.4,-4.2 -37.1,1.1 -14.9,6.8 -29.5,20.1 -45.8,41.7 -15.1,20.0
    -24.4,47.2 -24.4,71.6 -0.0,20.3 4.6,31.6 19.2,46.7 7.9,8.2 8.4,9.0
    6.7,11.7 -0.9,1.5 -3.5,6.3 -5.7,10.5 -2.1,4.2 -4.4,7.6 -5.1,7.6
    -0.6,0 -2.2,-1.8 -3.5,-4.0 -1.2,-2.2 -3.8,-5.8 -5.8,-8.1 -1.9,-2.2
    -4.2,-5.9 -5.1,-8.2 -0.8,-2.3 -3.5,-8.4 -5.9,-13.5 -5.7,-12.2
    -6.7,-15.2 -9.4,-28.6 -3.8,-18.8 -2.5,-64.6 2.1,-76.4 2.4,-6.0
    3.1,-8.3 3.6,-11.5 0.4,-2.9 4.8,-12.4 10.3,-22.6 2.7,-5.0 5.5,-10.8
    7.5,-15.6 0.9,-2.3 2.2,-4.3 2.8,-4.3 0.5,0 1.0,-0.8 1.0,-1.9 0,-2.5
    7.0,-13.4 16.2,-25.3 10.3,-13.3 47.1,-50.7 53.6,-54.5 10.7,-6.2
    37.5,-19.1 41.7,-20.0 2.3,-0.5 4.6,-1.4 5.0,-2.1 0.4,-0.6 2.1,-1.2
    3.7,-1.2 1.6,0 3.5,-0.6 4.3,-1.3 1.7,-1.7 23.2,-6.3 26.1,-5.6
    1.2,0.3 2.3,1.4 2.3,2.4 z m 142.8,18.6 c 6.8,2.6 17.5,6.5 23.7,8.7
    6.2,2.2 11.9,4.5 12.6,5.2 0.6,0.6 2.1,1.1 3.3,1.1 1.9,-0.0 52.4,24.6
    55.4,27.0 4.8,3.9 19.4,14.8 23.3,17.4 3.9,2.6 15.5,13.8 30.6,29.4
    5.2,5.4 15.8,21.2 18.7,28.0 4.0,9.4 9.4,31.6 9.9,41.3 0.0,0.7
    0.4,1.9 0.8,2.6 1.7,2.9 0.0,45.3 -2.1,54 -1.2,4.7 -2.6,11.6
    -3.2,15.3 -1.2,7.9 -1.6,9.1 -7.8,22 -5.2,10.8 -12.6,22.0 -16.9,25.5
    -1.4,1.2 -4.1,3.4 -5.9,5.0 -3.6,3.2 -14.6,6.7 -20.8,6.7 -3.8,0
    -4.5,-0.7 -8.4,-8.7 -2.3,-4.8 -5.3,-11.5 -6.7,-15 -1.3,-3.4
    -4.3,-10.2 -6.6,-15.2 -2.2,-4.9 -6.8,-15.4 -10.1,-23.3 -3.3,-7.9
    -7.3,-16.4 -8.9,-19.0 -1.6,-2.5 -3.6,-6.1 -4.5,-8 -6.8,-14.7
    -9.7,-21.4 -9.7,-22.0 0,-0.3 -1.7,-4.4 -3.8,-8.9 -8.7,-18.8
    -13.4,-29.1 -13.4,-29.6 0,-0.2 -2.1,-4.8 -4.6,-10.1 -2.5,-5.2
    -4.6,-10.1 -4.6,-10.7 0,-0.6 -1.4,-3.3 -3.1,-6.1 -1.7,-2.7 -3.5,-6.5
    -4.0,-8.5 -0.4,-1.9 -4.5,-11.2 -9.0,-20.6 -13.1,-27.6 -16.8,-35.5
    -17.7,-38.7 -0.5,-1.6 -1.4,-3 -2.1,-3 -0.6,0 -1.2,-0.8 -1.2,-1.8
    0,-0.9 -4.2,-10.6 -9.3,-21.4 -5.1,-10.7 -9.3,-20.4 -9.3,-21.5 0,-2.8
    2.5,-2.3 16.2,2.8 z m -207.1,109.0 c 1.9,1.9 1.9,2.3 -0.1,4.5
    -1.2,1.3 -2.2,2.8 -2.2,3.3 0,0.8 -31.2,64.1 -34.3,69.5 -0.8,1.4
    -5.1,10.4 -9.6,20 -16.4,35.0 -18.9,39.4 -21.7,39.0 -1.5,-0.2
    -4.2,-3.4 -6.7,-7.7 -3.9,-7.0 -4.1,-7.8 -3.9,-22 0.1,-11.8 1.0,-17.8
    4.5,-31.3 8.2,-31.4 16.2,-44.2 43.9,-70.1 5.8,-5.4 17.0,-9.5
    23.0,-8.4 2.8,0.5 6.1,1.9 7.3,3.0 z m 11.5,14.7 c 2.9,10.2 2.5,22.0
    -1.2,38.1 -3.4,14.1 -9.5,31.5 -11.5,32.8 -0.6,0.3 -1.0,1.7 -1.0,2.9
    0,6.4 -17.2,30.5 -28.6,39.9 -4.8,4.0 -17.2,9.5 -21.5,9.5 -6.5,0
    -6.2,-1.3 5.8,-24.7 0.7,-1.3 2.9,-5.8 4.9,-9.8 1.9,-4.0 9.5,-19.0
    16.7,-33.3 19.1,-37.9 29.3,-59.1 29.3,-61 0,-0.9 1.1,-1.6 2.5,-1.6
    1.9,0 3.0,1.7 4.6,7.2 z m 72.0,454.3 c -4.7,1.7 -11.3,6.0 -13.6,8.9
    -1.7,2.1 -2.2,14.3 -0.8,18.1 0.4,1.1 4.0,4.2 8.0,6.7 7.9,5.0
    14.6,5.8 23.4,2.8 8.2,-2.8 14.3,-10.2 14.3,-17.3 0,-3.5 -5.0,-11.8
    -10.3,-16.8 -3.9,-3.7 -14.3,-5.0 -21.0,-2.5 z};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \fill[orange!50!white]
    (current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm impressed by what Inkscape is capable of doing...

Comment: @MarioS.E. In fact, Inkscape uses [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net)...

Answer (score 13):

EDITED to replace the "R" with a mirrored C and a manipulated mirrored integral sign.  REEDITED to make the "V" a reflection of an `\rmfamily` "V".

FINAL EDIT to make the top of the "T" a more accurate rendition. (3RD ATTEMPT)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,wasysym}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
%Save the T's top bar in a \savestack
\savestack{\tbar}{%
\scalebox{2.8}[1]{\slantbox[.14]{$\RHD$}%
\kern-5pt%
\rule[1.28pt]{5pt}{2.55pt}%
\kern-5pt%
\slantbox[-.14]{$\LHD$}}}
%
\scalebox{5}{%
\stackinset{c}{4.3pt}{b}{-.3pt}{\slantbox[-.3]{\scalebox{1.2}[.18]{\reflectbox{$\int$}}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.25pt}{t}{-0.8pt}{\rmfamily.}{%
\stackinset{c}{-2.1pt}{b}{3.2pt}{\scalebox{1.1}[1.3]{\slantbox[-.4]{\tiny o}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-1.1pt}{b}{1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.2]{\slantbox[-.6]{\scriptsize C}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{2.05pt}{b}{1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.2]{\slantbox[.6]{\reflectbox{\scriptsize C}}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.23pt}{c}{3.2pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.3]{%
  \Large \stackon[-1.25pt]{I}{\scalebox{.3}{\tbar}}}}{%
\scalebox{1.5}[1.1]{\reflectbox{\large\rmfamily V}}}%
}}}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2ND ATTEMPT:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\scalebox{5}{%
\stackinset{c}{4.3pt}{b}{-.3pt}{\slantbox[-.3]{\scalebox{1.2}[.18]{\reflectbox{$\int$}}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.25pt}{t}{-1.5pt}{\rmfamily.}{%
\stackinset{c}{-2.1pt}{b}{3.2pt}{\scalebox{1.1}[1.3]{\slantbox[-.4]{\tiny o}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-1.1pt}{b}{1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.2]{\slantbox[-.6]{\scriptsize C}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{2.05pt}{b}{1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.2]{\slantbox[.6]{\reflectbox{\scriptsize C}}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.23pt}{c}{2pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.3]{\large T}}{%
\scalebox{1.5}[1.1]{\reflectbox{\large\rmfamily V}}}%
}}}}}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\scalebox{5}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.2pt}{t}{-1.5pt}{\rmfamily.}{%
\stackinset{c}{-2.5pt}{b}{3.9pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1]{\slantbox[-.2]{\tiny o}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-1pt}{b}{1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.2]{\slantbox[-.6]{\scriptsize C}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{2pt}{b}{}{\slantbox[.55]{\footnotesize R}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-.18pt}{c}{2pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.3]{\large T}}{%
\scalebox{1.5}[1]{\large V}}%
}}}}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `\slantbox` comes from Bruno at [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188)

Comment: You almost have it! :)  Do you think there is something you could do with the **t**?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I'll have to give it some more thought.  An `\rmfamily` "T" is definitely not the solution.  Perhaps I can stretch and skew two overlapping triangles.  (But right now I must depart and shovel some snow)

Comment: Try removing `\sffamily` and `\rmfamily`, and add at the beginning `\usepackage{ebgaramond}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. (`fbb` font is in the neighborhood, too.)

Comment: @AndrewCashner That's a nice font to know, but in this case, it brings some additional problems: the bottom serif on the "T", for example.  Also, the variation in strokes of the "V" is not as pronounced.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MarioS.E. Please see revision.