# How to start with recreating typographical complex stuff?

Tags: typography

I happen to own an early version of "Also Sprach Zarathustra" by Friedrich Nietzsche, and I always found the title-page (just after the the preface) quite nice, and I always wanted to recreate it with LaTeX somehow, but I have no real clue how I should start.

Is it possible to recreate it using METAFONT (which I'd need to learn then), or is it better doing it in TikZ? Does anyone have an idea or could even do some simple letters or something?

This is a scan of the typography-part of the title-page (I didn't want to press too much on the scanner whilst doing this, because I didn't want my edition to be damaged somehow), so I lightened it up a bit with gimp).

[image: Zarathustra]

Thanks.

Comment: Paul's answer to this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220914/victory-symbol-in-salamanca, shows how to convert a scan into a `tikz` drawing, by "using Inkscape to extract the SVG path."

Comment: My suggestion would be first to get a really good scan. There are book scanners that allow you to scan a page in a book cleanly without stressing the binding -- a print shop might be able to do this, or  archive specialists at a local library. Then you can use the scan as the basis for an autotrace -- there are several pieces of software that can do that. Just google 'autotrace'. The ideal would be to find a digital version of the typeface, but a quick search turned up no exact matches.

Comment: although it's vaguely possible that this could be emulated using a font, i believe that this is an example of expert calligraphy. observe the slight differences in the shapes of "s" and the curl at the end of the tail on the "h".  (it *is* quite impressive though.)

Comment: If this font exists in .ttf or .otf formats, it's easy to use it with `Xelatex` or `lualatex`.