# Stacking multiple TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw my university logo. My 5 individual TikZ pictures are OK. However, I don't know how to combine them to a single picture. Code: http://integraali.com/uef-logo-tikz.tex

[image: UEF-logo-original-vs.TikZ]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\vspace{5cm}

\hspace{-1.2cm}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{0}{%
      \pgfmathparse{-0.83*abs(x)-0.28}%
    }
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{0}{%
      \pgfmathparse{-0.6-1.7*(abs(x)-0.7)^2}%
    }
%+1.433 => g(0)=0
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=4.632cm, %height=2.316cm,
width=3.8592cm,%width=1.9296cm,
%height=1.158cm,
%width=0.9648cm,
%anchor=origin, % Same as before <==rotate
%rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)},
  domain=-0.4824:0.4824, %width=0.9648
  ymin=-1.433,
  ymax=-0.28,%height=1.158
  samples=161,
  stack plots=y,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,}
]
%%%\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1] <===flip
% draw graph for the first function f
\addplot+[black,thick,mark=none] {f};
% draw graph of max(g-f, 0) and stack
\addplot+[mark=none,fill=gray!60,black] {g-f} \closedcycle;
%%%\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fff}{0}{%
      \pgfmathparse{-1.3 + x/3 +(x-1.7)^3/15+(x - 1.7)^9/35}%
    }

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ggg}{0}{%
      \pgfmathparse{-1.6+(x-2)^3/6}%
    }
%+1.433 => g(0)=0

\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=3.72cm,
width=2.654cm,
%anchor=origin, % Same as before <==rotate
%rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)},
  domain=0.1973:1.5, %width=1.3027
  ymin=-2.64,
  ymax=-0.78,%height=1.86
  samples=161,
  stack plots=y,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,}
]
%%%\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1] <===flip
% draw graph for the first function f
\addplot+[black,thick,mark=none] {fff};
% draw graph of max(g-f, 0) and stack
\addplot+[mark=none,fill=gray!60,black] {ggg-fff} \closedcycle;
%%%\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-2.5cm}
\hspace{-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=3.72cm,
width=2.654cm,
%anchor=origin, % Same as before <==rotate
%rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)},
  domain=0.1973:1.5, %width=1.3027
  ymin=-2.64,
  ymax=-0.78,%height=1.86
  samples=161,
  stack plots=y,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,}
]
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1] <===flip
% draw graph for the first function f
\addplot+[black,thick,mark=none] {fff};
% draw graph of max(g-f, 0) and stack
\addplot+[mark=none,fill=gray!60,black] {ggg-fff} \closedcycle;
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ff}{0}{%
      \pgfmathparse{-2.1+(x-2)^3/8+(x-2)^7/50}%
    }

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gg}{0}{%
      \pgfmathparse{-3.5-(x-2)^2/3.5}%
    }
%+1.433 => g(0)=0
\vspace{-1cm}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=4.79204cm,
width=3.7342cm,
%anchor=origin, % Same as before <==rotate
%rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)},
  domain=0.1329:2,  %width=1.8671
  ymin=-4.49602,%height=2.39602
  ymax=-2.1,
  samples=161,
  stack plots=y,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,}
]
%%%\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1] <===flip
% draw graph for the first function f
\addplot+[black,thick,mark=none] {ff};
% draw graph of max(g-f, 0) and stack
\addplot+[mark=none,fill=gray!60,black] {gg-ff} \closedcycle;
%%%\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\vspace{-3.5cm}
\hspace{-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=4.79204cm,
width=3.7342cm,
%anchor=origin, % Same as before <==rotate
%rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)},
  domain=0.1329:2,  %width=1.8671
  ymin=-4.49602,%height=2.39602
  ymax=-2.1,
  samples=161,
  stack plots=y,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,}
]
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,yscale=1] <===flip
% draw graph for the first function f
\addplot+[black,thick,mark=none] {ff};
% draw graph of max(g-f, 0) and stack
\addplot+[mark=none,fill=gray!60,black] {gg-ff} \closedcycle;
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could simply add negative vertical spaces between the pictures, e.g. `\vspace*{-1cm}`. BTW, your code throws an error on my TeXLive 2017 distribution.

Comment: Note: maybe you've checked already, but if you plan to use your tikz version of the logo instead of the official image, check whether the university is ok with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the result of the converted [svg logo](https://www.yerun.eu/wp-content/themes/yerun/assets/yerun/img/univs/university-of-eastern-finland.svg) (and not an approximation) using the workflow described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427568).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill svg{M 8.9 -26.7 V -10.7 C 13.3 -11.7 20.1 -13.9 25.7 -19 C 34.2 -26.8 34.3 -46.4 34.3 -46.4 S 31.3 -39.6 25.9 -34.9 C 20.3 -30.1 13.4 -27.8 8.9 -26.7 Z M 49.8 -19 C 55.3 -14 62.2 -11.7 66.6 -10.7 V -26.8 C 62.1 -27.9 55.2 -30.2 49.6 -34.9 C 44 -39.6 41.2 -46.4 41.2 -46.4 S 41.3 -26.8 49.8 -19 Z M 75.4 -35.5 V -62.3 S 70.3 -62.3 61.3 -65.6 C 48 -70.4 40 -83.5 40 -83.5 L 42.5 -61.7 C 43.1 -56.1 45.2 -47.1 53.4 -41.4 C 64.1 -33.9 75.4 -35.5 75.4 -35.5 Z M 0 -35.5 V -62.3 S 5.1 -62.3 14.1 -65.6 C 27.4 -70.4 35.4 -83.5 35.4 -83.5 L 32.9 -61.7 C 32.3 -56.1 30.2 -47.1 22 -41.4 C 11.3 -33.9 0 -35.5 0 -35.5 Z M 37.7 -23.2 S 36.1 -17.3 33.2 -13.6 C 30.4 -10 28 -8.4 28 -8.4 L 37.7 0 L 47.4 -8.4 S 44.9 -10.1 42.2 -13.7 C 39.4 -17.4 37.7 -23.2 37.7 -23.2 Z};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! +1. Didn't know that the svg was available.

Comment: @marmot not the full svg, only the paths. And there are some cavets with "compressed" form and the "scientific" notation.

Comment: How could I change the color of the logo @Kpym?

Comment: @juhisteri as usual `\fill[red] ...` will fill the logo in red. Probably you should learn a little bit how works Ti*k*Z ;)

Answer (score 6):

I would not use pgfplots for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,8.2) to[out=110,in=-30] (-1.2,10.1) -- (0,11.1) --
(1.2,10.1) to[out=210,in=70] cycle;
\fill (-0.5,5.4) to[out=110,in=-10] (-3.5,7.7) -- (-3.5,9.7) 
 to[out=-20,in=100] cycle;
\fill (-0.3,0.7) to[out=110,in=-8] (-4.7,3.3) -- (-4.7,6.6) 
 to[out=0,in=95,looseness=1.25] cycle;
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
\fill (-0.5,5.4) to[out=110,in=-10] (-3.5,7.7) -- (-3.5,9.7) 
 to[out=-20,in=100] cycle;
\fill (-0.3,0.7) to[out=110,in=-8] (-4.7,3.3) -- (-4.7,6.6) 
 to[out=0,in=95,looseness=1.25] cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can cut the corners via `\foreach \x in {1,-1}{\begin{scope}[xscale=\x]
\fill (-0.5,5.4) to[out=110,in=-10] (-3.5,7.7) -- (-3.5,9.7) to[out=-20,in=100] cycle;
\fill (-0.3,0.7) to[out=110,in=-8] (-4.7,3.3) -- (-4.7,6.6)  to[out=0,in=95,looseness=1.25] cycle;
\end{scope}}` since it is symmetric

Comment: @percusse I agree. Yet copy and paste into the scope was even less effort. ;-) But yes, if one is to play around with the parameters, your proposal is certainly better.

Comment: @percusse If you want to cut it down, you don't need `cycle` for `fill` ;)

Comment: @Kpym I do if I want to have a nice miter though

Comment: @percusse nice miter for `fill` ? I need an example here.

Comment: @Kpym for `filldraw` I didn't read the code properly then

Comment: @percusse I am always confused about this. Does the contour of `\fill` have a width, i.e. is the miter really an issue there? (I am not saying you are not right, I am really wondering.)

Comment: @percusse for `filldraw` I agree.

Comment: @Kpym But for the top contour, one does actually need to add cycle, or draw the contour in a different order.

Comment: @percusse and @marmot, sorry, I didn't read the code properly it is a curved `to` to `cycle`, and not a straight line. So you need it !