# Creating the Twitter verified badge using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, svg

I'm trying to create the blue Twitter verified badge using TikZ. The real version looks like this:

[image]

(Source: https://twitter.com/verified)

This is the MWE I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{twitblue}{RGB}{1,156,246}
\newcommand{\verified}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\fill [twitblue] (0,0) circle (.7ex);
\draw [white,scale=0.1,line cap=round,line width=0.2mm](-.4,-.05) -- (-.1,-.3) -- (.4,.4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Joe Bloggs} \verified{} 

\textbf{Joe Bloggs} \verified{scale=1.5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some of the issues:

- I am unsure how to get the curved effect around the edge of the circle.
- The bottom part of the checkmark isn't curved.
- How do I get it to scale correctly? (The white checkmark isn't scaling properly)
- How can I adjust the vertical alignment of the symbol?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The accepted answer provides a TikZ solution as the question originally requested. However, two solutions involving the exact `.svg` file of this badge were also provided. See answers by Kpym: [(If you want the logo to be exactly the same, you can use the SVG original...)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430629/128068) and [(Here is a font solution, without TikZ...)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430655/128068).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `cloud` from the `shapes` library:

[image]

You create a `\node[cloud]`, specify the number of `cloud puffs` (8, from your picture), and the `cloud puff arc` (135° looked right to me).

I added `line join=round` to the tick to make the lower part be rounded.

Also, I changed the color a bit and changed the syntax of the command to allow the optional argument to be optional.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\definecolor{twitblue}{HTML}{1DA1F2}
\newcommand{\verified}[1][1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]%
    \node [draw,fill,twitblue,cloud,cloud puffs=8,cloud puff arc=135, inner sep={#1*0.4ex}] {};
    \draw [white,scale=0.1,line cap=round,line width={#1*0.2mm},line join=round](-.4,-.05) -- (-.1,-.3) -- (.4,.4);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Twitter Verified} \verified[0.5]

\textbf{Twitter Verified} \verified

\textbf{Twitter Verified} \verified[2]

\textbf{Twitter Verified} \verified[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [Twitter blue color](https://about.twitter.com/en_us/company/brand-resources.html) for the logo is `1DA1F2` ;)

Comment: @Kpym My approach was more lazy. I just took the color from OP's picture. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kpym Confusingly when I probe the colour of 'Twitter blue', as displayed on my Chrome browser. I get a different colour - `3AA1F2 `.  I took a screenshot of a few pixels of the colour and checked it using html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/ . Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @Myles Download the twitter logo [zip file](https://about.twitter.com/content/dam/about-twitter/company/brand-resources/en_us/Twitter%20Logos.zip) and check the svg file inside. Or you can also inspect directly the svg "Twitter trusted" logo in [this page](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/about-twitter-verified-accounts).

Comment: @Myles Weird indeed. We shall hold a trial by combat to determine which one is correct. May the gods be on your side :)

Comment: Sorry, I got carried away there. But @Kpym's color indeed looks more Twitter-*y*.

Answer (score 20):

If you want the logo to be exactly the same, you can use the SVG original (which is a single path image) with the `svg.path` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\definecolor{twitter}{HTML}{1DA1F2}
\tikzset{
  twitter verified/.pic={
    \fill[scale=.01cm/1pt,twitter,#1] svg{M50-2.4a19 19 0 0 1-10 17.2l.9 6.6a19 19 0 0 1-18 19.1c-2.4 0-4.8 0-6.7-1.5-2.9 6.7-9 11-16.2 11s-13.3-4.8-16.2-11c-2.4 1-4.3 1.4-6.7 1.5a19 19 0 0 1-18-19.1c0-2.4 0-4.8 .9-6.6a19 19 0 0 1-10-17.2 19 19 0 0 1 9.5-16.6v-2.4a19 19 0 0 1 17.6-19.1c2.4 0 4.8 0 6.7 1.5 2.9-6.7 9-11 16.2-11s13.3 4.8 16.2 11c2.4-1 4.3-1.4 6.7-1.5a19 19 0 0 1 18 21.5 19 19 0 0 1 9.1 16.6zm-31.4 15.7-20.5-30.9a3.3 3.3 0 0 0-4.8-1l-.9 .5-11.4 11.4a3.4 3.4 0 1 0 4.7 4.8l8.6-8.1 18.1 27.6a3.8 3.8 0 0 0 6.2-4.3z};
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,transform shape]
    \pic{twitter verified};
    \pic[scale=.7] at (1,0) {twitter verified=purple};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** The path was adapted following [my favorite workflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427568) for logos.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a font solution, without TikZ.

1. Grab the original SVG file (for example [from here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kpym/533aad00b0439a53f647d9316059774f/raw/TwitterVerified.svg)).
2. Go to [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) and drag the SVG file inside. Then select this new icon.
3. Chose an unicode symbol : I chosed ['CHECK MARK' (U+2713)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm).
   Grab the hex code (in my case `2713`) and put it as a code for this icon in the "Customize codes" tab.
4. Set the font name to "twitterverified". Download the font (a zip file). Extract the [`twitterverified.ttf`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kpym/533aad00b0439a53f647d9316059774f/raw/twitterverified.ttf) to the same folder as your tex file.
5. Use this font, for example like this with XeLaTeX.

   ```
   \documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
     \newfontfamily{\TwitterVerified}{twitterverified.ttf}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
     \definecolor{twitter}{HTML}{1DA1F2}
   \begin{document}
     \textbf{\textsf{Twitter Verified}} \textcolor{twitter}{\TwitterVerified ✓}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]