# Using TikZ to create a custom word which combines an svg image and text

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I am trying to create a custom word, f-hole, where instead of an `f` I use the actual outline of a violin f-hole:

[image]

I have an `.svg` file of the outline I want to make into a symbol, and using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430629/128068) I've managed to use `\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}` to include it in a `tikzpicture`. From there I've manually adjusted the size and position to make it sit next to the piece of text `-hole`. However, I'm having trouble getting it to align with the baseline of my text and get punctuation to work around it (before and after the word).

[image]

Additionally, my solution doesn't scale nicely when I change the size of the font (I need it to work with `footnotesize` and `huge` at a minimum). Any tips to improve this? I need a pdfLaTeX solution.

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\tikzset{
  fhole/.pic={
    \fill [scale=0.045] svg{m141.50504652572636,8.750154755020048 l12.88491,15.0039 c-6.33974,5.397 -6.91986,11.7233 -3.91811,17.7654 c2.79858,4.7279 9.39378,6.1777 14.58215,3.3698 c14.90229,-8.6016 2.97205,-29.2657 -8.32413,-35.8434 c-12.46952,-7.671 -23.48465,-2.9727 -32.06999,2.2816 c-32.57131,21.0958 -31.29905,53.0495 -36.53204,111.7787 l-3.80143,2.2686 l3.46803,2.8209 c-1.81268,50.3552 -7.19548,108.8638 -47.31312,118.9301 l-13.70647,-17.533 c6.63203,-1.8678000000000003 11.01697,-7.1683 12.24781,-13.0208 c1.58418,-12.036 -9.34214,-23.7985 -23.61721,-18.9647 c-14.27507,4.8337 -12.70367,27.7181 -1.47322,39.9927 c11.23043,12.2746 28.2174,15.8516 42.3734,10.8362 c41.92159,-16.3793 51.61678,-67.3469 52.89911,-111.1003 l3.68819,-2.1338 l-3.4807,-3.4122 c2.6751,-40.5983 -4.97189,-105.0606 32.09282,-123.0397 z};
  }
}

\newcommand\fhole{\begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (0,0) pic [yscale=-1] {fhole};
     \node at (0.64,-0.17) {-hole};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
The violin \fhole.

\footnotesize The footnotesize violin \fhole.

\huge The huge violin \fhole.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that commands like `\huge` are switches and don't take arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package `scalerel` could be used to scale the graphics to the size of 'f' in the current fontsize. The kerning is adjusted acc. to @Emma's suggestion.

**Edit:** `\mbox` added to prevent linebreak *before* hyphen and  `\hspace{0pt}` inserted to allow linebreak *after* hyphen.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\tikzset{
  fhole/.pic={
    \fill svg{m141.50504652572636,8.750154755020048 l12.88491,15.0039 c-6.33974,5.397 -6.91986,11.7233 -3.91811,17.7654 c2.79858,4.7279 9.39378,6.1777 14.58215,3.3698 c14.90229,-8.6016 2.97205,-29.2657 -8.32413,-35.8434 c-12.46952,-7.671 -23.48465,-2.9727 -32.06999,2.2816 c-32.57131,21.0958 -31.29905,53.0495 -36.53204,111.7787 l-3.80143,2.2686 l3.46803,2.8209 c-1.81268,50.3552 -7.19548,108.8638 -47.31312,118.9301 l-13.70647,-17.533 c6.63203,-1.8678000000000003 11.01697,-7.1683 12.24781,-13.0208 c1.58418,-12.036 -9.34214,-23.7985 -23.61721,-18.9647 c-14.27507,4.8337 -12.70367,27.7181 -1.47322,39.9927 c11.23043,12.2746 28.2174,15.8516 42.3734,10.8362 c41.92159,-16.3793 51.61678,-67.3469 52.89911,-111.1003 l3.68819,-2.1338 l-3.4807,-3.4122 c2.6751,-40.5983 -4.97189,-105.0606 32.09282,-123.0397 z};
  }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\fhole{\mbox{\scalerel*{\tikz{\path (0,0) pic [yscale=-1] {fhole};}}{f}\hspace{-0.135em}-}\hspace{0pt}hole}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
The violin \fhole.

\footnotesize The footnotesize violin \fhole.

\huge The huge violin \fhole.

xxxxxx xxxxxx The huge violin \fhole.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would think an `\hspace{-.3ex}` should do the trick for the spacing. The units `ex` and `em` are relative the the current font size.

Comment: @Emma I believe a horizontal space (`hspace`) should be given in a unit that is relative to the horizontal font size (`em`) ! - not `ex` that is relative to the vertical font size.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, but for a given font, the ratio between 1ex and 1em is fixed, that is, independent from the font size, as far as I know. Thus, either can be used.

Comment: @AlexG I did not know that - do you have a reference for this? Is no font wider than others?

Comment: Ok, if you change font, it is another story.

Comment: @hpekristiansen You may be right, after all, using a horizontal unit here, because one may want to use e. g.`\bfseries`. Here, the ratio between 1em and 1ex is different.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I did think of the horizontal/vertical discrepancy as I posted, but I was hoping that for most purposes it wouldn't matter much. I had actually thought that both were relative to the height. Now that I investigate further, I see several different definitions and it's not obvious which one TeX uses. Using the trick from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm) I find that the length of an ex differs in bold vs. normal weight font, while the length of an em does not.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not fuzzy about the exact shape, you could produce something similar using an integral sign:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\newcommand\fhole{\rotatebox{-10}{\kern-0.2em$\varint$}\kern-0.2em-hole}


\begin{document}

The normalsize violin \fhole.

\footnotesize The footnotesize violin \fhole.

\huge The huge violin \fhole.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ;) I hadn't realised how close it is to an integral sign! But the whole point of my exercise is to replicate an exact violin f-hole. Hence going to extra lengths to use an svg outline of an f-hole design based on that by Antonio Stradivari :)

Comment: @Milo there are some articles wondering about the similarity, but the answer seems always to be: coincident. Kind of boring... If you want the shape from someone truly famous, you could replace the Stradivari shape with the original integral shape from  Leibniz :)