# IEEEtran - How to include ORCID in TeX/PDF with PdfLatex

Tags: symbols, ieeetran, hyperlink

> **This question led to a new package:**
> [`orcidlink`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink)

I would like to display the ORCID id in an author list in an IEEEtran pdf, like that:
[image: what it should look like]

Is there a standard way to include it in an IEEEtran article with PdfLaTeX?
I used two approaches from [Is there a standard way to include ORCID in TeX / PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275578/is-there-a-standard-way-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf), but I failed.

One is to insert the ORCID icon in the author list. I used the blow code:

```
\author{Ali Al-Obaidi \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/orcid_16x16.png}}}
```

where orchid_16x16.png is provided in the link https://orcid.org/trademark-and-id-display-guidelines. But the result is that the icon is not clear enough, even I replaced it with a different size.

The other approach is to use the [`academicons`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/academicons) package, like that:

```
\usepackage{academicons}
\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\author{AAA \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\aiOrcid}}}
```

However, the result is like that:

[image: faulty result]

And I also got two errors: "Latex Error: Encoding scheme 'TU' unknown" and "Bad character code (59865)".
In the latest academicons.sty (see ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/academicons/academicons.sty), academicons use the font TU. However, it seems that the compiler PdfLateX cannot support this font.

Thus, is there anyone that knows a standard way to include it in an IEEEtran article with PdfLaTeX? Please help me.

Comment: `\usepackage{academicons}` doesn't work with `pdflatex`

Comment: @Milo That's good to know. Are you aware of any alternatives that are compatible with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Milo The package https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5 has the symbol `\faOrcid` and it runs with `pdflatex`. It can also be made green by `{\color{orcidgreen}\faOrcid{}}` (you need to define the color first) or similar. An alternative is the new https://www.ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink.

Comment: @CampanIgnis For full clarity, the orcidlink package on CTAN explicitly notes that it is simply a packaging of the accepted answer on this thread.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**This answer has been packaged into [the `orcidlink` package on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink) by  @duetosymmetry**

---

Here is a `pdflatex` solution which uses `tikz` and the original `.svg` of the orcid icon.

[image]

Here are the steps:

1. Using the `svg.path` TikZ library you can faithfully replicate the icon.
2. I've used the `scalerel` package to scale the icon to the size of `|` (a vertical bar). This means it scales nicely with the size of the font. No special reason for choosing `|` other than it makes the size and placement roughly match the guidelines on the orcid website, which illustrate the icon placement should look something like this:

[image]

3. This has all been wrapped in a command called `orcidicon` which takes as an input the orcid code, e.g. `\orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}`.
4. `\href` takes care of making it hyperlinked.

Note to get a bit of additional spacing after the logo I've used `\,` to add some thinspace.

*Inspired by [Using TikZ to create a custom word which combines an svg image and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439212/using-tikz-to-create-a-custom-word-which-combines-an-svg-image-and-text.)*

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
  orcidlogo/.pic={
    \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
    \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
                 svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
                 svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
  }
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel*{
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,transform shape]
\pic{orcidlogo};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{|}}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\author{John Doe \orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}\,, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to male this work with the `authblk` package? First the `\orcidicon` command needs  a `protect` there and then it completely garbles how more than one author is typeset...

Comment: Sorry, can't help with this. Perhaps you can ask a new question on the site with a MWE of your problem.

Comment: @pankajsingh If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/168864)

Comment: Great, great, great. Anybody did something similar to the DOI icon? Or, any place where I can understand how to convert the DOI svg file into latex tikz commands?

Comment: FYI @Milo, I packaged up your command into a .sty file to make it simple for users, with credit to this answer. The style file can be found here: https://github.com/duetosymmetry/orcidlink-LaTeX-command

Comment: @StefanPinnow What pankajsingh asks is exactly what's asked in the question, it would just be a duplicate question if he asked another!

Comment: @Milo I have not forgotten your "glasses symbol"....:-)

Comment: @duetosymmetry, could you publish the orcidlink.sty at CTAN?

Comment: @FHZ I don't come around here often, so I only saw this message just now. What would I need to do to make it ready for inclusion on the CTAN? Does it need documentation? I've never done that before.

Comment: @duetosymmetry, I'm not such advanced user. I haven't published any of my own packages on CTAN yet, but I may give you some advice.
First: Promote your code to a .sty style file
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_package
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/make-your-own-sty-files
Second: Revise to CTAN
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/854/how-can-i-contribute-to-ctan
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan

Comment: For people having issues to compile it with the llncs class, you just need to replace `\newcommand` with `\newrobustcmd` from `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}`.

Comment: I include the package with `usepackage{orcidlink}` (sty file in the folder), and here is the error:
`<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.33 \ifnum
           \c@pgfmath@counta=0
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra \fi.
l.35 \fi
`

Answer (score 4):

The package to be used here is `orcidlink`.

To use this package, in the preamble include `\usepackage{orcidlink}`.

Full command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pdfstartview=XYZ,
bookmarks=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
pdftex,
bookmarks=true,
linktocpage=true, % makes the page number as hyperlink in table of content
hyperindex=true
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{orcidlink}

\begin{document}

\title{Here is the title}
    
\author{Author 1\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0000}     
    \and
    Author 2\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0000}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see any new information to the accepted answer ...

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: using this package makes some of the titles disappear and changes the color of some others, for ieeeaccess document class

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This looks exactly how it looks on other publications in the IEEE Journals.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variant that uses `pict2e`, if you cannot use `tikz` for some reason:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newsavebox{\ORCIDlogo}
\savebox{\ORCIDlogo}{%
\setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr 1em/256\relax}%
\begin{picture}(256,256)%
  \color[HTML]{A6CE39}\put(128,128){\circle*{256}}%
  \color{white}%
  \put(78.6,199.2){\circle*{20}}%
  \moveto(70.9,176,9)\lineto(86.3,176,9)\lineto(86.3,69.8)\lineto(70.9,69.8)%
  \closepath\fillpath%
  \moveto(108.9,176.9)\lineto(150.5,176.9)%
  \curveto(190.1,176.9)(207.5,148.6)(207.5 ,123.3)%
  \curveto(207.5,95,8)(186,69.7)(150.7,69.7)%
  \lineto(108.9,69.7)%
  \closepath\fillpath%
  \color[HTML]{A6CE39}%
  \moveto(124.3,83.6)\lineto(148.8,83.6)%
  \curveto(183.7,83.6)(191.7,110.1)(191.7,123.3)%
  \curveto(191.7,144.8)(178,163)(148,163)%
  \lineto(124.3,163)%
  \closepath\fillpath%
\end{picture}%
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\ORCIDlogo}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\author{John Doe \orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}\,, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The coordinates are derived directly from the official ORCID Logo SVG.