# authblk with protected commands and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, author, authblk, protected-macro

When trying to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445583/17107) to add a linked image to an author with the `authblk` package, somehow all the following text is shifted, with pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
  blaaa/.pic={
    \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
    \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
                 svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
                 svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
  }
x}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel*{
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,transform shape]
\pic{blaaa};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{|}}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\author[1]{Rincewind \protect\orcidicon{8000-0000-0000-0000}\,, Unseen University}
\affil[1]{\small rw@unseen.edu}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting document]

Is there a way to combine `authblk` with images inside the author macros?  Or is there another package to have authors with arbitrary footnotes/affiliations?  Note that this problem seem to happen with pdfLaTeX only, not with XeLaTeX (there's no hyperlink there though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix with overlay:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path,calc}

\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
  blaaa/.pic={
    \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
    \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
                 svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
                 svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
  }
x}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[ overlay,remember picture]
\coordinate (A);
\coordinate(B) at ($(A)-(7pt,5pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,yscale=0.05,xscale=0.05,transform shape]
\pic at (B) {blaaa};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{|}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\author[1]{Rincewind \protect\orcidicon{8000-0000-0000-0000}\,, Unseen University}
\affil[1]{\small rw@unseen.edu}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]