# ORCID in LaTex file of IEEE Trans. in a customized position

Tags: positioning, ieeetran, icon

I would like to use the ORCID in LaTex file of IEEE Trans. I reached to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445583/120126). I would like to place the ORCID icon in another position in front of the name as:

[image]

How can I do that in a standard way?

Answer (score 4):

May be you could use `\textsuperscript{...}` within an inline math-mode to achieve what you want. As in:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
    orcidlogo/.pic={
        \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
        \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
        svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
        svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
    }
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel*{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,transform shape]
                \pic{orcidlogo};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }{|}}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}

    \title{Title goes here}
    \author{John Doe$^{\textsuperscript{\orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}}}$\,, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}}
    \maketitle
    This answer is copied from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445563/ieeetran-how-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf-with-pdflatex/445583#445583.
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]