Add ORCID instead of email address to IEEE paper template
IEEE template mentioned that it can add email or ORCID. What is a proper way to add this ORCID? When add email address it has clickable email in paper but when add ORCID it not give clickable ID.

Latex code:
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}


"Update" while writing my own answer:
Check out this answer, which I used to reference for the orcid logo design. However, apparently meanwhile there is a package which does the same as I do manually.
For completeness, here is what I use in my papers:
\documentclass[letterpaper, journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% orcid logo, taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445563/ieeetran-how-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf-with-pdflatex/445583#445583
\definecolor{orcidlogocolor}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\def\orcidsymbolpathouter{svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z}}
\def\orcidsymbolpathinner{svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
                     svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
                     svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z}}
\tikzset{
    orcidlogo/.pic={
        \fill[orcidlogocolor] \orcidsymbolpathouter;
        \fill[white] \orcidsymbolpathinner;
    },
}
\def\orcidsymbol{\tikz[yscale = -1, scale = 0.035, transform shape, baseline = -7.5pt] \pic{orcidlogo};}
\def\orcid#1{\tikz[yscale = -1, scale = 0.035, transform shape, baseline = -7.5pt] \pic{orcidlogo};\url{https://orcid.org/#1}}

\title{TITLE TITLE TITLE}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{AUTHOR AUTHOR AUTHOR} \\
    \IEEEauthorblockA{
        AFFILIATION\\
        \orcid{0000-0002-6164-5756}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}


Is this ok to add in IEEE conference paper template?

Depends on how correct you want to be. I personally think it is nice to have a link that can be clicked in a conference paper. However (I know that's written somewhere, but I'm not sure where exactly right now -- some IEEE author guide) officially, you are not supposed to have links in your papers, so I typically replace \url with \textrm. Then you get the same look, but no hyperlinks in the pdf. But I highly doubt that you will have any repercussions if you do.
