# The symbol on Aaron Turon's thesis title page

Tags: symbols

I want to create the symbol Aaron Turon used as a vertical separator on his thesis title page. I think it is typeset like normal text and is not an external Image. It looks like two integral symbols rotated into a horizontal shape. [This](http://aturon.github.io/academic/turon-thesis.pdf) is his Thesis.

[image]

And this is the titlepage:

[image]
Does anyone know how to typeset the symbol?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This one looks like `adforn` n° 21:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adforn}

\begin{document}

\adforn{21}

\end{document}
```

You might also want to take a look at [PGFOrnament](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament?lang=en) and [PSVectorian](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian?lang=en).

Answer (score 7):

> Just for fun, use @PhelypeOleinik nice answer for your work

You can indeed construct such a symbol from integral signs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\scalebox{2}{\rotatebox{-50}{$\int$}\kern-0.95em\rotatebox{-50}{$\int$}}
\end{center}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: haha awesome! really cool

Comment: @bananabombo You could also use the violin holes of Antonio Stradivari instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439212/using-tikz-to-create-a-custom-word-which-combines-an-svg-image-and-text :)