# Make an interesting calligraphy character like an Axe in the Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, graphics, symbols, characters

I am trying to use LaTex/PDFTex to make this character (or at least Figure) in the text.

I could not find any proper charcter look like this:

[image]

> Do you have any way to find this symbol or make this as an character just like an alphabet in English so we can type on LaTex?

Comment: Of course, you can build such a character with Ti*k*Z. People have drawn [glasses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447397/121799) and many other things. It is just tedious to draw this from a screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least a figure with TikZ is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (-0.9,7.1) -- (-4.8,6.79)
-- (-0.72,6.26) -- (-0.71,4.81)
-- (-0.94,3.78) -- (-5.69,3.73)
-- (-0.65,2.96) -- (-0.7,-5.6)
.. controls (-0.78,-5.82) and (-0.74,-6.04)
.. (-1.02,-6.31) .. controls (-1.29,-6.37) and (-1.5,-6.48)
.. (-2.1,-6.27) .. controls (-2.8,-5.98) and (-3.45,-5.43)
.. (-3.92,-4.81) .. controls (-4.32,-3.6) and (-4.38,-2.9)
.. (-4.36,-2) .. controls (-4.12,-0.24) and (-2.85,0.63)
.. (-2.5,1.4) .. controls (-3.8,1.1) and (-4.22,0.5)
.. (-4.74,-0.7) .. controls (-5.32,-2.05) and (-5.47,-3.2)
.. (-4.84,-4.6) .. controls (-4.6,-5.2) and (-4.23,-5.7)
.. (-3.31,-6.47) .. controls (-2.16,-7.14) and (-1.5,-7.19)
.. (-0.3,-7.2) .. controls (1,-7.15) and (1.91,-7.14)
.. (2.8,-6.46) .. controls (3.81,-5.56) and (4.1,-4.7)
.. (4.35,-4.2) .. controls (4.7,-3.3) and (4.88,-2.11)
.. (4.5,-1.1) .. controls (4.18,-0.24) and (3.7,0.41)
.. (3.24,0.9) .. controls (2.8,1.25) and (2.48,1.37)
.. (1.94,1.61) .. controls (2.88,0.29) and (3.56,-0.75)
.. (3.81,-1.6) .. controls (4.09,-2.97) and (3.72,-4.18)
.. (2.86,-5.18) .. controls (2.46,-5.67) and (2.4,-5.78)
.. (1.76,-6.06) .. controls (1.06,-6.51) and (0.6,-6.5) .. (0.2,-6.3)
.. controls (0.19,-3.59) and (0.16,-1.8)
.. (0.28,3.06) -- (5.26,3.4)
-- (0.22,3.97) -- (0.2,6.25)
-- (4.54,6.68) -- (2.39,6.99) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add.
A more symmetric figure could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (s0) at (0,7.15);
\coordinate (s1) at (-4.6,6.8);
\coordinate (s12) at (4.6,6.8);
\coordinate (s2) at (-0.5,6.3);
\coordinate (s11) at (0.5,6.3);
\coordinate (s3) at (-0.5,4);
\coordinate (s10) at (0.5,4);
\coordinate (s4) at (-5.4,3.4);
\coordinate (s9) at  (5.4,3.4);
\coordinate (s5) at (-0.5,3);
\coordinate (s8) at  (0.5,3);
\coordinate (s6) at (-0.5,-6.2);
\coordinate (s7) at  (0.5,-6.2);

\fill[black] (s0) -- (s1) -- (s2) -- (s3) -- (s4) -- (s5) -- (s6)
.. controls (-4.9,-6.5) 
and (-5,-0.9) .. (-2.3,1.4) .. controls (-6.5,-0.9) 
and (-5.7,-7.1) .. (0,-7.1) .. controls (5.7,-7.1) 
and (6.5,-0.9) .. (2.3,1.4) .. controls (5,-0.9) 
and (4.9,-6.5) .. (s7) -- (s8) -- (s9) -- (s10) -- (s11) -- (s12) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: more symmetric figure]

Comment: thanks +1, this is the coolest way to make a figure indeed.

Comment: Indeed, I will accept vi pa's answer if the figure can be made as simple as symmetric as it should be (The vi pa's answer is very nice and too authenticate and genuine to my OP.)

Comment: @annieheart I've add a more symmetric figure. Obviously there is some arbitrariness in the way of make a figure "more symmetric" and "more clean".

Answer (score 3):

One option is to save the image (Xsney.png) and then make a macro. If you fiddle with the spacing a bit, it looks ok. Note the `\` after the macro call if you want a space after the symbol.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Xsney}{\hspace{-.1em}\raisebox{-.1ex}{\resizebox{1.8ex}{!}{\includegraphics{Xsney.png}}}\hspace{-.1em}}

\begin{document}

I don't know what \Xsney\ means. O\Xsney O 

{\Large I don't know what \Xsney\ means. O\Xsney O}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After looking at this some more, I think I like `\raisebox{-.15ex}` better. Up to you of course.

Comment: thanks +1, this is the most simple way indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can :

1. Convert your PNG to SVG using Inkscape for example.
2. Use your SVG to create à custom font with [fontello](http://fontello.com/). I assigned your symbol to the `O` letter.
3. Use the so defined `xseny.ttf` within XeLaTeX like this :

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \newfontfamily{\Xseny}{xseny.ttf}
\begin{document}
  \textbf{\textsf{Xseny symbol}} {\Xseny O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note :** This answer follow the same workflow as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430655).