# How can I input the Gucci logo?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, symbols

I'd like to input the [Gucci](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/1960s_Gucci_Logo.svg/2000px-1960s_Gucci_Logo.svg.png)
 logo in math mode 
in a TeX document what's the best way to do this?

Comment: save the image and use `\includegraphics{the-image-you-saved}`  what did you try?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply use `\includegraphics{graphicfile}`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's lawful to use a trademark symbol for your own purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I stress that on purpose this is not a perfect match since I don't want get into legal trouble. However, this post is meant to explain how to do something similar to that logo.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=4mm] ($(-1,0)+(18:1.8)$) -- ++(0,0.04) arc(18:350:1.85)
-- ++(-0.6,0);
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
\draw[line width=4mm] ($(-1,0)+(18:1.8)$) -- ++(0,0.04) arc(18:350:1.85)
-- ++(-0.6,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes. For instance, the start above the gap is not straight.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Do you think this is necessary? (I hope our world is not yet *that* crazy. ;-)

Comment: @CarLaTeX But the user shared an svg file that is freely available. If someone would want to forge the logo, (s)he will definitely use the svg and not the tikz code.

Comment: Trademarks protect the logo for "trade" purposes, to identify the company. It's not copyright.  As far as you are not impersonating Gucci or pretend some product is from Gucci or anyway associating anything non-Gucci with Gucci, you're fine. In this case, showing the logo to explain how to draw it is perfectly fine. If this were some copyrighted material this would still fall under "fair use", so fine as well (not a lawyer here, though)

Answer (score 2):

The following code was generated using [my favorite workflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427568/9335) for logos using [the wikimedia's svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/1960s_Gucci_Logo.svg).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill svg{M 66 -16 c -16 0 -29 -11 -34 -25 h 7 c 4 11 14 19 27 19 c 15 0 28 -12 27 -28 s -12 -28 -27 -28 c -12 0 -22 8 -27 18 h 8 v 7 h -16 c 2 -18 16 -31 35 -31 c 19 0 34 15 34 34 s -15 34 -34 34 z};
    \fill svg{M 34 -16 c 16 0 29 -11 34 -25 h -7 c -4 11 -14 19 -27 19 c -15 0 -28 -12 -27 -28 s 12 -28 27 -28 c 12 0 22 8 27 18 h -8 v 7 h 16 c -2 -18 -16 -31 -35 -31 c -19 0 -34 15 -34 34 s 15 34 34 34 z};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]