# Svg to Tikz doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg, inkscape

I'm using inkscape to draw a simple picture and i saved with svg extension 
I want to convert this svg file to Tikz code for latex
I download the extensions from github https://github.com/paaguti/svg2tikz and i Extract the files
**tikz_export.py**, **tikz_export_effect.inx**, and **tikz_export_output.inx** from svg2tikz-master/svg2tikz/extensions and put them in the share/extension directory inside the Inkscape installation directory.
when i chose extension->exporter->export to tikz path i get this message and nothing happen;

- **Inscape a reçu des données additionnelles du script exécuté. Le
  script n’a pas retourné d’erreur, mais ceci peut indiquer que les
  résultats ne sont pas ceux attendus.**
- tikz_export.py:645: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or
  `optparse` has been deprecated and replaced with `argparser`.You
  must change `self.OptionParser.add_option` to
  `self.arg_parser.add_argument`; the arguments are similar.
- parser = self.OptionParser
- Traceback (most recent call last):
- File "tikz_export.py", line 1478, in
- main_inkscape()
- File "tikz_export.py", line 1461, in main_inkscape
- effect = TikZPathExporter(inkscape_mode=True)   File
  "tikz_export.py", line 629, in **init**
     self._set_up_options()
- File "tikz_export.py", line 646, in _set_up_options
     parser.set_defaults(codeoutput='standalone', crop=False, clipboard=False, AttributeError: 'TikZPathExporter' object has no
  attribute 'set_defaults'

Comment: Do I understand you correctly in that you just want to include your drawing in your document? In that case, why don't you just use the `svg` package? You can read about how to set it up in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973).

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using Inkscape 1.1 on mac OSX 11.0. I expect, that the extension is too old.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever get around to resolving this?

Comment: No I forgot this

Comment: I had the same problem with `svg2tikz` but suceeded with`SVGPathy` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427568).