# How can we make a pumpkin, jack-o-lantern, or other halloween spirit, ghoul, or skeleton?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, fun

We have questions about [Christmas trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39149/22413) and [Hearts for Valentines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139733/22413) but we have no questions that specialize in Halloween or Dia de los Muertos art. Here it goes:

Using Ti*k*Z or PSTricks or any other of your favorite LaTeX tools, create pumpkins, ghouls, etc., appropriate to the season.

I think multiple submissions should be fine provided different objects are created.

Comment: *Boys and girls of every age, wouldn't you like to see something strange?* `:)`

Comment: We have `chickenize`. The time is ripe for a pumpkinification package.

Comment: @Thérèse --- [in fact ...](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath)

Answer (score 88):

Here's some diabolical TikZ code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikz[background rectangle/.style={fill=black},show background rectangle]\foreach\c[count=\i from0]in{red!10!black,red!15!black,red!20!black,red!25!black,red!30!black,red!35!black,red!40!black,red!45!black,red!50!black,red!55!black,red!60!black,red!65!black,red!75!black,red!75!black!75!orange,red!75!black!50!orange,red!75!black!25!orange,red!75!black!5!orange,orange,orange!75!yellow,orange!50!yellow,orange!25!yellow,yellow,yellow!75,yellow!50,white}\clip[preaction={fill=\c},xscale=1-\i/100,yshift=(\i>0)*1.5](-6,-7)(6,3)\foreach\x in{1,-1}{[xscale=\x](0:1)to[bend right]++(315:2)to[bend right]++(60:4)to[bend right,looseness=0.5]cycle}[shift=(270:\i/15),yscale=1-\i/50](0:5)arc(360:330:5 and 3)\foreach\i in{330,300,270,240}{arc(\i:\i-10:5 and 3)--(\i-15:5 and 5)--(\i-20:5 and 3)arc(\i-20:\i-30:5 and 3)}arc(210:180:5 and 3)arc(180:195:5 and 6)\foreach\i in{195,225,255,285,315}{arc(\i:\i+10:5 and 6)--(\i+15:5 and 4)--(\i+20:5 and 6)arc(\i+20:\i+30:5 and 6)}arc(345:360:5 and 6)--cycle;
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this may take until next Halloween to compile:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}
\tikzset{pics/flame/.style 2 args={code={
  \fill [fill=#1, yscale=1-#2/4, xscale=1-#2/5, rotate=rand*5]
    (0:.5+rnd) coordinate (a) arc (360:180:1 and 1) 
    .. controls ++(90:rnd)            and ++(270:rnd) .. (90+rand*5:2+rnd*2)
    .. controls ++(270+rand*5:.5+rnd) and ++(90+rand*5:.5+rnd) .. (a) 
    \pgfextra{\pgfgetpath\flame\global\let\flame=\flame};
  \foreach \l in {1,...,20}
    \draw [draw=#1, line width=\l/2, draw opacity=1/10] \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\flame};
}}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{flames}{burn}{
  \state{burn}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
     \pic {flame={flame}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}};
   }
}
\colorlet{flame}{red}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=black}, show background rectangle, line join=round]
\useasboundingbox (-20,-20) rectangle (20,20); 
\foreach \c [count=\x from 0] in {red!50!black, red!75!black, orange, yellow}{
  \colorlet{flame}{\c}
  \draw [decoration={flames, segment length=1.5cm-\x*0.125cm, amplitude=\x}, decorate] 
    circle [radius=15]
    (270:15) -- (54:15) -- (198:15) -- (342:15) -- (126:15) -- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [I am the one hiding under your bed, teeth ground sharp and eyes glowing red!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny33f3mSjHs) `:)`

Comment: The “depth” in the lower part of the mouth (in the center) has changed (to the worse, in my opinion). Is this intended? Or does the pumpkin need a new dental care plan?

Comment: @Manuel you're right. In part that resulted from treating the mouth and eyes as one path (before they were independent), making adjustments trickier. I've "kind-of" sorted it now.

Answer (score 34):

tikz?, pstricks? everyone knows the underworld used picture mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\pagecolor[RGB]{255,177,69}
\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(120,200)
\thicklines
\put(100,100){\circle{150}}

\put(70,130){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(70,130){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\put(60,120){\line(1,0){20}}

\put(130,130){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(130,130){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\put(120,120){\line(1,0){20}}

\put(100,90){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(100,90){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\put(90,80){\line(1,0){20}}

\put(70,50){\line(1,0){60}}
\put(70,50){\line(-2,1){5}}
\put(130,50){\line(2,1){5}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any method is fine by me.

Comment: The underworld and the aviation industry?

Comment: Er, this seems more like a smiley than anything Hallow-y to me... Maybe if you used an eclipse instead of a circle?

Comment: @thkala beware that smile, danger lurks...

Comment: [Everyone hail to the Pumpkin King!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny33f3mSjHs) `:)`

Comment: If you downvote any question on the site it's normal to leave a comment saying why...

Answer (score 32):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\def\onehalf{
\fill(0.25,0) to [bend right] ++(180:1) to [bend right] ++(330:1.5) to[bend right, looseness=0.5] cycle;
\draw [decoration={expanding waves,angle=4,segment length=0.5pt},decorate] (-1cm,0.7cm) to[out=0,in=140] (0.7cm,-0.2cm);
\fill (1.05cm,-1.1cm) to[out=270,in=180] ++(2mm,-0.4cm) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=0.5] cycle;
\fill[preaction={draw,decorate},decoration={ticks}] (-0.3,-1.5) to[out=-30,in=180] (1,-2) to[bend left] (1,-3) to[bend left] cycle;}
\onehalf\begin{scope}[cm={-1,0,0,1,(2,0)}]\onehalf\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach to the reflection.

Comment: [I am the shadow on the moon at night, filling your dreams to the brim with fright!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny33f3mSjHs) `:)`

Answer (score 18):

A truly demonic entity would manually write its own postscript code.

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%Title: pumpkin.eps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 200 200
/tri {newpath 0 0 moveto 10 0 lineto 0 20 lineto -10 0 lineto closepath fill} bind def
1.0 0.6 0.25 setrgbcolor
1 setlinewidth
100 100 100 0 360 arc gsave stroke grestore fill
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
100 90 60 190 350 arc stroke
100 100 translate tri
-50 40 translate tri
100 0 translate tri
showpage
%EOF
```

[image: pumpkin]

Comment: and thkla said _mine_ looked like a smiley!

Comment: A bit too round and too happy for me. Maybe an eclipse instead of a circle, and a flat black rectangle for the mouth?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Don't worry, this does too :-)

Comment: Goota love this pumpkin. `:)` Can't wait for a poker face version. `:)`

Answer (score 18):

[image: all hallows eve]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\newcommand*{\llygaddienyddiwr}{\textpmhg{\He}}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
% adapted (simplified version) from tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  on foreground layer/.style={%
                execute at begin scope={%
                  \pgfonlayer{foreground}%
                  \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
                  \tikzset{every on foreground layer/.try,#1}%
                  \tikz@options%
                },
                execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{%
  pics/yr Angau/.style n args={2}{
        code={
          \path  (-#2/4,-.55*#2)
                |- (-.15*#2,-.15*#2) coordinate (angau7)
                [out=-20, in=110] to (-.025*#2,-.25*#2) coordinate (angau8)
                [out=85, in=-85] to (0,-.1*#2) coordinate (angau9)
                [out=135, in=-100] to (-.125*#2,-.015*#2) coordinate (angau3)
                -| (-#2/4,#2/2) -| (.375*#2,-.55*#2) -- cycle;
          \path [line cap=round, line width=.025*#2]
                  (0,-.5125*#2) coordinate (angau5) -- ++(-#2/6,.95*#2) coordinate [pos=.875] (angau4) coordinate [pos=.95] (angau1);
          \path [draw=#1, fill=#1, line width=.005*#2, line join=miter]% llafn
                (angau1) [out=30, in=150] to ($(angau5) + (.375*#2,#2)$) [out=-30, in=135] to ++(.125*#2,-.1*#2) [out=135, in=30] to (angau4);
                \path [angau clogyn={#1}{#2}]% corff & pen
                (-.2*#2,-#2/2)
                  [out=85, in=-110] to (angau7)
                  [out=160, in=-45] to (-.2*#2,-.115*#2)
                  [out=135, in=-135] to (-.2*#2,.075*#2)
                  [out=45, in=-135] to (-.05*#2,.125*#2)
                  [out=80, in=-80] to (-.075*#2,.2*#2)
                  [out=100, in=-150] to (.025*#2,.35*#2) coordinate (pen angau)
                  [out=-35, in=80] to (.125*#2,.2*#2)
                  [out=-100, in=170] to (.15*#2,.1*#2)
                  [out=-10, in=120] to (.3*#2,-#2/2)
                  [out=170, in=-10] to cycle;
          \path [angau inner={#1}{#2}]% gwyneb
                (.025*#2,.325*#2) coordinate (pen angau1)
                  [out=-40, in=60] to (.025*#2,.125*#2) coordinate (angau6)
                  [out=120, in=-145] to cycle;
          \begin{scope}% carn (neu 'dwrn'?)
                \clip  (-#2/4,-.55*#2)
                  |- (angau7)
                  [out=-20, in=110] to(angau8)
                  [out=85, in=-85] to (angau9)
                  [out=135, in=-100] to (angau3)
                  -| (-#2/4,#2/2) -| (.375*#2,-.55*#2) -- cycle;
                \path [draw=#1, line cap=round, line width=.025*#2]
                  (angau5) -- (angau1);
          \end{scope}
          \path [angau outer={#2}{#1}]% llewysau (llinellau)
                (angau6)
                  [out=-100, in=85] to (.025*#2,-#2/2)
                (angau7)
                  [out=-20, in=110] to (angau8)
                  [out=85, in=-85] to (angau9)
                  [out=135, in=-100] to (angau3)
                (.15*#2,-.02*#2)
                  [out=-60, in=30] to (.125*#2,-.175*#2) coordinate (angau10)
                  [out=-10, in=135] to (.275*#2,-.475*#2) coordinate (angau2);
          \path [angau inner={#1}{#2}]% llawes chwith
                (angau8) [out=85, in=-85] to (angau9) [out=-85, in=-85] to cycle;
          \path [angau inner={#1}{#2}]% llawes dde
                (angau10) [out=-10, in=135] to (angau2) [out=135, in=-20] to ($(angau10) + (-.005*#2,-.015*#2)$) [out=160, in=170] to cycle;
        }
  },
  pics/dienyddiwr/.style n args={2}{
        code={
          \begin{scope}[on foreground layer]% carn (neu 'dwrn'?)
                \path (-#2/4,-.55*#2)
                  |- (-.15*#2,-.15*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr7)
                  [out=-20, in=110] to (-.025*#2,-.25*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr8)
                  [out=85, in=-85] to (0,-.1*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr9)
                  [out=135, in=-100] to (-.125*#2,-.015*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr3)
                  -| (-#2/4,#2/2) -| (.375*#2,-.55*#2) -- cycle;
                \begin{scope}
                  \clip  (-#2/4,-.55*#2)
                        |- (dienyddiwr7)
                        [out=-20, in=110] to (dienyddiwr8)
                        [out=-85, in=-85] to (dienyddiwr9)
                        [out=135, in=-100] to (-.125*#2,-.015*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr3)
                        -| (-#2/4,#2/2) -| (.375*#2,-.55*#2) -- cycle;
                  \path [draw=#1, line cap=round, line width=.025*#2]
                  (-.05*#2,-.25*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr5) -- ++(#2/4,.45*#2) coordinate [pos=.875] (dienyddiwr4) coordinate [pos=.95] (dienyddiwr1);
                \end{scope}
          \end{scope}
          \path [draw=#1, fill=#1, line width=.005*#2, line join=miter]% llafn
                (dienyddiwr1)
                  [out=-35, in=-115] to ++(.2*#2,-.025*#2)
                  [out=-90, in=35] to ($(dienyddiwr4) + (.125*#2,-.175*#2)$)
                  [out=65, in=-35] to (dienyddiwr4);
          \path [angau clogyn={#1}{#2}]% corff & pen
          (-.2*#2,-#2/2)
                [out=85, in=-110] to (dienyddiwr7)
                [out=160, in=-45] to (-.2*#2,-.115*#2)
                [out=135, in=-135] to (-.2*#2,.075*#2)
                [out=45, in=-135] to (-.05*#2,.125*#2)
                [out=80, in=-80] to (-.075*#2,.2*#2)
                [out=100, in=-150] to (.025*#2,.35*#2) coordinate (pen dienyddiwr)
                [out=-35, in=80] to (.125*#2,.2*#2)
                [out=-100, in=170] to (.15*#2,.1*#2)
                [out=-10, in=120] to (.3*#2,-#2/2)
                [out=170, in=-10] to cycle;
          \path [angau inner={#1}{#2}]% gwyneb
                (.025*#2,.325*#2) coordinate (pen dienyddiwr1)
                  [out=-40, in=60] to (.025*#2,.125*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr6)
                  [out=120, in=-145] to cycle;
          \begin{scope}[on foreground layer]
                \path [angau outer={#2}{#1}]% llewysau (llinellau)
                  (dienyddiwr7)
                        [out=-20, in=110] to (dienyddiwr8)
                        [out=85, in=-85] to (dienyddiwr9)
                        [out=135, in=-100] to (dienyddiwr3)
                  (.15*#2,-.02*#2)
                        [out=-60, in=30] to (.125*#2,-.175*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr10)
                        [out=-10, in=135] to (.275*#2,-.475*#2) coordinate (dienyddiwr2);
                \path [angau inner={#1}{#2}]% llawes chwith
                  (dienyddiwr8) [out=85, in=-85] to (dienyddiwr9) [out=-85, in=-85] to cycle;
                \path [angau inner={#1}{#2}]% llawes dde
                  (dienyddiwr10) [out=-10, in=135] to (dienyddiwr2) [out=135, in=-20] to ($(dienyddiwr10) + (-.005*#2,-.015*#2)$) [out=160, in=170] to cycle;
          \end{scope}
          \path [angau outer={#2}{#1}]% clogyn (llinell canolog)
                (dienyddiwr6)
                  [out=-100, in=85] to (.025*#2,-#2/2);
          \begin{scope}% llygaid
                  \clip (pen dienyddiwr1) [out=-40, in=60] to (dienyddiwr6) [out=120, in=-145] to cycle;
                  \path [fill=#1!25!darkgray, draw=#1!25!darkgray, line width=.005*#2]
                        ($(dienyddiwr6)!2/3!(pen dienyddiwr1) - (.03*#2,0)$) coordinate (llygad dienyddiwr chwith) +(.005*#2,0) coordinate (llygad dienyddiwr chwith1) circle (.013*#2 and .003*#2)
                        ($(dienyddiwr6)!2/3!(pen dienyddiwr1) + (.03*#2,0)$) coordinate (llygad dienyddiwr de) +(-.006*#2,0) coordinate (llygad dienyddiwr de1) circle (.013*#2 and .003*#2);
                  \path [fill=#1, draw=#1, line width=.005*#2]
                        (llygad dienyddiwr chwith1) +(.003*#2,0) circle (.003*#2)
                        (llygad dienyddiwr de1) +(-.003*#2,0) circle (.003*#2);
                  \node [#1, font=\tiny, xscale=-.0075*#2, yscale=.0075*#2, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center] at (llygad dienyddiwr chwith) {\llygaddienyddiwr};
                  \node [#1, font=\tiny, scale=.0075*#2, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center] at (llygad dienyddiwr de) {\llygaddienyddiwr};
          \end{scope}
        }
  },
  angau outer/.style n args={2}{draw=#2, line join=miter, line width=.005*#1},
  angau clogyn/.style n args={2}{angau outer={#2}{#1}, inner color=#1, outer color=black},
  angau inner/.style n args={2}{angau clogyn={#1!25!black}{#2}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={top color=black!35!red, bottom color=black!85!red}, show background rectangle]
  \pic {yr Angau={darkgray}{50pt}};
  \pic at (1,0) {dienyddiwr={red}{50pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

A complete Halloween scene, in one line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[
\bigpumpkin\bigskull\mathwitch\mathghost\mathbat\rip
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: halloween]

(I just discovered the awesome [halloweenmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath), and must now find a way to use it in my work.)

Answer (score 5):

Here comes a cute expl3 pumpkin ...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\draw_begin:

\draw_linewidth:n { 6pt }
\color_stroke:n { black }

\color_stroke:n { yellow!25!green }
\color_fill:n { yellow!50!green }
\draw_path_moveto:n { 2.5cm , 4.5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 0 } { 90 } { 2cm } { 0.75cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnn { 0 } { 90 } { 3cm }
\draw_path_lineto:n { -2.5cm , 7.75cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnn { 90 } { 0 } { 2cm }
\draw_path_lineto:n { -0.5cm , 5.25cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 90 } { 180 } { 2.5cm } { 0.75cm }
\draw_path_close:
\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }

\color_stroke:n { yellow!25!red }
\color_fill:n { yellow!50!red }
\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { -4cm , 0cm } { 3cm , 0cm } { 0cm , 4.8cm } 
\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { 4cm , 0cm } { 3cm , 0cm } { 0cm , 4.8cm } 
\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }
\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { -2.5cm , 0cm } { 3cm , 0cm } { 0cm , 4.9cm } 
\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { 2.5cm , 0cm } { 3cm , 0cm } { 0cm , 4.9cm } 
\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }
\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { 0cm , 0cm } { 3cm , 0cm } { 0cm , 5cm } 
\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
\draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , 5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 90 } { 130 } { 3cm } { 5cm } 
\draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , 5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 90 } { 50 } { 3cm } {5cm } 
\draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , -5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 270 } { 230 } { 3cm } { 5cm } 
\draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , -5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 270 } { 310 } { 3cm } {5cm } 
\draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }

\color_stroke:n { black }
\draw_path_moveto:n { -3.5cm , 1cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnn { 180 } { 0 } { 1cm }
\draw_path_moveto:n { 1.5cm , 1cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnn { 180 } { 0 } { 1cm }
\draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }

\color_fill:n { red!33 }
\draw_path_circle:nn { -4cm , -0.25cm } { 0.75cm }
\draw_path_circle:nn { 4cm , -0.25cm } { 0.75cm }
\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\color_fill:n { black }
\draw_path_moveto:n { -1.5cm , -0.5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnn { 180 } { 360 } { 1.5cm }
\draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke, fill, clip }

\color_fill:n { black!25!red }
\draw_path_moveto:n { -1.25cm , -2.5cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnn { 180 } { 0 } { 1.25cm }
\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\draw_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{formula}{Formula}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{240mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{142mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.3in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3in}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [black!80, rotate=05] (1,0) ellipse (0.25cm and 1.0cm);
\fill [black!80, rotate=-05] (-1,0) ellipse (0.25cm and 1.0cm);
\draw (-4,-6) .. controls (-3,1) and ( -1,3) .. (0,3)
          .. controls (1,3) and (3,1) .. (4,-6);
\draw (-4,-6) .. controls (-4.5,-6.5) and (-2.5, -6) .. (0,-6);
\draw (4,-6) .. controls (4.5,-6.5) and (2.5,-6) ..  (0,-6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\Large {We wish you HAPPY HALLOWEEN!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This just calls for a plot ... (it is probably the ghost of trigonometry)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-pi:pi] {sin(90-deg(x)};
    \fill (0.5,0.25) ellipse [x radius=.1, y radius=.1];
    \fill (-0.5,0.25) ellipse [x radius=.1, y radius=.1];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Almost normal horror :-)

Comment: So this is the paranormal distribution?

Comment: @AlanMunn But that ghost would have another function, I think ... namely to scare away students from statistics