# A command like `\hspace` calculating the distance from the beginning of the line

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I would like to place several blocks of text in `one line`, but fixing their positions by distances from the beginning of the line. For example

`(1.2pt from beginning) cat (2.1pt from beginning) dog (2.9pt from beginning) bird`

`\hspace` does not work, since it fixes the distances from the end of the last word. Is there a command which fixes this distance from the beginning of the line? If the words are too long or too close to each other, they should overlap.

Comment: There are several ways how to do that: `\rlap`, `\hbox to`, `tabbing`, `tabular`, ... In order to give you the best answer, we would need to know some background as what do you want it for. Maybe construct a MWE using `\hspace*` and then say what should be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tabto` package does what you want.  If a `\tabto` requires a leftward tab, it will issue a linefeed, unless you use the `\tabto*` invocation.  Below, I show successive `\tabto`'s with and without the `*` variant.

Note that a blank line appears between the two versions in the output because the `\tabto{1.2pt}cat` is a leftward tab relative to the `\parindent` value (so a linefeed was inserted).  If I had added a `\noindent` prior to the invocation, no blank line would have appeared.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\tabto*{1.2pt}cat
\tabto*{2.1pt}dog
\tabto*{2.9pt}bird

\tabto{1.2pt}cat
\tabto{2.1pt}dog
\tabto{2.9pt}bird
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `tabbing`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent\vrule height2pt depth 2pt\hrulefill\vrule % to show the line width

\begin{tabbing}
\=\hspace{10pt}\=\hspace{10pt}\=\hspace{10pt}\=\kill
\>\> cat \> dog \> bird \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I refuse to show the result with too narrow distances.

An environment where you can specify the distances from the left margin and doesn't require the starting `\>\>`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ftabbing}{m}
 {
  \marioscool_set_distances:n { #1 }
  \begin{tabbing}
  \tl_use:N \l__marioscool_preamble_tl
 }
 {
  \end{tabbing}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__marioscool_preamble_tl
\dim_new:N \l__marioscool_distance_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \marioscool_set_distances:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__marioscool_preamble_tl
  \dim_zero:N \l__marioscool_distance_dim
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__marioscool_preamble_tl
     {
      \exp_not:n { \=\hspace } { \dim_eval:n { ##1 - \l__marioscool_distance_dim } }
     }
    \dim_add:Nn \l__marioscool_distance_dim { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__marioscool_preamble_tl { \=\+\+\kill }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent\vrule height2pt depth 2pt\hrulefill\vrule % to show the line width

% this one is for comparison
\begin{tabbing}
\=\hspace{10pt}\=\hspace{10pt}\=\hspace{10pt}\=\kill
\>\> cat \> dog \> bird \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{ftabbing}{10pt,20pt,40pt}
cat \> dog \> bird \\
AAA \> BBB \> CCC \\
\end{ftabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{picture}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(1.2pt,0){cat}
\put(2.1pt,0){dog}
\put(2.9pt,0){bird}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the first coordinate `(0,0)`? Is it the anchor of some box?

Comment: @Sigur it's the size of the box for the entire picture (not very big in this case:-)

Comment: @Sigur it's standard latex syntax (just used the `picture` package so could use `pt` not integer coordinates). See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209940/1090

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. Note that your horizontal spaces are too short. I made an example with other units, just to show better the output.

The black lines are the left and top margins of text area, produce by `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\rlap{\hspace*{1.2pt}cat}%
\rlap{\hspace*{2.1pt}dog}%
\rlap{\hspace*{2.9pt}bird}

\noindent%
\rlap{\hspace*{1.2ex}cat}%
\rlap{\hspace*{2.1ex}dog}%
\rlap{\hspace*{2.9ex}bird}
\end{document}
```

[image]