# How use parts of an eps image?

Tags: graphics, eps

I am working on a college presentation and I'd like to include some graphics into my latex baposter.

The graphics is eps free file, similar to the below:
http://freedesignfile.com/552-hand-draw-flower-vector-02/

For example, if I choose the above file, I need to display each flower separately in different sections of my poster. I tried trimming the image (like [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image)), but it does not give good results.

Extremely appreciate any tips on how to go about this from within latex or some free graphics program.

Comment: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) can edit encapsulated postcript files. Not trivial, but the tutorials are good.

Comment: Are you using pdflatex ? Have you epstopdf ? Work trim & clip with with png, jpg or pdf files ?

Comment: Thanks for comments.  I have used eps2pdf to convert the image to pdf and then tried cropping the image by trim command in latex, but did not  get good results. I am using TexNicCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of an `eps` file, you will find the bounding box, a sequence of four numbers which define the left, lower, right and upper edges of the image (in that order). In [this masterpiece](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209991/2417), the bounding box is 0 0 200 200.

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%Title: pumpkin.eps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 200 200
/tri {newpath 0 0 moveto 10 0 lineto 0 20 lineto -10 0 lineto closepath fill} bind def
1.0 0.6 0.25 setrgbcolor
1 setlinewidth
100 100 100 0 360 arc gsave stroke grestore fill
0 0 0 setrgbcolor 
100 90 60 190 350 arc stroke
100 100 translate tri
-50 40 translate tri
100 0 translate tri
showpage
%EOF
```

Using optional arguments to `\includegraphics*`, you can define a viewing window, which can be different to the bounding box. The example below displays the upper right corner and the centre of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics*[100,100][200,200]{pumpkin}
\quad
\includegraphics*[050,050][150,150]{pumpkin}
\end{document}
```

[image: crop]

However, this doesn't work with `pdflatex`. To get around this, make a copy of the `eps` file and change the bounding box there before converting to `pdf`.