# Defined a character with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter - "Undefined control sequence" when I use it

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I'm trying to define some unicode characters to add a halloween theme to my upcoming homework, but I'm getting "Undefined control sequence" when I try to use a character that I've declared.

Here is my LaTeX file:

```
\Documentclass[24pt,a4paper,margin=1in]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\pumpkin}

\begin{document}

\pumpkin

\end{document}
```

And here is the console output up through the error when I build it with pdflatex:

```
$ pdflatex.exe hw5.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(hw5.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty")

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [24pt,margin=1in].

(hw5.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \pumpkin
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to define (or load a package which does so) `\pumpkin` somewhere. A quick search reveals the conveniently timed [`halloweenmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath) package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336768/134574.

Comment: So \DeclareUnicodeCharacter doesn't introduce a new control sequence?

Comment: It's perfect! :)

Comment: No, it defines the unicode codepoint (in this case `00E4`) to expand to the given control sequence. More or less like a shortcut. In this case you are making `ä` expand to `\pumpkin`. Not a terribly good idea, if you intend to use `ä` in your document, but definitely valid for trick-or-treating ;-)