# pstool does not scale

Tags: scaling, pstool

Hello I am trying to use `pstool` by invoking

```
\psfragfig*[scale=0.5]{picname}
```

However, the picture does not get scaled. Here an example where this does not work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\psfragfig[scale=0.01]{PCO}
{\tiny\psfrag{[t]}{$t$}}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks! The picture can be downloaded [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hs60ygi4a4xx1u4/PCO.eps?dl=0)

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example that illustrates the problem. Without this, it may be difficult for anyone to help you. You might need to make your eps file available for download and add a link here, but not if you can reproduce the problem with a masterpiece such as [pumpkin.eps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209991/2417).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run pdflatex with shell escape enabled. So, if I save your file as `test.tex`, then

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

will work. The method for enabling shell escape might be slightly different on windows machines.

Comment: Thanks it's working now! However, if I try to add a label to the picture, then it looks like the label is undefined and I can't refer to the picture. Any thought?

Comment: Never mind, I got it.