# How to split tikz rectangle by half with different colors and text lines

Tags: tikz-styles

So I have tkiz style:

```
\tikzset{
state/.style={
       rectangle,
       rounded corners,
       draw=black, very thick,
       minimum height=2em,
       inner sep=2pt,
       text centered,
       },
```

How I can split this rectangle to two parts, with different colors, like:

```
|----|
| red|
|----|
|blue|
|____|
```

And how I could write text in different lines, but in same part. Or I should another command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `rectangle split` shape from the `shapes.multipart` library can do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
state/.style={
       rectangle split,
       rectangle split parts=2,
       rectangle split part fill={red!30,blue!20},
       rounded corners,
       draw=black, very thick,
       minimum height=2em,
       text width=3cm,
       inner sep=2pt,
       text centered,
       }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [state] {text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how to make bigger spaces between rectangles? :)

Comment: @Mantas Does adding `inner ysep=10pt,` (or some other value) do what you want?

Comment: No :) I have no spaces between rectangles now. Its more like width or something :)

Comment: inner sep isn't doing the job :/ Still no spaces between rectangles...

Comment: @Mantas I don't understand, do you want a gap between the red and the blue part? Your last comment I don't understand at all.

Comment: I need gap between rectangle 1 and rectangle 2 . Not between parts :)

Comment: @Mantas Well, I cannot know how you positioned the second node (rectangle 2), so all I can say is choose a different coordinate, further away from the first node. I'd recommend asking a new question about it though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Could the colors be side by side as well?

Comment: @FacebFaceb Add `rectangle split horizontal` after `rectangle split` in the `state` style. (Cf. the description of `rectangle split` in the manual, chapter 67.6 *Shapes with multiple parts*.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. And could the splitted rectangles have gradients or pictures in it as well as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215895/color-gradient-in-tikzpicture-from-top-to-bottom-corner and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz respectively?

Comment: @FacebFaceb Not entirely sure, I'd suggest you ask a new question about that.