# Creating a comparison chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How to create a chart as follows using LaTeX.
This is just one example. You can also share your more elegant suggestions.

**MWE:**

[image: current result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-5cm)}, fill opacity=0.5,
      mytext/.style={text opacity=1,font=\large\bfseries}]
    
    \draw[fill=blue, draw = black] (0,0) circle (8);
    \draw[fill=yellow, draw = black,name path=circle 1] (0,-2) circle (6);
    \draw[fill=green, draw = black,name path=circle 2] (0,-2) circle (3);
    
     
    
    \node[mytext] at (0.4,7) (A) {Artifical Intelligence}; 
    \node[mytext] at (0,3.3) (C) {Machine Learning}; 
    \node[mytext] at (0,0.1) (E) {Deep Learning};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

**P.S.**: I have a problem with coloring. Because the color changes at the intersection of the diagram.  Also, I'm living a problem with entering the text to the next line and adding arrows like in the second figure.

[image]

or another example is

[image]

Comment: Hello. Since you're not new to this site, you probably know (or at least you should) that this is not a *do it for me* site. Please edit your post to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and ask for help about a specific issue you encounter.

Comment: How? // Use tikz. Draw 3 circles. Use 3 "split rectangle" objects to host headline and text. Or replace the headline with an image to obtain the second example. // We are looking forward to your Edit to append tikz-code (from \documentclass to \end{document}) and screenshot(s).

Comment: Good places to start: 1) Minimal introduction (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)  2) Tikz-manual (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)  3) https://texample.net/tikz/examples/venn/  4) split rectangles: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301404/how-to-split-tikz-rectangle-by-half-with-different-colors-and-text-lines .

Answer (score 2):

**Here are some ways to do it**, which address most of your questions:

- for simplicity I changed to `standalone`, which is independent of paper size; readjust later to `article`
- I added `two more libraries`, which will be needed below
- I put a `help grid` to have a better idea of the dimensions and coordinates you chose
- add `align=center` to your nodes options, so you'll have multilines
- I also put an example for shape `rectangle split`
- as an example I put a new `node (m)` for text to the left
- I draw 2 lines, the straight line with the standard arrow tip, a bent line with e.g. the `{Stealth}` tip, to show the differences

**Remaining issues:**

- alignment, postioning
- using different text fonts
- color

(can be solved in various ways with `tikz`)

[image: current result]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=10pt]{standalone}% fits paper automatically
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, shapes.multipart, % <<< for rectangle split
                arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-5cm)}, fill opacity=0.5,
      mytext/.style={text opacity=1,font=\large\bfseries}]
    
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5); % <<< to "see" coordinates
    \draw[fill=blue, draw = black] (0,0) circle (8);
    \draw[fill=yellow, draw = black,name path=circle 1] (0,-2) circle (6);
    \draw[fill=green, draw = black,name path=circle 2] (0,-2) circle (3);
    
     
    
    \node[mytext, align=center] at (0.4,7) (A) % <<< align
            {Artifical Intelligence\\ sth. else}; % <<< now you have multi-lines
    \node[mytext] at (0,3.3) (C) {Machine Learning}; 
    
    \node[mytext,   rectangle split, 
                    rectangle split parts=2, align=center] % <<< alternative
            at (0,-2) (E) % <<< shifting
            {Deep Learning
             \nodepart{two} % <<< rectangle split
                Subnset of \\
                machine learning\\
                which 
            };
            
            
    \node [mytext] (m) at  (-10, 3.2) {Machine Learning};  
    \draw [->] (m) to (C); % standard arrow tip
    \draw [-{Stealth}] (m) to [bend left] (C); % a different tip from arrows.meta
    
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```