# Use gradient or picture as fill in split rectangle?

Tags: tikz-styles

So I have made a split rectangle using Torbjørn T.'s answer in [How to split tikz rectangle by half with different colors and text lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301404/how-to-split-tikz-rectangle-by-half-with-different-colors-and-text-lines).

But could I use gradient ([Color gradient in tikzpicture from top to bottom corner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215895/color-gradient-in-tikzpicture-from-top-to-bottom-corner)) in the **upperhalf** and pictures ([How to create a rectangle filled with image using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz)) in the **lowerhalf** as *fills* as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

is this what you like to have? sorry, the question is not clear to me ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style={
       rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
       draw=black, thick, rounded corners,
       left color=blue, right color=blue!20!white,
       text width=3cm, align= center}
                    ]
\node [box]
       {\nodepart{one} text text
        \nodepart{two} text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm] {standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,fadings, positioning, shapes.multipart}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=3mm,
box/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
        draw=black, thick, rounded corners,
        text width=3cm, align=center,
        postaction={path fading =#1,
                    fading angle=#2,
                    fill=#3}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [box=north/45/blue] {text1 \nodepart{two} text 2};
\node (n2) [box=south/-45/orange,
            below=of n1] {text1 \nodepart{two} text 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit (1):**
regarding to edit of question: in the multi part shapes the gradient coloring and fading separately for each shape parts is not possible to do with known shape's options (your question seems to be new feature request for multi part shapes).

**edit (2):**
as workaround the gradient colors on the background layer separately for each node part in case, can be drawn:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{
       rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
       rounded corners,
       text width=3cm, align=center,
    draw,  thick,
    append after command={\pgfextra
        \fill[left color=#1, right color=#1!20!white]
    (\tikzlastnode.one west) 
    [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.north) -| (\tikzlastnode.one east) 
    [sharp corners]   |- (\tikzlastnode.one split) -| cycle;
        \fill[left color=#2, right color=#2!20!white]
    (\tikzlastnode.two west) 
    [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.south) -| (\tikzlastnode.two east)  
    [sharp corners]   |- (\tikzlastnode.one split) -| cycle;
                                    \endpgfextra}% end of the append after command
                        }% end of the box style definition
                    ]
\node [box=blue/red]
       {\nodepart{one} longer, two lines text in part 1
        \nodepart{two} text 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where `append after command={\pgfextra ...}` is used to fill each shape's part separately.

Comment: Does `??` mean : `Yes you can use gradient as fill` ?

Comment: actually mean: is this what OP like to have :) i'm not sure if i understand what is desired result. corrected in answer :)

Comment: thanks for your answer! sorry, my question is a little unclear, I'll edit the question :)

Comment: you can solve your problem with drawing stack of two rectangles with solution of the my first solution and then clip corners to round shape.

Comment: @Zarko Could you please explain `\draw[thick, % node part one
                              left color=#1, right color=#1!20!white]
            (\ppbb.west) [rounded corners] |- (\ppbb.north) -|
            (\ppbb.east) [sharp corners]   |- (\ppbb.north |- \ppbb.west) -| cycle;
                        \draw[thick, % node part two
                              left color=#2, right color=#2!20!white]
            (\ppbb.west) [rounded corners] |- (\ppbb.south) -|
            (\ppbb.east) [sharp corners]   |- (\ppbb.south |- \ppbb.west) -| cycle;`?

Comment: @FacebFaceb, i add some explanation to my answer. probably i will later return to it. it is quite challenging :)

Comment: @Zarko Ok thanks, because I don't know how to put rectangles side by side with the part in my previous comment

Comment: @FacebFaceb, meanwhile i return to your answer and made (far)  better solution.

Comment: @Zarko Do you mean you are going to explain how to make rectangles side by side (left and right)?

Comment: @FacebFaceb, site complain for tomany comments ...so if you have new question, please ask it as question. and please clarify in it what you means with "rectangles side by side". two `multipart` nodes or one horizontal `multipart` node? it may make a link to this question.

Comment: @Zarko Is it possible to set a minimum height for each subrectangle, independent of the amount of text?

Comment: no, it is not possible (as far as i know). ask as question if someone know for some heck.