# Picture in Love Heart

Tags: graphics, errors, pstricks

I try to reproduce the answer Photo Clipper of kiss my armpit to the question [Photo Clipper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/can-we-make-a-love-heart-with-latex) but it is not succeeding. As I do not have any clue what might be the problem I would like to know if there is anything I have to take into account to get the desired result (such as picture size...):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{pretty}}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=100,
    xunit=.5\wd\IBox,
    yunit=.5\ht\IBox,
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1.5)
\begin{psclip}{\psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\rput(0,1.25){%
    \color{red}\large
    $\displaystyle\!
    \begin{aligned}
%        x(t)&=\sin^3 t\\
%        y(t)&=(13\cos t -5\cos 2t -2\cos 3t -\cos 4t)/16
    \end{aligned}$}
\rput(0,1){
%HAPPY BIRTHDAY
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit 1**. The resulting picture is this:
[image]

Comment: So you have copied the code, commented out some content and then what? Maybe you can show us what result you get when you put in your desired picture? Is it too big, too small?

Comment: @Huang_d: Thank you. I edited the question but I am not able to say anything more than it does not work.

Comment: Well… Is your picture named `pretty.png`  (or .jpg or any other that is accepted by `\includegraphics`? Have you tried the options of `\includegraphics` such as `[scale=]` or `[width=\textwidth]`?        (4kg of potatoes? You must be german)

Comment: @Huang_d: Thank you again. The picture is named pretty.jpg. I tried .png, different values for `[scale=]` and `[width=\textwidth]`, but it does not work. (I am:-))

Comment: Do you get some sort of error, does it compile without any notice? If you get an error, what kind? If not, try the `[noisy]` option. I can't verify your problem here. Are you running Lua-, La-, Xe-, XelaTeX? The manual says: "You cannot run your files with pdftex/pdflatex/luatex/lualatex, use xetex/xelatex instead or the sequence latex->dvips->ps2pdf" (from here: https://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/ ) Please provide more information.

Comment: @Huang_d: The console says this: `...22: Undefined control sequence. 
<recently read> /c@lor@to@ps

l.22...rigin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}}`

Comment: I've copied your code, changed `pretty` by `example-image`, compiled with `xelatex` and it worked. I get `example-image` clipped inside a hart line.

Comment: Same as @Ignasi, copied, put an image into the same folder, named it pretty.png and compiled it with XeTeX. Does that work for you? What error do you get in that case?

Comment: Hey guys, it is working since I compiled it with `xelatex`. Thank you so much!!!