# Color in Love Heart

Tags: graphics, pstricks, backgrounds, fun

I would like to use the Photo Clipper shape of kiss my armpit that they provided as an answer to [Can we make a love heart with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/can-we-make-a-love-heart-with-latex). However, I would like to have the background around the heart in red (except for the picture). Can anyone help me with that one?

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{pretty}}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=100,
    xunit=.5\wd\IBox,
    yunit=.5\ht\IBox,
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1.5)
\begin{psclip}{\psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\rput(0,1.25){%
    \color{red}\large
    $\displaystyle\!
    \begin{aligned}
%        x(t)&=\sin^3 t\\
%        y(t)&=(13\cos t -5\cos 2t -2\cos 3t -\cos 4t)/16
    \end{aligned}$}
\rput(0,1){
%HAPPY BIRTHDAY
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of [this other question of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374520/69818)?  Please don’t ask the same question twice: wait patiently until someone is willing to answer.

Comment: The first question was about getting a result and it was answered in the comment section by Ignasi & Huang_d. Now, I need to change the result.

Comment: Fair enough.  Nonetheless, consider whether this question could be better merged into the previous one, as an edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything red"? You mean the white background around the heart?

Comment: It was about the background around the heart, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `pagecolor` package to do this:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{duck}}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{red}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(#1)-5*cos(2*#1)-2*cos(3*#1)-cos(4*#1))/16}

\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=100,
    xunit=.5\wd\IBox,
    yunit=.5\ht\IBox,
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1.5)
\begin{psclip}{\psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15}]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` can be removed without making any problem.