# TikZ: complex mask over image (even odd rule)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw masks (with various shapes) over an image. For example, I made a circle mask like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{2C414C}
\definecolor{foreground}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=foreground, fill=foreground]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5,even odd rule]
    (image.north west) rectangle (image.south east) % Cover up everything
    (0,1) circle [radius=50pt]; % Punch a hole
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mask example]

**How do I use a more complex shape instead of the circle? Specifically, I need a heart shape.** I tried using the one from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139735/117535), but it either causes errors or doesn't appear:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=foreground, fill=foreground]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5,even odd rule]
    (image.north west) rectangle (image.south east)
    (0,1) draw .. controls (0,0.75) and (-1.5,1.00) .. (-1.5,2)  arc (180:0:0.75)  -- cycle;
    (0,1) draw .. controls (0,0.75) and ( 1.5,1.00) .. ( 1.5,2)  arc (0:180:0.75) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Error: `! Use of \@next doesn't match its definition.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw the heart with only one path:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{2C414C}
\definecolor{foreground}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=foreground, fill=foreground]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5,even odd rule]
    (image.north west) rectangle (image.south east)
    (0,1) .. controls (0,1.75) and (-1.5,2.00) .. (-1.5,3)  arc (180:0:0.75)  arc (180:0:0.75)
    .. controls ( 1.5,2.00) and (0,1.75) .. (0,1) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And with relative coordinates in hart definition, it's easier to place wherever you want over the image:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{2C414C}
\definecolor{foreground}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\newcommand{\hart}{.. controls +(0,.75) and +(0,-1.00) .. ++(-1.5,2)  arc (180:0:0.75) arc (180:0:0.75)
    .. controls +(0,-1.00) and +(0,.75) .. cycle}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=foreground, fill=foreground]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5,even odd rule]
    (image.north west) rectangle (image.south east)
    {[rotate=90, scale=.5](image.center)\hart} 
    {[scale=1.5](image.center)\hart}
    {[rotate=-50]([shift={(1,2)}]image.south west)\hart};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @kontextify: may be you are interested in updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Seems, there was two times `draw` an one `;` to much.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{2C414C}
\definecolor{foreground}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=foreground, fill=foreground]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5,even odd rule]
    (image.north west) rectangle (image.south east) % Cover up everything
    (0,1) circle [radius=50pt]; % Punch a hole
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=foreground, fill=foreground]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5,even odd rule,]
   (image.north west) rectangle (image.south east)
(0,1) .. controls (0,0.75) and (-1.5,1.00) .. (-1.5,2)  arc (180:0:0.75)  -- cycle
(0,1) .. controls (0,0.75) and ( 1.5,1.00) .. ( 1.5,2)  arc (0:180:0.75) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```