# Custom border for glossary and index pages

Tags: margins, koma-script, glossaries

I'm preparing a technical book in Latex using [KOMA script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script) `srcbook` class and I would like to add a gray border ONLY to glossary and index pages. The idea is to make them easy to find when the book is closed, like in the sample below:

[image: index page]

I have seen similar solutions using `fancyhdr` or `tikz` but (1) I don't know if they can be applied directly without screwing KOMA, and (2) I've found no way to limit the border only to index/glossary pages and I'm sure there must be an obvious way to do both things.

UPDATE: I found a solution (see below) using the `eso-pic` and `ifthen` packages to draw the border  and the `etoolbox` to patch the `theindex` environment and control where it appears.

Comment: this looks like a request for "thumb indexex".  see [Adding chapter marker to far right edge of page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31462/579).  i don't know whether there might be incompatibility with the koma script classes.

Comment: This is not exactly what I had in mind but with some tinkering it might produce what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package `background` in combination with TikZ and the defined node `current page`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{a}\lipsum[1-10]

\AddEverypageHook{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[line width=1cm](current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south east);%
}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Curiously enough, the `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` line gives the following error: `! Undefined control sequence.` Could it be a problem with Latex's version?

Comment: Changing `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` to `\SetBgContents{}` mostly works with my package version. The border is drawn correctly but for some reason begins the page BEFORE the actual index begins.

Comment: @AlbertoMiranda: I am using TeX Live 2013.

Comment: It seems that with my version there are some incompatibilities between `background` or `tikz` (don't know which one) and `KOMA`. I found a solution that works in my system without using either, but your answer helped me find related solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoMiranda: Instead of trying a hack you should update your system.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately that is out of my hands.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering my own question in hope that someone will find it useful later on.

My solution is inspired and based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73703/32893) since using Tikz shows some weird behavior with the `scrbook` class (at least in my system). I've created two new commands `\addthumbindex` and `\clearthumbindex` that can be used to enable and disable the thumbindex respectively. The first command receives the thumbindex's color and width as mandatory arguments, and you can also specify an optional `bleed` argument if you need to print in A4 but want it cropped to B5 (the MWE below shows an example).

<s>This solution is not perfect though: as you can see in the following picture, I haven't been able to remove the border in the page BEFORE the actual index begins, so I'm still searching for a solution (whether it's an improvement on mine or a different method altogether).</s> EDIT: FIXED.

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4,cam,center]{crop} % to show cropping marks (if needed)
\usepackage{xcolor}              % to have colors 
\usepackage{eso-pic}             % put things into background 
\usepackage{ifthen}              % support for conditionals
\usepackage{imakeidx}            % to create the index

\usepackage{lipsum}              % for sample text

\definecolor{thumbindexgray}{RGB}{102,102,102}

% patch `begin{theindex}` to add the border
\AtBeginEnvironment{theindex}{\addthumbindex[bleed]{.5cm}{thumbindexgray}}

% patch `end{theindex}` to clear the border
\AtEndEnvironment{theindex}{\clearthumbindex}

\newcommand{\addthumbindex}[3][]{
    \newlength{\thumbindexwidth}
    \setlength{\thumbindexwidth}{#2}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{bleed}}{
        %\clearpage (not needed if we patch 'theindex' environment)
        \AddToShipoutPicture{% from package eso-pic: put something to the background
            \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{
                % odd page: right bar
                \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the bottom right of the page
                    \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth+\thumbindexwidth-2\thumbindexwidth},
                         \LenToUnit{\dimexpr-\thumbindexwidth}){% move it to the top right
                        \color{#3}\rule{2\thumbindexwidth}{\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight+2\thumbindexwidth}}%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
            {%
                % even page: left bar
                \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the left bottom of the page
                    \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\thumbindexwidth-2\thumbindexwidth},
                         \LenToUnit{\dimexpr-\thumbindexwidth}){% move it to the top right
                        \color{#3}\rule{2\thumbindexwidth}{\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight+2\thumbindexwidth}}%
                    }%
                    %\color{#3}\rule{\thumbindexwidth}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
                }%
            }%
        }
    }
    {
        %\clearpage (not needed if we patch 'theindex' environment)            
        \AddToShipoutPicture{% from package eso-pic: put something to the background
            \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{
                % odd page: right bar
                \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the bottom right of the page
                    \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\thumbindexwidth},0){% move it to the top right
                        \color{#3}\rule{\thumbindexwidth}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
            {%
                % even page: left bar
                \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the left bottom of the page
                    \color{#3}\rule{\thumbindexwidth}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
                }%
            }%
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\clearthumbindex}{
    \clearpage
    \ClearShipoutPicture
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\input{fake_index.tex} % just a collection of \index{XXX}\lipsum[1-10]

% \addthumbindex[bleed]{.5cm}{thumbindexgray} % (not needed if patching 'theindex')
\printindex
% \clearthumbindex{}  % (not needed if patching 'theindex')

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I found a solution by patching the `theindex` environment generated by `makeindex` using the `etoolbox` package. For future reference, the code works both in `pdflatex` and in `xelatex` and I assume that something similar will work with glossaries or acronym lists. I've added my changes to the code above and a picture of the final result below.

[image: final result]